# How to golf evaluation of math expression in MySQL?

Tags: code-golf, tips

The challenge given to me is comparatively easy, and specific to MySQL *only*. I'm given a table `expressions` which have mathematical calculations done by a kid. Basically, I've to `select` all the right calculations!

The table have the following properties,

- `a` : an integer, *the left operand*.
- `b` : an integer, *the right operand*.
- `operation` : a char, any one operation from `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'` and `'/'` (pure-div).
- `c` : an integer, the result given by *the kid*.

## Example

```
a  b  operation  c
------------------
2  3  +          5
4  2  /          3
6  1  *          9
8  5  -          3
```

As we can see, the second and third operations are wrongly calculated, so they need to be filtered out. Here is what I've done till now,

## MySQL, 88 chars

*Rule:* 88 chars is calculated by removing *all spaces* (`\s+`) from the given code. This is MySQL, so they simply take amount of chars (calculated [here](https://regex101.com/r/h8kiSW/1)).

```mysql
select * from expressions
where if(
    '+' = @o := operation,
    a + b,
    if(
        @o = '-',
        a - b,
        if(
            @o = '*',
            a * b,
            a / b
        )
    )
) = c
```

[Try it on Rextester](https://rextester.com/RAVJO35061)!

But, I'm sure that this can be golfed further, as many other submissions are of `73` chars, which is `15` bytes fewer than mine!

I think I need to change the idea of my solution, but I can't find anything which can evaluate expressions directly in MySQL. Any ideas?

## Rules

- The names, specific to table, included in the code isn't subject to change.
- `select` is considered to be the only method to output/result.
- For multiple statements, it should be wrapped inside `begin ... end`, as the whole code is the body of a function, defined as,
  `CREATE PROCEDURE expressionsVerification()`

Comment: Generally language-specific challenges work because of a unique feature inherent to the language ([for example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/klein-topololyglots)). This might fall under a [tips] challenge, but in that case it needs to have the tips tag and you need to include what can and can't be golfed. For example, changing `operation` or `expressions` in your code would reduce bytes, are they acceptable golfs?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - thanks for informing me, I've included any necessary rules. Also, can I add `mysql` tag, as in the example post?

Comment: You talk about `oper` at the top, but `operation` in your rextester code and link. Which of the two should it be? Also, I barely know anything about MySQL, but maybe you can somehow create an array `[a+b,a-b,a*b,a/b]`, get the index of the operator-character in `"+-*/"` and use it to index into the created value array? Not sure how to accomplish it, and not sure if it's shorter though. Just an idea.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - It was a typo, edited it. Though, arrays are not a type in mysql, but I was also thinking over thinking some kind of map or hash.

Comment: Do you allow a `view` definition? This will provide the ultimative solution: `select * from e where c = r`. Note `e` is view on `expressions` that defines a column `r` with the *rigth* answer. This is the  *database* approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Score 69

```sql
select * from expressions
where elt(ord(operation)/2-20,a*b,a+b,a-b,a/b)=c
```

Takes inspiration from [Marmite Bomber](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55931/marmite-bomber)'s use of `elt`, but uses a magic formula. Indexes into the list via `ord(operation)2/-20`, which buckets the four character codes across 1 to 4 by abusing `elt`'s rounding behavior.

-1 thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld), who improved on the modulo reduction.

-1 thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler), who found a better non-modulo formula.

### Score 73

```sql
select * from expressions
where elt(instr('*/-+',operation),a*b,a/b,a-b,a+b)=c
```

This is my best guess as to the 73 you mention other people have gotten in the question.

Comment: `where elt(ord(operation)*3%7+1,a*b,a/b,a-b,a+b)=c` saves a byte.

Comment: @Arnauld Very nice!

Comment: I think `where elt(ord(operation)/2-20,a*b,a+b,a-b,a/b)=c` saves a byte further, abusing elt's behavior on half-integers (it rounds them up before indexing).

Comment: @Bubbler that's extremely clever. I would not have guesses such a simple task would have so much golf potential!

Comment: Really amazed to see such kind of golfing in mysql `:O`

Comment: `SELECT*FROM` (without the spaces) works and saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @ElPedro Normally I'd agree but the post says it's scored after removing spaces so I left them in for clarity.

Comment: @Sisyphus - Fair point :)

Comment: I'm sorry! Really forgot about accepting it, thanks to SE comments ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## MySQL, <s>82</s> 74  bytes

```
select * from expressions
where 
elt(locate(operation,'+-/*'),a+b,a-b,a/b,a*b)=c
```

output

```
a           b           operation c           
----------- ----------- --------- ----------- 
2           3           +         5           
8           5           -         3
```

Explanation

[ELT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) returns the Nth element of the list of strings (the expressions are evaluated and converted to strings)

[LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)     Return the position of the first occurrence of substring

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Comment: I think using `LOCATE` is shorter than using `FIELD`: `locate(operation,'+-/*')`.

Comment: It's really amazing to know how you'd used `elt`!! Also, `locate` would be shorter, as suggested by @FryAmTheEggman.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks for the hint - updated

Answer (score 0):

## Score 32

Solution using a database [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)

```
select a,b,operation
from e
where c=r
```

Unfortunately a `select *` is not possible as the view contains an extra column with the correct result.

Requires a view creation in the database

```
create or replace view e as
select
  a,b,operation,c,
  elt(field(operation,'+','-','/','*'),a+b,a-b,a/b,a*b) r
from  expressions
```

Comment: why doesn't the view count in the score?

Comment: The view is defined in the database - not part of the query (= program) @user253751 `create table` and `insert` + `commit`also do not count here;)

Comment: It seems a bit like answering every challenge with "first, define `v` as the list of prime numbers where the last 3 digits form a square [or whatever the challenge is]". Then, `print(v)`. 8 bytes.

Comment: Nope @user253751 this is a *database* chalange and a *database view* is a sort of module or library in a programming language.  In your 8 bytes you also do not count the bytes required to implement the `print` function. But I have no problem if this solution is not accepted. I've only posted it because IMO a) it can't be topped and b) *this is the way* how in the database you attack the problems.

Comment: Judging by the Rextester link by OP, you can't change the code before the submission section (you're supposed to start with one table and no views), so you should include the view definition in the submission (and therefore in the score). And the fact that "the whole code is the body of the function defined with `CREATE PROCEDURE`" only makes it worse.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber It's like defining a library `L` that defines `v` as whatever the solution is and then saying `import L;print(L.v)` is the answer (19 bytes)