# MacGyver's Toolbox

Tags: restricted-source, answer-chaining

In this question each answer will get a "toolbox" that can be used to construct a program/function.  The toolbox will consist of two things:

- a list of programming languages
- a list of valid characters

You must write a valid program/function in one of the languages provided using only the characters in the toolbox.  Your program/function should output the number of answers already present on this question.

Once you have written and posted an answer the language and characters you have used will be removed from the toolbox and 1 new language and 12 new characters will be randomly added to be used as the toolbox for the next answer.

### Rules

- Each answer will:

  - Output the number of valid answers coming before it
  - Contain a subset of the characters provided in the toolbox for that answer.  (repeats are allowed)
  - Be in one of the languages from the provided toolbox
- The next toolbox will determined by [this](https://tio.run/##dVbXduM2EH22vkLRycZSYjqm3DfZk957L5bPGgRBEhIIYFEkcVP@Os/OzICUvCkP4NwBMBWDAW0XGqPn94rp2o@fjG8mJ@esyMXkaDL3rFAITtfMAbmEcX0NH5ZZwVwWnMBVxkNkSnUIy9JapLXRxKvaqIurmqDktFvZJvIVIquysmPK1C8wGVfMe8n7SV1rRI53JhLQRpW06L1oC9VlzD/kav7Coma@RT4WwtVSkwcbsr418C2Yb5CgTCFYm4hOJGi5IiT8hm0JVVHXYo@y6ytkFIk7xpsuRbPD88RInVWKrQamMEYNuErJIAzJqghLpjPep6mIBZxCHdE3jsnRNaEUKM9CosyVUjNUywVYxhB4AzoTBV@VTIIN5NKkjY0oSzpZ3kg8Ni61Zq3RWW9tSQnhSnpaVWYZHUbPTVVBUriTNhCrS9mDtdgS2ODX2sFLx7rkkut8SMZ9xk3S5jOwiafBYyFJHGunxJGOh867FFy2JFpCLC0ZLEUwEQMoQStlSyjRCh0IYS5Fy0B/H4FocY10CIeJzPZBiMDwu5a4WkFNG9RbCaeZLg1BrL9KOlFAtRMk55BkvhHDnJcUaY@wACrDyWZlSI9xQfS0yWoiPevg2Ose0FR0UpAbuxRB2XEZyEKtOtuYHQAfUBV4i1M0D@W0i692cCeIylYQNWaNea49@tgwv0ohNKwbktkUvEHZRmyHGy1x6CBcCmmJI4sFLi0ZGVqyNcuMFXpZrv7BXvd8ciorWCHggptSvDg/zIjUVIj2yV4amolKsoGeA1hlK6MZAYNGV0pQ5a9MUAmQtGJF58B7wpKUK7XGGoerKnkyq4waUESVuAx1VxhFN79lTpr@ErYsNJL7hBSRtXCScteyLZQrAqmxbrN5OTAqgdWgBqbwG6ol1rmOLfSqTVoyzEvUb4ql4EGuRbZvAVBVpMrwAGYRNKjHMgdF3ohALRQ4mdVY/JZaDAKo/fOeXiBtaBni76@JpWZgUbc1G@GG4t4zw9W1TqhYJmSwd/sNFoiNztLDYaNvMMu2WxGLjckTcKyVZeahBbVphQ7F0mOU79B8jzLb2W7HngLCiwF9diUCAbq4Di9rmz3srE44UVNXcpiTqKjjIaaKcWJLa7TVlDRljCWSeoCD2OgRSiBDp1wqeRc9GvdwGRhRDAc6t3j@kIOCEHo/UUdJyfGipC/UU/RUjF54g@nxDbP7zkT3midA5@zpwHwTYEPSIVWSg5ezEYTaoiKislalduE1pIjWtNm01GC8aSn7/pmS1JPo4nMW/ICT@sCcI/@CS1@G7d13Le6DbYbIFo8@cEVfum9BtFaxQB6FBv4WWEkoikQCdlQ4h64vPOx7u7Ahurqm7hdcbO1@PrqgyK8IrzcVedQl1LIh7VEr1hZ0jlE7sNj/w6xxpGNaSw8/LBlJZ1qEobeuZfAY5qaRTiUKvltG/y0b6YkYePlTX9p4THEX0fPnEO/tvWwtHNUYemmjZDEaWeODLOGnChL2VGobw3Q2wttbmC3MDjP4JKcZyEOY9tMzkHe6htle33Fbnk@TSlgbgXdKjJXQ017jbPzm@PLx6ECLDc6A4GQyOkjbtAnjYd64HZR63AuD3AGaO462hBOb9jtmML3XR/@IN@BgmNJeeBdKWQvweXaUX8weDc742ex2dNBrPmYWun@51ziCF278FG07/C@Z5vNZ8hrz8C@vp/3CrPebNoHskDS48JSEnsck5POr/wiHlKRwekO8cf8fCyiB3bLa2URn9nbRQA8fBJhswLmB2iGzPXc3mRwvjdRTj@9/ufN3dnd/n88vzs5ORzeH8M9yeDQ@fPBri@yDtpJYKGME@@uCnGjNkt6ww9vR4WJ7cgIjhzGHcQrjDMY5jAsYlzCuFmGhgRYw@MLBV8CoFtscJHOQzEEyB8kcJHOQzEEyB8n8CsY1DAYDpHMOo4QB8nk1fmny8qNXFofT2auvHWXHr5/Mz84vLq@uH7/x5K2333n3vfc/@PCjjz/59LPPv/jyq6@/@fa773/48aeff/n1ZrG4fXrHCl6Kqm7kcqVabZ85H@Jm2z3/7fc//lxsL6vDv7TJOPxbi78B) python program.  To generate the next toolbox put in the remaining languages and characters along with the *post id* of the last answer.
- The language list here is all the languages available on try it online at the time of this post.  The characters have char codes 0-127.
- You may write either a full program or a function as your answer.  Since REPLs are different languages they will not be allowed.  (use the TIO version of every language)
- If a language uses a special encoding the characters should be interpreted as *bytes* (decoded from ASCII and padded with a zero).
- The starting toolbox will be randomized from this questions post id ([126063](https://tio.run/##dVbXduM2EH22vkLRycZSYjqm3DfZk957L5bPGgRBEhIIYFEkcVP@Os/OzICUvCkP4NwBMBWDAW0XGqPn94rp2o@fjG8mJ@esyMXkaDL3rFAITtfMAbmEcX0NH5ZZwVwWnMBVxkNkSnUIy9JapLXRxKvaqIurmqDktFvZJvIVIquysmPK1C8wGVfMe8n7SV1rRI53JhLQRpW06L1oC9VlzD/kav7Coma@RT4WwtVSkwcbsr418C2Yb5CgTCFYm4hOJGi5IiT8hm0JVVHXYo@y6ytkFIk7xpsuRbPD88RInVWKrQamMEYNuErJIAzJqghLpjPep6mIBZxCHdE3jsnRNaEUKM9CosyVUjNUywVYxhB4AzoTBV@VTIIN5NKkjY0oSzpZ3kg8Ni61Zq3RWW9tSQnhSnpaVWYZHUbPTVVBUriTNhCrS9mDtdgS2ODX2sFLx7rkkut8SMZ9xk3S5jOwiafBYyFJHGunxJGOh867FFy2JFpCLC0ZLEUwEQMoQStlSyjRCh0IYS5Fy0B/H4FocY10CIeJzPZBiMDwu5a4WkFNG9RbCaeZLg1BrL9KOlFAtRMk55BkvhHDnJcUaY@wACrDyWZlSI9xQfS0yWoiPevg2Ose0FR0UpAbuxRB2XEZyEKtOtuYHQAfUBV4i1M0D@W0i692cCeIylYQNWaNea49@tgwv0ohNKwbktkUvEHZRmyHGy1x6CBcCmmJI4sFLi0ZGVqyNcuMFXpZrv7BXvd8ciorWCHggptSvDg/zIjUVIj2yV4amolKsoGeA1hlK6MZAYNGV0pQ5a9MUAmQtGJF58B7wpKUK7XGGoerKnkyq4waUESVuAx1VxhFN79lTpr@ErYsNJL7hBSRtXCScteyLZQrAqmxbrN5OTAqgdWgBqbwG6ol1rmOLfSqTVoyzEvUb4ql4EGuRbZvAVBVpMrwAGYRNKjHMgdF3ohALRQ4mdVY/JZaDAKo/fOeXiBtaBni76@JpWZgUbc1G@GG4t4zw9W1TqhYJmSwd/sNFoiNztLDYaNvMMu2WxGLjckTcKyVZeahBbVphQ7F0mOU79B8jzLb2W7HngLCiwF9diUCAbq4Di9rmz3srE44UVNXcpiTqKjjIaaKcWJLa7TVlDRljCWSeoCD2OgRSiBDp1wqeRc9GvdwGRhRDAc6t3j@kIOCEHo/UUdJyfGipC/UU/RUjF54g@nxDbP7zkT3midA5@zpwHwTYEPSIVWSg5ezEYTaoiKislalduE1pIjWtNm01GC8aSn7/pmS1JPo4nMW/ICT@sCcI/@CS1@G7d13Le6DbYbIFo8@cEVfum9BtFaxQB6FBv4WWEkoikQCdlQ4h64vPOx7u7Ahurqm7hdcbO1@PrqgyK8IrzcVedQl1LIh7VEr1hZ0jlE7sNj/w6xxpGNaSw8/LBlJZ1qEobeuZfAY5qaRTiUKvltG/y0b6YkYePlTX9p4THEX0fPnEO/tvWwtHNUYemmjZDEaWeODLOGnChL2VGobw3Q2wttbmC3MDjP4JKcZyEOY9tMzkHe6htle33Fbnk@TSlgbgXdKjJXQ017jbPzm@PLx6ECLDc6A4GQyOkjbtAnjYd64HZR63AuD3AGaO462hBOb9jtmML3XR/@IN@BgmNJeeBdKWQvweXaUX8weDc742ex2dNBrPmYWun@51ziCF278FG07/C@Z5vNZ8hrz8C@vp/3CrPebNoHskDS48JSEnsck5POr/wiHlKRwekO8cf8fCyiB3bLa2URn9nbRQA8fBJhswLmB2iGzPXc3mRwvjdRTj@9/ufN3dnd/n88vzs5ORzeH8M9yeDQ@fPBri@yDtpJYKGME@@uCnGjNkt6ww9vR4WJ7cgIjhzGHcQrjDMY5jAsYlzCuFmGhgRYw@MLBV8CoFtscJHOQzEEyB8kcJHOQzEEyB8n8CsY1DAYDpHMOo4QB8nk1fmny8qNXFofT2auvHWXHr5/Mz84vLq@uH7/x5K2333n3vfc/@PCjjz/59LPPv/jyq6@/@fa773/48aeff/n1ZrG4fXrHCl6Kqm7kcqVabZ85H@Jm2z3/7fc//lxsL6vDv7TJOPxbi78B)), there will be 7 languages to start and I will add the characters `echoprint0` and ascii 0-31 for free to get people started.
- You may not answer twice in a row

### Scoring

Each person will have a score equal to the number valid answers they have provided.  There will not necessarily be an end and I will not be accepting any answers.

### Sporting

This is a competition, but I encourage you to put fun above winning while still staying competitive (if I could make the winning criteria "fun had" I would).  Some things that are not fun:

- Intentionally using characters you don't need to stunt future answers.
- Attempting to game the post id system to make future tool boxes harder to use.
- Attempting to game the post id system to make future tool boxes easier to use.

I can't prevent any one from doing these things, but I will be downvoting any answers I suspect are doing this.

On a more positive note, here are some things that are good sporting and encouraged:

- Coordinating with other users in chat.
- Saving characters for harder or more restrictive languages

Comment: Can we output numbers in bases other in 10?

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony If that is the standard way of outputting in a language.

Comment: Well...an interesting setup that got nipped in the bud early due to too many missing characters for languages that are defined by a very small set of characters. Logicode got hosed by the lack of a `1` and `!` in its toolbox. I managed to produce the string "0110" using `?`,`0` and `+` although I couldn't quite figure out what the `?` actually did (and it was not in the language specification).  But `+` was missing from the toolbox as well, along with `=` which would have allowed for variable assignment.  Aaanndd...no `o` for `out`put.

Comment: @Draco18s I found an SML answer, so maybe now there are enough chars available for a logicode answer.

Comment: @Laikoni Nice! I couldn't find specs for several of the languages, SML being one of them.

Comment: ...Are Emojicode programs even possible in this challenge? It's one of the available languages, but I can't figure out how one would produce a 

Comment: @Draco18s I'll look into it, they may be possible if not I'll remove them from the rotation.

Comment: There may also be another bug: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126063/macgyvers-toolbox/126432?noredirect=1#comment311251_126432 13 `W`s in the toolbox linked on that answer.

Comment: What about emojis for use in Emojicode?

Comment: @SantiagoBenoit I have removed emojicode

Comment: Adding 12 new characters each time may have made this too easy.

Comment: @mbomb007 You are almost certainly correct.  I wasn't able to get enough people to help me test this before release.  I hope to re-release this challenge with a number of improvements, among them a lower character influx.

Comment: Or, maybe make it so that the characters added don't have to be unique, so it might not actually add as many until more are missing.

Comment: @WheatWizard There are repeat languages showing up as options now. We have already done Go and Forte. Should we just remove them and continue? In your future version, I think that the input should have the languages that have already been done, rather than what it is.

Comment: @andrewarchi Repeat languages are intentional, I don't know if I would disallow them in future versions they keep things interesting.

Answer (score 7):

## 2. [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), `(no@`

Third time's the charm

```
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((no@((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/19jJIK8fAeNUTAKRgHR4P9/AA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZLjxs3DD6vf4VrtFgbiBY7TvdVJCjaSy9FT0Uv2SDRSJoZ2RpJ1cP2BOhv35KUxt70cdDwoyRSJEVS46c0OLt9Mdz2cfl@@WF1e8fbRq3erLaRtwbB2wMPQB5gPD3BhzOveGApKFzlImVuzIRQSu@R9s4Sb3pn7h97glrQbuOHLPaIvGFy4sb1XzFMGB6jFnXS9hZREJPLBKwzkhZjVGNrJsbja64XXy1aHkfkc6tCry1ZcKTTTw6@LY8DEpRpFR8LsYUkq/eEVDzyE6Eu215dEHt6RMaQeOBimIo3Z7wtjLasM3w/M61zZsZdCQZhCFZHWHPLRA1Tm1u4hT6jbQKDY3tCxVHBUqE8SG05qhUKTkYXxAA6CwVbjS6CA8TSlY2DkpJuVgwar01oa/noLKun7SggwuhIq8btckDvhes6CIoI2idirdQVHNSJwBG/3s9WBj4Vk8IUUzk8MuGKtsjgTLwNkVtN4pg7Eke5HrpvqYQeSVSCLyMdKFVyGR2QoJWipYwalU2EMJZq5KC/eqBGXCMdanQ7PVPhJBqiAgaXXRxTieP3oFGigzx3eFanguVWOoKYk50OqoUKIEgGI2FxUPNc1OR9RZgUnRNkR@dIjwtJVTqwnkhlA6RCXwFN5aAVmXEOG6Si0IlO6M3kB3cGYAOqAmtxiuYhxc7@9QHqhKgeFVHnDhj7PqKNA4/74sLApznAQysGlB3Uaa5yjKO2SYXi0g4Hyy0u7TgdtOMHzpxXdif3/2CfKl@MYi1vFRR9uZBX8/OMKo2GaA32ztFMNprP9A7Anu2d5QQcHro3iqph75IpgKQNb6cA1hPWpNyYA@Y9lO@cGcaZGWVUicuQi60z1A1GHrSrhTnyNGgRCzJEDipoit3IT5DCCLTFXGZbOTOmgP2sBqbwm7od5r7NI/SvY1lyPGrU79qdEkkfFLu0BcgqUuVEgmMRDKjH8wCJP6hEbRU4zXosCE9tBwHk/l2l90gHWgb/a@l4ahAedXt3VGFO7gszl7MPymRZkMN@Ho@YID4HT4@Jz3HAKPtpTyw2q0gg8FFLFqEtjWWFLsXTA9Wc0faCmJ/8dGbfAsLCgN67V4kAFW7AYh3Z624bVFA9daqAMcmGuiBiypigTrRGW52kKec8kdIDAvhGD1MBDI0KJeVDjnh4hGLgRNEd6Obqy2sOEkLZy0SfNQUnKklfyKccKRmjig7DEwfuL52J6loUQPcc6cLikGBD0aFNkYPXdFCExrYjYthoSruIFkJEa9YdR2ow0Y0U/fin0dSTqPAFT3HGRX3iIZB9KZQvx5YfpxH3wTZH5IRXn4ShL9VbUqM3PJFFaYA/CC4JZVVIwo4K9zDVxMO@d3YbvOt76n4p5NFf5nNIhuzK8KJTkmcrIZcdac/W8LGle8w2wIn1v@aAo1zTQUf4iWEkzaxKc2896BTRzeOggykUbPec/mWOOhJx8DdQ@tIxYoinjJZ/AX8/vujRw1UtoZcORreLhXcxaQk/WhCwT9r6nNabBVZv604wO8/gM11mIA5pXac3IB9sD7NV380o79ZFJawtwDqjlkbZddW4Wb5bPvywuLLqiDMguFotrso269JynnfhDLVdVmGQu8LjbrKXcGPrumMD0xd99N/4AQxMa9oL74LUvQKbN2@a@813szFxs/m4uKqab7iH7i8vGhfwwi0/4dkB/1XWzXZTrMY4/MvqdV3YVLtpE8jOQYOCpyBUfrP85v2y2T7@hz@kpfhTTxJD@H9nQAnsrmpfOVHUwN2A5By9yn1erW52Ttt1xDdenm3afH55abb3tw/bxYdr@Fe5frO8PpcmMvRPgGB@hxDXZkiwdPHrj4vr59PtLYwGxhbGWxjfw7iDcQ/jAcbjc3q2QFsY4jnAV8Honk8NSDYg2YBkA5INSDYg2YBkA5LNI4wnGBwGSDcChoShvr253d69@/Gnn3/59bff//gsVA8XFNLhePry1/Ppobv@Gw)

Answer (score 5):

## 1. 3var (1 byte)

### Toolbox

```
['elf', 'cubix', 'sml-mlton', 'forte', 'logicode', 'python1', '3var']
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e.0@BGN`ceghilnoprtvwz}'
```

### Code

```
p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##My5LLPr/v@D/fwA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbNbiM3DD7HT@EaKGIDO0HG22STogsUvfTWF9gsdjUSPSNbI6n6sT0L9NlTktLY2f4cNPwoiRRJkRz5KQ3Obl@NsH1cflx@Wt0/iK6F1bvVNorOEHh/FAHJBxzPz/gRjQcRmhSAVoVMWRgzEVTKe6K9s8yb3pnHp56hlrzb@CHLAyFvGjUJ4/rvmEYaEaOWddL2llCQk8sMrDOKF2OEsTNTI@JbrpffLVoRR@JzB6HXli048elnh99OxIEIyXQgxkJsIcnqAyOIJ3FmtMu2hytqnp@IMSwehBym4s0FbwujbbMz4jAznXNmxrsSDMYYrB1jLWwja5i63OEt9JlskxQc2zMqjsomFSqC0laQWgl4MrkgB9RZKNpqdBEcMJaubBxAKb5ZOWi6NqmtFaOzTT1tzwGRRkdeNW6fA3kv3W6HQZFB@8SsVbqCI5wZnOjr/WxlEFMxKUwxlcNjI13RFhs8k25D5k6zOOWOolGuh@9bgdQjiyr0ZeQDFSSXyQGFWjlaYGAEmxhRLGEUqL96ACOtsQ4Y3V7PVDpFhkCg4DZXxyAJ@h41Sewwzx2dtYNghVWOIeXkTgfosAIYssFEmjjAPBc1e18RJcXOSbZj51iPCwkqHZqeSWUDpkJfAU/loIHNuIQNU1HqxCf0ZvKDuwC0gVShtTTF85hiF//6gHXCVI/A1Lkjxb6PZOMg4qG4MIhpDvDQyYFkBzjPVU5x1DZBKC7taTS5o6W94IP24iga58Hu1eEf7HPli1FNJzrAoi8X8mZ@noHSaJjWYO8dz2SjxUwfEByag7OCgaNDDwa4Gg4umQJY2ohuCmg9Y83KjTlS3mP5zplhnJlRJpW0jLnYOcPdYBRBu1qYo0iDlrEgw@QIQXPsRnHGFCagLeVys1UzYwo4zGpwir5pt6fct3nE/nUqS05ETfpdtweZ9BGaa1vArGJVTiY8lsBAerwImPgDJG6ryOmmp4Lw3HYIYO4/VPpIdOBl9L@WjucG4Um3dycIc3JfmbmcfQCTVUGO@nk8UYL4HDz/THyOA0XZTwdmqVlFBkGMWjUR29JYVvhSPP@g2gvaXlHjJz9d2PeIqDCw9x4gMeDCDVSsY/O22wYI0HOnChSTbLgLEuaMCXDmNd7qFE8555mUHhDQN/4xFdCQUaGkfMiRDo9YDIIpuYPdHL695TAhwF4n@qw5OBEUfzGfcuRkjBAdhScOwl87E9e1LIDvOfKFxSHhhqJDmyKHf9MBGI3djolpRlPaRbQYIl6z7jRyg4lu5OjHP43mnsSFL0WKMy7qkwiB7UuhfAW1/DiNtA@3OSZnuvokDX@53hKM3ojEFqUBXxBCMcpQSKKOivcw1cSjvndxG73re@5@KeTRX@dzSIbtyvhH5yTPVmEuO9aerRFjx/eYbcAT67vmSKNc01FHfMQ0LN1YSHNvPeoUyc3ToIMpFG33gt8yJx2ZOHwNlL50ihTiKZPl39Dfz6969HhVS@ylg9HdYuFdTFrhQwsD9kVbn9N6s6Dq7dwZZ@cZ@k2XGYxDWtfpDcoH2@Ns1Xc3qod1UYlrC7TOwNKAXVeNm@Uvyw8/L24snGgGBVerxU3ZZl1azvMuXKC2yyqMcjd03F32Cm9sXXdscPqqj9@Nn9DAtOa9@F9Quge0efOufdz8OBsTN5vPi5uq@U547P7qqnGBf7jlFzo70Ftl3W43xWqKw7@sXteFTbWbN6HsHDQseA5C5TfLHz4u2@3Tf/jDWoo/9SQ5hP93BpXg7qr2jRNFDd4NSs7Rq9zX1epu77RdR/rHq4tNm6@vr@328f7xafHpFt8qt@@Wt/z@IXCpUWL4cUBg/iERrl3x9vPi9uV8f4@jxbHF8R7HTzgecDzi@IDj6SW9WKQdDvkS8As4di/nFiVblGxRskXJFiVblGxRskXJ9gnHMw6BA6VbiUPhgLv7X3/7/Y@vEnq8FosmHk/f/rr9Gw)

Answer (score 4):

## 3. [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 3 bytes

```
`
2
```

Exploits a syntax error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P4HL6P9/AA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbrjyM1DP98/SvKAtpWuqx2euwL3QmBQHxBiA8IhG5Pd5kkM5M2k4Q82s5J/O2L7WTaPR4fEv/ysGM7thM/pcHZzZPhto/LN8u3F9c3vG3UxcuLTeStQfBqzwOQO2gPD9Bx5hUPLAWFq1ykzI2ZEErpPdLeWRqb3pnb@56gFrTb@CGLHSJvmJy4cf0nAyYMj1GLOml7iyiIyWUC1hlJizGqsTUT4/H5qBefLFoeRxznVoVeW9LgQKcfHfQtjwMS5GkVHwuxhSSrd4RUPPAjoS7bXp0Re7jHgSH2wMUwFWtOeFMG2rLO8N08aJ0zM@6KMwiDszrCmlsmqpva3MIt9Bl1E@gc2xMqhgqWCuVBastRrFBwMpogBpBZKOhqdGEcwJeubByUlHSzYtB4bUJby0dnWT1tSw4RRkdaNW6bA1ovXNeBU0TQPtHQSl3BXh0JHLD3ftYy8KmoFKaYyuGRCVekRQZn4m2I3Gpix9iR2Mr10H1LJfRIrBJsGelAqZLLaIAEqeQtZdSobCKEvlQjB/nVAjXiGslQo9vqmQonUREV0LnsbJhKHPu9Ro4O4tzhWZ0KllvpCGJMdjqoFjKAICmMhMVBzXNRk/UVYVB0TpAenSM5LiRV6cB6InUYIBT6CmgqB61IjZPbIBSFTnRCbyY/uBMAHVAUaItTNA8hdrKvD5AnRPWoiDq3R9/3EXUceNwVEwY@zQ4eWjEg76COc5ajH7VNKhSTtthYbnFpy@mgLd9z5ryyW7n7x/ChjotSrOWtgqQvF/Jsfp5RpdAQrc7eOprJRvOZ3gDYsZ2znIDDQ3dGUTbsXDIFELfh7RRAe8KahBuzx7iH9J0jwzgzo4wicRlisXWGqsHIg3Y1MUeeBi1iQYbIXgVNvhv5EUIYgbYYy2wj54EpYDeLgSnsU7fF2Ld5hPp1KEuOR43yXbtVIum9YueyAFFFopxIcCyCAeV4HiDwB5WorMJIsx4TwlPZQQCxf1PpLdKBlsH@mjqeCoRH2d4dVJiD@zyY09kHZbIsyGE9jwcMEJ@Dp8fE5zigl/20oyEWq0gg8FFLFqEsjWWFLsXTA9Wc0OaMmJ/8dBq@AoSJAbV3pxIBStyAyTqy59U2qKB6qlQBfZINVUHEFDFBHWmNtjpJU855IqUGBLCNHqYCGCoVSsiHHPHwCMnAiaI5UM3Vx@cjCAhlzxN91uScqCT1EE85UjBGFR26Jw7cnysT5bUogO450oXFIcGGIkObwgev6aAIjW1HxLDRlHIRLbiI1qw7jFRgohvJ@/FPo6kmUeILnuKMi/jEQyD9Uig9x5IfpxH3wTZH5IhXn4ShnvItqdEbnkijNMAPgktCWRWSsKLCPUw18LDuncwG6/qeql8KefTn@RySIb0yvOgU5NlKiGVH0rM1fGzpHrMNcGL91@yxlWva6wifGEbczKo019a9ThHNPAw6mEJBd8/pL3PQkYiD30CpS4eILp4yav4R7H33pEcPV7WEWjoY3S4W3sWkJXy0wGHvtfU5rdYLzN7WHWF2nsFnusyAH9KqTq@BP9geZqu8q1HerIpIWFuAdkYtjbKrKnG9fL28@3rxwqoDzgDjxcXiRdlmXVrO8y6coLbLygx8L/C4q@wl3Niq7ljD9Fke/RvfgoJpRXvhXZC6V6Dz@mVzu/5yViau1@8WL6rkK@6h@suzxAW8cMv3eHbAv8qq2ayL1uiHf2m9qgvrqjdtAt7ZaZDw5IQ6Xi8/e7NsNvf/YQ9JKfbUk8QQ/t8YEAK7q9hnRhQxcDfAOXuvjj5cXFxtnbariG@8POm0/vD01Gxur@8eFm8v4a9y@XJ5eUpNHNCfAMH8DiGuxRDh9vLd4vLxeH0NrYG2gfYK2lfQbqDdQruDdv@YoG@hiccAvYLWPR4b4GuArwG@Bvga4GuArwG@Bviae2gP0Dg04G4ENAlNLT//4ur61c3962@@/e77H3786edffv3t9z@E6nq4oPHPkPaH48e/Ho933eXf)

Answer (score 4):

## 5. J, 3 Bytes

```
5|9
```

Performs 5 mod 9, outputting 4

[Next toolbox!](https://tio.run/##dVZZjxs3DH5e/wrXbbA2kFnseLtXm6AHWvShRduHogeyaaKRNDOydUWH7QnQ374lqRl70@NBw4@SSJEUyZEfUu/s@lEz28X5y/mrxeU1a2q5eL5YR9ZoBFc7FoDcwri/hw@rvGShSkHiKuMpM60HhEJ4j7RzlnjdOX1z1xFUnHZr32e@ReR1JQamXfcBU3HNYlR8nLSdRRT44DIB67SgxRilafRQsfiU6/gHi5ZFg3xuZOiUJQv2dPrBwbdhsUeCMo1kphBbSLJqS0jGPTsQarPt5AlV93fIaBIPjPdD8eaI14VRtmo1205M45yecFuCQRiC1RJWzFZ8DFOTG7iFLqNtHINjO0LFUV6lQlkQyjJUyyWcjC7wHnQWCrZqVQR7iKUrG3spBN0s7xVeG1fWMuNsNZ62oYBwrSKtarfJAb3nrm0hKDwon4i1Qo1gJw8E9vj1frIysKGYFIaYyuGx4q5oixWcibfBc6NIHHNH4CjXQ/ctJFeGRAX4YuhAIZPL6IAArRQtqaWRNhHCWErDQP/ogTS4RjqkcRs1Ue4EGiIDBrc6OSYTw@9OoUQLee7wrFYGy6xwBDEnWxVkAxVAkAxGUsVeTnNRkfcjwqRoHSc7Wkd6XEhypH3VERnZAKnQjYCmclCSzDiGDVKRq0QndHrwvTsCsAFVgbU4RfOQYkf/ugB1QlQZSdS5Hca@i2hjz@K2uNCzYQpw3/AeZXt5mKoc46hskqG4tMFR5QaXNowO2rAdq5yXdiO2/2DvR74YVTWskVD05UKezE8zsjQaomOwN45mslZsotcAttXWWUbA4aFbLakati7pAkhas2YIYD1hRcq13mHeQ/lOmaGdnlBGlbgMudg4Td3AsKDcWJiGpV7xWJAmspNBUewMO0AKI1AWc7lai4nRBWwnNTCF39RuMPdtNtC/9mXJsahQv2s2kie1k9WpLUBWkSrHExyLoEc9ngVI/F4maqvAqarDgvDUdhBA7l@P9AZpT8vg/1g6nhqER93e7WWYkvvETOXsg9RZFOSwn8c9JojPwdPPxOfYY5T9sCUWm1UkEJhRoorQlkxZoUvx9IOqj2h9QpUf/HBkrwBhYUDv3cpEgAo3YLGa6mm3DTLIjjpVwJhkTV0QMWVMkAdao61O0JRznkjpAQF8ox9TARUaFUrKhxzx8AjFwIiiO9DN5funHCSEtKeJLisKTpSCvpBPOVIyRhkdhif2zJ86E9U1L4DuOdKFxT7BhqJD6SIHf9NeEjJNS0RXRpd2ES2EiNas2xtqMNEZin58pxX1JCp8zlKccFGfWAhkXwrly7Dlx8HgPtjmiBzw6hPX9KV6S9J4zRJZlHp4QTBBKMtCEnZUuIdhTDzse0e3wbuuo@6XQjb@NJ9D0mRXhj86JXm2AnLZkfZsNTMN3WO2AU4c3zU7HOWadirCI6Yi6crKNPXWnUoR3dz3KuhCwXbP6C2zV5GIg9dA6Uv7iCEeMlr@Hvx9/aiMh6uaQy/ttWpmM@9iUgIeWhCwN8r6nJarGVZv4w4wO83gb7rMQBzScpxegXywHcyO@i6MuF4WlbA2A@u0nGtpl6PG1fzF/Paz2ZmVe5wBwcVidla2WZfm07wLR6jsfBQGuTM87iJ7ATe2HHesYPqkj96Nr8DAtKS98F8QqpNg8@p5fbN6NhkTV6vXs7NR8wXz0P3FSeMM/nDzN3h2wLfKsl6vitUYh39ZvRwXVqPdtAlkp6BBwVMQRn41/@jlvF7f/Yc/pKX4M57E@/D/zoAS2D2qfeJEUQN3A5JT9Ebu7WJxsXHKLiP@48XRptXbx8fby9ub29mrc3iqnD@fnx8rExl6EiCYfkOIn7x5SeDUW85fz84fDpeXMGoYaxhXMD6FcQ3jBsYtjLuH9GCBNjD4Q4CvhNE@HGqQrEGyBskaJGuQrEGyBskaJOs7GPcwGAyQrjkMAUPOFx9/8uzisr66@/zFF19@9fU33373/Q8//vTzL7/@9vsfDw9/vuWy7Xq12Wpj3@Xd/jC8/@vhcNue/w0)

Comment: I pasted in the wrong toolbox link, it should be correct now

Comment: you still need the answer to output 4

Comment: In the question: *Each answer will: Output the number of valid answers coming before it*. There are **four** valid answers before this one, so your program must output `4`. If you cannot make that happen, please delete your answer.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the requirements. I've fixed it.

Comment: Can you post a TIO link?  Also I'm pretty sure that's 9 mod 5, not 5 mod 9

Comment: That's 9 mod 5.

Answer (score 4):

## 15. [Half-Broken Car in Heavy Traffic](https://git.metanohi.name/hbcht.git/)

```
# 
^
^
^
^
^
^
^
^
^
^
^
^   >>v
  < ^ 
^ >   v
  ov ^
^< <  <
```

Outputs is in cell -2.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0hKzij5/19ZgSsOO1RQULCzK@NSULBRiAMqUrADCoC4@WUKQFkboLCCzf//X/PydZMTkzNSAQ)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbXduM2EH22vkLRycZSYjqm3DfZk957L5bPGgRBEhIIYFEkcVP@Os/OzICUvCkP4NwBMBWDAW0XGqPn94rp2o@fjG8mJ@esyMXkaDL3rFAITtfMAbmEcX0NH5ZZwVwWnMBVxkNkSnUIy9JapLXRxKvaqIurmqDktFvZJvIVIquysmPK1C8wGVfMe8n7SV1rRI53JhLQRpW06L1oC9VlzD/kav7Coma@RT4WwtVSkwcbsr418C2Yb5CgTCFYm4hOJGi5IiT8hm0JVVHXYo@y6ytkFIk7xpsuRbPD88RInVWKrQamMEYNuErJIAzJqghLpjPep6mIBZxCHdE3jsnRNaEUKM9CosyVUjNUywVYxhB4AzoTBV@VTIIN5NKkjY0oSzpZ3kg8Ni61Zq3RWW9tSQnhSnpaVWYZHUbPTVVBUriTNhCrS9mDtdgS2ODX2sFLx7rkkut8SMZ9xk3S5jOwiafBYyFJHGunxJGOh867FFy2JFpCLC0ZLEUwEQMoQStlSyjRCh0IYS5Fy0B/H4FocY10CIeJzPZBiMDwu5a4WkFNG9RbCaeZLg1BrL9KOlFAtRMk55BkvhHDnJcUaY@wACrDyWZlSI9xQfS0yWoiPevg2Ose0FR0UpAbuxRB2XEZyEKtOtuYHQAfUBV4i1M0D@W0i692cCeIylYQNWaNea49@tgwv0ohNKwbktkUvEHZRmyHGy1x6CBcCmmJI4sFLi0ZGVqyNcuMFXpZrv7BXvd8ciorWCHggptSvDg/zIjUVIj2yV4amolKsoGeA1hlK6MZAYNGV0pQ5a9MUAmQtGJF58B7wpKUK7XGGoerKnkyq4waUESVuAx1VxhFN79lTpr@ErYsNJL7hBSRtXCScteyLZQrAqmxbrN5OTAqgdWgBqbwG6ol1rmOLfSqTVoyzEvUb4ql4EGuRbZvAVBVpMrwAGYRNKjHMgdF3ohALRQ4mdVY/JZaDAKo/fOeXiBtaBni76@JpWZgUbc1G@GG4t4zw9W1TqhYJmSwd/sNFoiNztLDYaNvMMu2WxGLjckTcKyVZeahBbVphQ7F0mOU79B8jzLb2W7HngLCiwF9diUCAbq4Di9rmz3srE44UVNXcpiTqKjjIaaKcWJLa7TVlDRljCWSeoCD2OgRSiBDp1wqeRc9GvdwGRhRDAc6t3j@kIOCEHo/UUdJyfGipC/UU/RUjF54g@nxDbP7zkT3midA5@zpwHwTYEPSIVWSg5ezEYTaoiKislalduE1pIjWtNm01GC8aSn7/pmS1JPo4nMW/ICT@sCcI/@CS1@G7d13Le6DbYbIFo8@cEVfum9BtFaxQB6FBv4WWEkoikQCdlQ4h64vPOx7u7Ahurqm7hdcbO1@PrqgyK8IrzcVedQl1LIh7VEr1hZ0jlE7sNj/w6xxpGNaSw8/LBlJZ1qEobeuZfAY5qaRTiUKvltG/y0b6YkYePlTX9p4THEX0fPnEO/tvWwtHNUYemmjZDEaWeODLOGnChL2VGobw3Q2wttbmC3MDjP4JKcZyEOY9tMzkHe6htle33Fbnk@TSlgbgXdKjJXQ017jbPzm@PLx6ECLDc6A4GQyOkjbtAnjYd64HZR63AuD3AGaO462hBOb9jtmML3XR/@IN@BgmNJeeBdKWQvweXaUX8weDc742ex2dNBrPmYWun@51ziCF278FG07/C@Z5vNZ8hrz8C@vp/3CrPebNoHskDS48JSEnsck5POr/wiHlKRwekO8cf8fCyiB3bLa2URn9nbRQA8fBJhswLmB2iGzPXc3mRwvjdRTj@9/ufN3dnd/n88vzs5ORzeH8M9yeDQ@fPBri@yDtpJYKGME@@tyeDs6XGxPTmDkMOYwTmGcwTiHcQHjEsbVIiw00AIGXzj4ChjVYpuDZA6SOUjmIJmDZA6SOUjmIJlfwbiGwWCAdM5hlDBAPq/GL01efvTK4nA6e/W1o@z49ZP52fnF5dX14zeevPX2O@@@9/4HH3708Seffvb5F19@9fU33373/Q8//vTzL7/eLBa3T@9YwUtR1Y1crlSr7TPnQ9xsu@e//f7Hn4vtZXX4lzYZh99p8Tc)

Comment: For number 16, I don't think it is possible in TRANSCRIPT or Emojicode. Transcript requires a `>` before lines that do stuff like print, and Emojicode needs emojis.

Comment: For 16 in scala, how much of this is needed? `object A{def main(a:Array[String]){print(Integer.parseInt("F",16))}}` [TIO](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8/z8/KSs1uUTBsTolNU0hNzEzTyPRyrGoKLEyOrikKDMvPVazugBIl2h45pWkpqcW6RUkFhWnAjkaSm5KOoZmmpq1tf//AwA). Most of that is the main, so can that be left out?

Comment: @andrewarchi You can write an function that returns 16.  That might save you.  I don't know scala so thats about as helpful as I can be.  However we currently have *all* of the characters so I wouldn't worry about using them.

Comment: @WheatWizard The two changes that I see are hbcht which I used and emojicode which seems to be removed from the generator program entirely. I assume the emojicode change was intentional. I didn't do that.

Comment: @Riley Ah I see all is good then.

Answer (score 3):

## 6. [Forte](https://github.com/judofyr/forter)

Uses `\n 187-DENPUT`

```
1 PUT 71-18
7 END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/99QISA0RMHcUNfQgstcwdXP5f9/AA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbrjxs1EP/c/BUhUC6R6tNtjntBK14SCIGEEBIP9Urrtb27Try260eSrcTffsyMd5MrlA/2/Mb2jGfG47H9kDpn1w@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@TAHuatGhbKcO0y3HOGqbVCgubbCxXOPUhtNGG77jzHllN3L7L/Zu5ItRrOa1gktfDuTR@DSiSqEhOgZ742gkG80negVgy7bOcgION90aRbdh65IpgKQNr4cA1hPWpNyYHeY9XN8pM4wzE8qoEqchF2tnqBr0PGg3Xsyep06LWJAhslNBU@x6foAURqAt5jJby4kxBWwnNTCEfWo2mPs291C/9mXK8ahRv6s3SiS9U@xUFiCrSJUTCbZF0KEezwMkfqcSlVXgNGvxQngqOwgg969Geo20o2nwf7w6ngqER93e7VWYkvvETNfZB2WyLMhhPY97TBCfg6fHxOfYYZT9sCUWi1UkEHivJYtQlvoyQ4fi6YGqjmh9QswPfjiyl4DwYkDt3apEgC5uwMvas8fVNqigWqpUAWOSDVVBxJQxQR1ojpY6SUPOeSKlBgTwjR6mAhgaFUrKhxxx8wiXgRNFd6Caq3ePOUgIZU8DbdYUnKgk9ZBPOVIyRhUdhid23J8qE91rUQCdc6QDi12CBUWHNkUOXtNOEerrhohhvSnlIloIEc1Zt@@pwETXU/TjW6OpJtHFFzzFCRf1iYdA9qVQeo4lPw49roNljsgBjz4JQz3dt6R6b3gii1IHPwguCWVVSMKKCucwjImHde/oNnjXtlT9Usi9P43nkAzZleFFpyTPVkIuO9KereF9TeeYbYAdx3/NDls5pp2O8IlhJM2sSlNt3ekU0c19p4MpFGz3nP4yex2JOPgNlLq0jxjiIaPl78DfVw@693BUc6ilndH1bOZdTFrCRwsC9lpbn9NyNcPbW7sDjE4j@EyXEYhDWo7DK5APtoXRUd95L6@WRSXMzcA6o@ZG2eWocTV/Pr/5fPbEqj2OgOBiMXtSllmX5tO4C0eo7XwUBrknuN159hJObDmuWMHwSR/9G1@CgWlJa@FdkLpVYPPqWXW9ejoZE1erV7Mno@Zz7qH6y5PGGbxw89e4d8C/yrJar4rVGIf/WL0cJ1aj3bQIZKegwYWnIIz8av7Ri3m1vv2AP6Sl@DPuJLrw/86AElg9qn3kRFEDZwOSU/RG7s1icb5x2i4jvvHyaNPqzcNDtb6@uL2avTyDv8rZs/nZ8WoiMz0/iB/9dWndqaYg@8Hn8@zV7Oz@cHEBrYK2hnYJ7TNoV9Cuod1Au71P0NfQxH2AXkFr7g8VyFUgV4FcBXIVyFUgV4FcBXLVLbQ7aBwaSFcCmoSmFh9/8vTT@zN2fnH5xfMXX3719Tfffvf9Dz/@9PMvv/72@x9/3t//9Uaopu30Zmt669/m3f4wvPv7/nDTnP0D)

Comment: no `(` -> scheme-chez , scala. no `1` nor `!` -> logicode

Comment: @marcosm Good point, I hope my toolbox didn't stop the chain ;_;

Comment: logicode actually has a problem with the fact that the characters to write `out` are missing. I managed to get `out ?+?+?+0` to produce the binary expression of `6`....which appears to be valid if "that is the standard way of outputting in a language" is allowed here, which for logicode would be mostly true. There is a convert-to-ascii, but without an `=` you can't assign `?+?+?+0`-like expressions to a variable *to* convert, nor can you wrap in parenthesis, due to a lack of `(`. `?+?+?+0` by itself is valid code...but produces no output. `+` is *also* missing, so even *that* won't work...

Comment: no `E` -> Forte (program would loop forever without an END keyword) as no `P`,`R`,`N`, and `T` for the `PRINT` command.
I cannot find a language definition for elf, assembly-as, or mlton (or at least, not enough in order to determine how to produce output).
no `(`,`o`,`s`,`;` -> Javascript (unable to call `console.log(...)`), no `r` for `alert` (if tio allowed it).

Comment: @Draco18s You don't need brackets for JavaScript since backtick and `6` are both legal, so you could do ``console.log`6` ``, the problem would be getting access to `console.log` since `s` isn't available

Comment: @BusinessCat I wasn't aware of that syntax. Neat. But yes, the `o` and `s` are still missing. And no `a` to try and fiddle things into an `eval`

Answer (score 3):

## 7. [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 7 bytes

```ml
fun$n=6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/8/rTRPJc/W7H9ZYo5CvIKtQkFRZl6JhmdeiV5JfnAJkJOuoaKhqan5HwA) This declares a function `$` which takes any argument and returns `6`, eg. by calling with `$()`.

[New toolbox.](https://tio.run/##dVbrkxs1DP98@StCGEgyU9/c5rgXtLyHx8DA8IZpSuv1enedeG3XjyTbGfjXD0neTa5QPtj6ybZkSZZluz621qzuNTdNmD6ZPp1dXPGykLNHs1XgpUZwueMeyA20uzvoOHOSexa9xFkuYuJa9wiryjmkjTXE68bq69uGoBK0Wrs2iS0ip1nVc22b1xgmNA9BiWHQNAaRF71NBIzVFU2GILtS94yHh1wjXps0PHTIp1L6RhmyYE@7Hyz0JQ8tEpQpJe8yMZlEo7aEZNjzA6E6mUaeELu7RUaTuOei7bM3R7zKjDKs1nw7MqW1esR1DgZhCFZNWHHDxBCmMpVwCk1C2wQGxzSEsqOCxUy5r5ThqFZI2BldEC3ozBRs1SoLthBLmxe2sqroZEWr8NiEMoZ31rBhtw0FRGgVaFbbTfLovbB1DUERXrlIrKnUAHbyQGCPvXOjlZ732STfh5g3D0zYrC0w2BNPQ6RSkTjmToUtHw@ddyWF6ki0Al862rCS0SZ0oAKtFC2pZSdNJISxlB0H/YMHssM50iE7u1EjFbZCQ6TH4LKTYzJy7HcKJWrIc4t71dIbbipLEHOyVl6WcAMIksFIWGjlOBYUeT8gTIraCrKjtqTH@igH2rKGyMB6SIVmADSUvJJkxjFskIpCRdqh0b1r7RGADagKrMUhGocUO/rXeLgnRFUniVq7w9g3AW1sedhmF1rejwFuS9GibCsP4y3HOCoTpc8ubbCxVOLUhtNGG77jzDppNtX2X@zdwGejWMlLCZc@H8iD8XFE5kJDdAj2xtJI0oqP9ArAlm2t4QQsbrrVkm7D1kadAUlrXvYerCesSLnWO8x7uL5jZmirR5RQJU5DLpZWUzXouFd2uJgdj60SISNNZCe9oth1/AApjEAZzGW2qkZGZ7Ad1cAQ9rHeYO6b1EH92ucpy4NC/bbcSBHVTrJTWYCsIlVWRNgWQYt6HPeQ@K2MVFaBU6zBC@Go7CCA3L8a6DXSlqbB/@HqOCoQDnU7u5d@TO4TM15n56VOVUYW63nYY4K45B09Ji6FFqPs@i2xWKwCAc87VbEAZanLM3Qojh6o4ohWJ8Rc7/ojewkILwbU3q2MBOjierysHXtYbb30sqFK5TEmSVMVREwZ4@WB5miprWjIWkck1wAPvtHDlAFDo3xOeZ8Cbh7gMnCi6A5Uc/nqIQcJIc1poEmKghNkRT3kUwqUjEEGi@EJLXenykT3WmRA5xzowEIbYUHWoXSWg9e0lYS6siaiWadzuQgGQkRzxu47KjDBdhT98FIrqkl08QWPYcRZfeTek33R555jyQ99h@tgmSVywKOPQlNP9y3KzmkeyaLYwg@CV4SSzCRiRYVz6IfEw7p3dBu8axqqftGnzp3Gk4@a7ErwolOSJ1NBLlvSnozmXUnnmIyHHYd/zQ5bPqadCvCJYSTNjIxjbd2pGNDNfau8zhRsd5z@MnsViFj4DeS6tA8Y4j6h5a/A32f3qnNwVFOopa1W5WTibIiqgo8WBOy5Mi7FxXKCt7e0BxgdR/CZziMQh7gYhpcg700Do4O@8666WmSVMDcB67ScamkWg8bl9PH05v3JmZF7HAHB2WxylpcZG6fjuPVHqMx0EAa5M9zuPLkKTmwxrFjC8Ekf/RufgoFxQWvhXahUI8Hm5aPievnOaExYLp9NzgbN59xB9a9OGifwwk2f494e/yqLYrXMVmMc/mP1YphYDnbTIpAdgwYXnoIw8MvpW0@mxer2Df6QluzPsJNo/f87A0pg9aD2gRNZDZwNSI7RG7gXs9n5xiqzCPjGV0ebli/u74vV9ep2NXk6h7/K/NF0Pr44iB98b5F9UEaQfeOLmddBPs@fTebrw8UFtALaCtoltPegXUG7hnYD7XYdoS@hibWHXkKr14cC5AqQK0CuALkC5AqQK0CuALniFtodNA4NpAsBrYImZ2@/8@56vmTnF5dXHzz@8KOPP/n0s8@/@PKrr7/59rvvf/jxp59/@fW33/9Yr/98IWTTqs1Wd9a93O0P/au//l4fbur5Pw) Powershell is the newly added language.

Comment: Looking at the new toolbox...No `(`, no `1`, no `!`, no `E`, no `P`, no `s`. The same characters that were precluding the other languages are still missing. :\

Answer (score 3):

## 23. [DStack](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DStack), 5 bytes

```
222cK
```

**Explanation**

DStack is read in pairs and moves the cursor one char at a time, so the instructions become `22`, `22`, `22`, and `cK`.

```
22  Multiplies register by 10 (initially 0), adds 2
22  Multiplies register by 10, adds 2
2c  Does nothing
cK  Displays number of the register
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SykuSUzO/v/fyMgo2fv/fwA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4pxyttuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5bfoA3ncAbuJwoO1CY/T8VjFd@/HD8fXk5IwVuZgcTeaeFQrB6Zo5IBcwrq7gwzIrmMuCE7jKeIhMqQ5hWVqLtDaaeFUbdX5ZE5ScdivbRL5CZFVWdkyZ@hkm44p5L3k/qWuNyPHORALaqJIWvRdtobqM@btczZ9Z1My3yMdCuFpq8mBD1rcGvgXzDRKUKQRrE9GJBC1XhITfsC2hKupa7FF2dYmMInHHeNOlaHZ4nhips0qx1cAUxqgBVykZhCFZFWHJdMb7NBWxgFOoI/rGMTm6JpQC5VlIlLlSaoZquQDLGAJvQGei4KuSSbCBXJq0sRFlSSfLG4nHxqXWrDU6660tKSFcSU@ryiyjw@i5qSpICnfSBmJ1KXuwFlsCG/xaO3jpWJdccp0PybjPuEnafAY28TR4LCSJY@2UONLx0HmXgsuWREuIpSWDpQgmYgAlaKVsCSVaoQMhzKVoGejvIxAtrpEO4TCR2T4IERh@1xJXK6hpg3or4TTTpSGI9VdJJwqodoLkHJLMN2KY85Ii7REWQGU42awM6TEuiJ42WU2kZx0ce90DmopOCnJjlyIoOy4DWahVZxuzA@ADqgJvcYrmoZx28dUO7gRR2Qqixqwxz7VHHxvmVymEhnVDMpuCNyjbiO1woyUOHYRLIS1xZLHApSUjQ0u2ZpmxQi/L1b/Yq55PTmUFKwRccFOKZ@eHGZGaCtE@2UtDM1FJNtAzAKtsZTQjYNDoSgmq/JUJKgGSVqzoHHhPWJJypdZY43BVJU9mlVEDiqgSl6HuCqPo5rfMSdNfwpaFRnKfkCKyFk5S7lq2hXJFIDXWbTYvB0YlsBrUwBR@Q7XEOtexhV61SUuGeYn6TbEUPMi1yPYtAKqKVBkewCyCBvVY5qDIGxGohQInsxqL31KLQQC1f9bTc6QNLUP8/TWx1Aws6rZmI9xQ3HtmuLrWCRXLhAz2br/BArHRWXo4bPQNZtl2K2KxMXkCjrWyzDy0oDat0KFYeozyHZrvUWY72@3YU0B4MaDPrkQgQBfX4WVts7ud1QknaupKDnMSFXU8xFQxTmxpjbaakqaMsURSD3AQGz1CCWTolEsl76JH4x4uAyOK4UDnFk/vclAQQu8n6igpOV6U9IV6ip6K0QtvMD2@YXbfmehe8wTonD0dmG8CbEg6pEpy8HI2glBbVERU1qrULryGFNGaNpuWGow3LWXfP1GSehJdfM6CH3BSH5hz5F9w6cuwvfuuxX2wzRDZ4tEHruhL9y2I1ioWyKPQwN8CKwlFkUjAjgrn0PWFh31vFzZEV9fU/YKLrd3PRxcU@RXh9aYij7qEWjakPWrF2oLOMWoHFvt/mDWOdExr6eGHJSPpTIsw9Na1DB7D3DTSqUTBd8vov2UjPREDL3/qSxuPKe4iev4U4r25la2FoxpDL22ULEYja3yQJfxUQcIeSW1jmM5GeHsLs4XZYQaf5DQDeQjTfnoG8k7XMNvrO27Ls2lSCWsj8E6JsRJ62mucjd8YXzwYHWixwRkQnExGB2mbNmE8zBu3g1KPe2GQO0Bzx9GWcGLTfscMpvf66B/xGhwMU9oL70IpawE@z47y89m9wRk/m92MDnrNx8xC9y/3Gkfwwo0foW2H/yXTfD5LXmMe/uP1tF@Y9X7TJpAdkgYXnpLQ85iEfH75nHBISQqnN8Qb9/@xgBLYLaudTXRmbxcN9PBOgMkGnBuoHTLbc48nk@OlkXrq8f0vd/7OHt/e5vPz8/P7o@tD@Gc5PBof3vm1RfZOW0F2eKsQ75945J5b2Ic3o8PF9uQERg5jDuMUxn0YZzDOYVzAuFyEhQZawOALB18Bo1psc5DMQTIHyRwkc5DMQTIHyRwk80sYVzAYDJDOOYwSBsjn1fiFyYsv3Xt5cTidvfLqUXb82kl@ev/s/OLy6sHrbzx8862333n3vfc/@PCjjz/59LPPv/jyq6@/@fa773/48aeff/n1erG4@e3RY1aUoqobuVStNvaJ8yGuN9vu6e9//PnXYntRHf6tTcbhf1v8Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## 27. [Assembly (x64, Linux, as)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html)

```
.text
  .global _start
_start:
movl $len,%edx
movl $msg,%ecx
movl $1,%ebx
movl $4,%eax
int $0x80
movl $0,%ebx
movl $1,%eax
int $0x80
.data
msg:
.byte 0b110010,0b110110
len = . - msg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BCsMwCAbgu0/hobu1QWGHUdizDLOGMjAtLDLSp89ka2EMBP3kR5RSUo66DVJaC5aqAWKYdY2ieCsmT4NvGyGvL8VO09Kf0lR35jI77wfZEQ@cHVLhsRh2VC@0r@k3w/@ZMIkJ@NkRQtwsIUVmIqb@M3iBv4BXDDigx6C1Nw)

## Explanation

I don't really know Assembly as, and information online seems hard to find ,so this is modified from the [Hello World test on TIO](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioTests/blob/master/HelloWorldTests/assembly-as.json).

The main issue here is that we lack the `2` byte, (turns out we did, but hey looks like I saved a 2 for the next answer) this makes it relatively hard to print `26`.  We can't use raw ascii or even Hexadecimal (`0x32`) so I ended up using binary.

```
msg:
.byte 0b110010,0b110110
```

Tells it to output the two bytes `2` and `6`.

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZf@M0EH9uPkUIP0gCdVmn9ILlvu/7bMpWlmVbiSxpdSTxcnxrnsvMyE66sDzI8x9Jc2o0su1CY/TiTjFd@/Eb4@vJgzNW5GJyPFl4VigEpxvmgFzAuLqCD8usYC4LTuAq4yEypTqEZWkt0tpo4lVt1PllTVBy2q1sE/kakVVZ2TFl6qeYjCvmveT9pK41Isc7Ewloo0pa9F60heoy5u9zNX9qUTPfIh8L4WqpyYMtWd8Z@BbMN0hQphCsTUQnErRcExJ@y3aEqqhrcUDZ1SUyisQd402XotnjRWKkzirF1gNTGKMGXKVkEIZkVYQl0xnv01TEAk6hjugbx@TomlAKlGchUeZKqRmq5QIsYwi8AZ2Jgq9KJsEGcmnSxkaUJZ0sbyQeG5das9borLe2ooRwJT2tKrOKDqPnpqogKdxJG4jVpezBRuwIbPFr7eClY11yyXU@JOM@4yZp8xnYxNPgsZAkjrVT4kjHQ@ddCi5bEi0hlpYMliKYiAGUoJWyJZRohQ6EMJeiZaC/j0C0uEY6hMNEZocgRGD43UhcraCmDeqthNNMl4Yg1l8lnSig2gmSc0gy34hhzkuKtEdYAJXhZLMypMe4IHraZDWRnnVw7HUPaCo6KciNfYqg7LgMZKFWnW3MHoAPqAq8xSmah3Lax1c7uBNEZSuIGrPBPNcefWyYX6cQGtYNyWwK3qBsI3bDjZY4dBAuhbTCkcUCl1aMDK3YhmXGCr0q1/9ir3o@OZUVrBBwwU0pnp4fZkRqKkT7ZK8MzUQl2UDPAKyztdGMgEGjayWo8tcmqARIWrGic@A9YUnKldpgjcNVlTyZVUYNKKJKXIa6K4yim98yJ01/CVsWGsl9QorIRjhJuWvZDsoVgdRYt9miHBiVwHpQA1P4DdUK61zHFnrVNi0Z5iXqN8VK8CA3Iju0AKgqUmV4ALMIGtRjmYMib0SgFgqczGosfkstBgHU/llPz5E2tAzx99fEUjOwqNuarXBDcR@Y4epaJ1QsEzLYu/0WC8RGZ@nhsNE3mGXbrYnFxuQJONbKMvPQgtq0Qodi6THK92hxQJntbLdnTwHhxYA@uxaBAF1ch5e1ze53ViecqKkrOcxJVNTxEFPFOLGjNdpqSpoyxhJJPcBBbPQIJZChUy6VvIsejXu4DIwohgOdWzy5z0FBCH2YqKOk5HhR0hfqKXoqRi@8wfT4htlDZ6J7zROgc/Z0YL4JsCHpkCrJwcvZCEJtURFRWatSu/AaUkRr2mxbajDetJR9/1hJ6kl08TkLfsBJfWDOkX/BpS/D9u67FvfBNkNkh0cfuKIv3bcgWqtYII9CA38LrCQURSIBOyqcQ9cXHva9fdgQXV1T9wsutvYwH11Q5FeE15uKPOoSatmQ9qgVaws6x6gdWOz/YTY40jFtpIcfloykMy3C0Fs3MngMc9tIpxIF3y2j/5at9EQMvPypL209priL6PkTiPfmTrYWjmoMvbRRshiNrPFBlvBTBQl7JLWNYTYf4e0tzA5mhxl8ktMM5CHM@uk5yDtdw2yv76Qtz2ZJJayNwDslxkroWa9xPn44vnhtdKTFFmdAcDIZHaVt2oTxMG/cHko97oVB7gjNnURbwonN@h1zmD7oo3/Ea3AwzGgvvAulrAX4PD/Oz@cvDM74@fxmdNRrPmEWun950DiCF278CG07/C@Z5Yt58hrz8B@vZ/3CvPebNoHskDS48JSEnsck5IvLZ4RDSlI4vSHeuP@PBZTAblntbaIzB7tooIf3Akw24NxA7ZDZnrudTE5WRuqZx/e/3Ps7v727yxfn51cXo@sp/LNMj8fT4TVC/MxixYX7fRF5agLT42n/kk9vRtPl7sEDGDmMBYxTGK/COINxDuMCxuUywLeAwZcOvgJGtdzlIJeDXA5yOcjlIJeDXA5yOcjllzCuYDAYIJ1zGCUMkM@r5ybPv7iczuYvvfzK6fnF1esP33zr7Xfefe/9Dz786ONPPv3s8y@@/Orrb7797vsffvzp519@vV4ub367rZrV2j6O2ye///HnX8vdRTX9W5uMw3@0@Ac)

Comment: That looks so ugly for something as trivial as printing `26`

Comment: I get a 2 when running the toolbox from either 25 or 26. You must have just forgotten to run it

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##SywuTs1NyqnUTSz@/1@voCgzr0RBychM6f9/AA) works xD

Answer (score 3):

## 35. [ELF 32-bit LSB executable (Linux)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf), 48 bytes

```
0000000: 7f 45 4c 46 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 43 0d  .ELF..........C.
0000010: 02 00 03 00 19 90 43 0d 19 90 43 0d 04 00 00 00  ......C...C.....
0000020: b9 2e 90 43 0d b2 0d cd 80 cc 20 00 01 00 33 34  ...C...... ...34
```

I've done it! I have conquered the elusive ELF. ELF has been the first language in the list ever since [the first toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbXduM2EH22vkLRycZSYjqm3DfZk957L5bPGgRBEhIIYFEkcVP@Os/OzICUvCkP4NwBMBWDAW0XGqPn94rp2o@fjG8mJ@esyMXkaDL3rFAITtfMAbmEcX0NH5ZZwVwWnMBVxkNkSnUIy9JapLXRxKvaqIurmqDktFvZJvIVIquysmPK1C8wGVfMe8n7SV1rRI53JhLQRpW06L1oC9VlzD/kav7Coma@RT4WwtVSkwcbsr418C2Yb5CgTCFYm4hOJGi5IiT8hm0JVVHXYo@y6ytkFIk7xpsuRbPD88RInVWKrQamMEYNuErJIAzJqghLpjPep6mIBZxCHdE3jsnRNaEUKM9CosyVUjNUywVYxhB4AzoTBV@VTIIN5NKkjY0oSzpZ3kg8Ni61Zq3RWW9tSQnhSnpaVWYZHUbPTVVBUriTNhCrS9mDtdgS2ODX2sFLx7rkkut8SMZ9xk3S5jOwiafBYyFJHGunxJGOh867FFy2JFpCLC0ZLEUwEQMoQStlSyjRCh0IYS5Fy0B/H4FocY10CIeJzPZBiMDwu5a4WkFNG9RbCaeZLg1BrL9KOlFAtRMk55BkvhHDnJcUaY@wACrDyWZlSI9xQfS0yWoiPevg2Ose0FR0UpAbuxRB2XEZyEKtOtuYHQAfUBV4i1M0D@W0i692cCeIylYQNWaNea49@tgwv0ohNKwbktkUvEHZRmyHGy1x6CBcCmmJI4sFLi0ZGVqyNcuMFXpZrv7BXvd8ciorWCHggptSvDg/zIjUVIj2yV4amolKsoGeA1hlK6MZAYNGV0pQ5a9MUAmQtGJF58B7wpKUK7XGGoerKnkyq4waUESVuAx1VxhFN79lTpr@ErYsNJL7hBSRtXCScteyLZQrAqmxbrN5OTAqgdWgBqbwG6ol1rmOLfSqTVoyzEvUb4ql4EGuRbZvAVBVpMrwAGYRNKjHMgdF3ohALRQ4mdVY/JZaDAKo/fOeXiBtaBni76@JpWZgUbc1G@GG4t4zw9W1TqhYJmSwd/sNFoiNztLDYaNvMMu2WxGLjckTcKyVZeahBbVphQ7F0mOU79B8jzLb2W7HngLCiwF9diUCAbq4Di9rmz3srE44UVNXcpiTqKjjIaaKcWJLa7TVlDRljCWSeoCD2OgRSiBDp1wqeRc9GvdwGRhRDAc6t3j@kIOCEHo/UUdJyfGipC/UU/RUjF54g@nxDbP7zkT3midA5@zpwHwTYEPSIVWSg5ezEYTaoiKislalduE1pIjWtNm01GC8aSn7/pmS1JPo4nMW/ICT@sCcI/@CS1@G7d13Le6DbYbIFo8@cEVfum9BtFaxQB6FBv4WWEkoikQCdlQ4h64vPOx7u7Ahurqm7hdcbO1@PrqgyK8IrzcVedQl1LIh7VEr1hZ0jlE7sNj/w6xxpGNaSw8/LBlJZ1qEobeuZfAY5qaRTiUKvltG/y0b6YkYePlTX9p4THEX0fPnEO/tvWwtHNUYemmjZDEaWeODLOGnChL2VGobw3Q2wttbmC3MDjP4JKcZyEOY9tMzkHe6htle33Fbnk@TSlgbgXdKjJXQ017jbPzm@PLx6ECLDc6A4GQyOkjbtAnjYd64HZR63AuD3AGaO462hBOb9jtmML3XR/@IN@BgmNJeeBdKWQvweXaUX8weDc742ex2dNBrPmYWun@51ziCF278FG07/C@Z5vNZ8hrz8C@vp/3CrPebNoHskDS48JSEnsck5POr/wiHlKRwekO8cf8fCyiB3bLa2URn9nbRQA8fBJhswLmB2iGzPXc3mRwvjdRTj@9/ufN3dnd/n88vzs5ORzeH8M9yeDQ@fPBri@yDtpJYKGME@@uCnGjNkt6ww9vR4WJ7cgIjhzGHcQrjDMY5jAsYlzCuFmGhgRYw@MLBV8CoFtscJHOQzEEyB8kcJHOQzEEyB8n8CsY1DAYDpHMOo4QB8nk1fmny8qNXFofT2auvHWXHr5/Mz84vLq@uH7/x5K2333n3vfc/@PCjjz/59LPPv/jyq6@/@fa773/48aeff/n1ZrG4fXrHCl6Kqm7kcqVabZ85H@Jm2z3/7fc//lxsL6vDv7TJOPxbi78B). Now we can move on.

I've never used or even heard of ELF before, so this one was an adventure to figure out. I eventually copied much of Dennis' [32 bit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84154/70606) Hello, World! program ([64 bit version here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84156/70606)). I modified it to print 33 and was able to remove a line of bytes.

Chars used: `\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\r\x19 .34CEFL\x7f\x80\x90\xb2\xb9\xcc\xcd`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc49DsMwCAXgvad4J0DPQH@ctUqmniJOMvX@qxvbaZ2hCBADfGJ9bzmzxYD7Br/CE/wGBpD/MxJu4ALI@JrkF0@5VCjsFLUuW@kh9pPzTO8mvkQrOSjdqTlC1341a@lpwYNICdqE@q0ZzCvVDCmjec4f)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##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@NwpXa6hpi3pr6Q03lSWI9VcrL0uodoLkHBIWWjnOBUWRDggLoLaCbNaW9Fgf5UBb1hAZWA/H3gyAppJXktzYpwjKTqhIFhrdu9buAfiAqsBbnKJ5KKd9fI2HO0FUdZKotRvMcxPQx5aHdQ6h5f2YzLYULcq2cjfeaIXDROlzSCscLJW4tOJkaMU3nFknzapa/4O9GvjsFCt5KeGC20q@Oj/OyNxUiA7JXlmaSVrxkZ4BWLO1NZyARaNrLany1zbqDEha87L34D1hRcq13mCNw1VVIpvVVo8ooUpchrorraab33Gv7HAJOx5bJUJGmshGekW56/gOyhWBMli3bFmNjM5gPaqBKfzGeoV1blIHvWqblywPCvXbciVFVBvJDi0AqopUWRHBLIIW9TjuochbGamFAqdYg8XvqMUggNo/G@g50paWIf7hmjhqBg51O7uVfizuAzNeXeelTlVGFnt32GKBuOQdPRwuhRaz7Po1sdiYAgHPO1WxAC2oyyt0KI4eo2KPlgfEXO/6PfsIEF4M6LNrGQnQxfV4WTt2v7N66WVDXcljTpKmjoeYKsbLHa3RVlvRlLWOSO4BHmKjRygDhk75XPI@BTQe4DJwohgOdG758j4HBSHNYaJJipITZEVfqKcUqBiDDBbTE1ruDp2J7rXIgM450IGFNsKGrEPpLAcvZysJdWVNRLNO53YRDKSI1ozddtRggu0o@@GFVtST6OILHsOIs/rIvSf/os9fju099B3ug22WyA6PPgpNX7pvUXZO80gexRb@FnhFKMlMInZUOId@KDzse/uwIbqmoe4XfercYT75qMmvBK83FXkyFdSyJe3JaN6VdI7JeLA4/MNscORj2qgAPyyMpJmRceytGxUDhrltldeZgu@O03/LVgUiFl7@3Je2AVPcJ/T8JcR7e6c6B0c1hV7aalVOJs6GqCr4qYKEPVPGpThfTPD2lnYHs@MMPsl5BvIQ58P0AuS9aWB20HfSVWfzrBLWJuCdllMtzXzQuJg@nV48mRwZucUZEJzNJkd5m7FxOs5bv4fKTAdhkDtCcyfJVXBi82HHAqYP@ugf8RocjHPaC@9CpRoJPi8eFueLB6MzYbG4nRwNmk@4g@5fHTRO4IWbPkPbHv9L5sVykb3GPPzL6/mwsBj8pk0gOyYNLjwlYeAxCcXy8j/CISU5nMGQaP3/xwJKYLeq9zbRmYNdNDDAewFmG3BuoHbM7MA9n81OVlaZecD3v9r7u3h@d1cszy@XjyfXx@MzdPxwekyXGgE9vQj2bwYy@ReFkLXHt5Pjm93pGYxzGBcwLm/ijQFawhAwJIz6ZlecwihgLGE8gvEYBsgVIFeAXHEJg8MAuQLkigoGyBb1a7PX33jw5s3x4q23H7J3Tovl2fnF5dWTp@@@9/4HH3708Seffvb5F19@9fU33373/Q8//vTzL79e39zc/vbsOYefiNVady982u76l7//8efxX8YyAX/I8m8)

Comment: We have done 35/243 languages! *Only* 85.596707% more languages left!

Answer (score 2):

## 9. [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 14 bytes

```javascript
console.log`8`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nPz3BIuH/fwA)

Miraculously all the characters needed were available.

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbpd9s2DP8c/xWe9zrbb1UWOUvidO3u@76vOGspipJoUyTLw7b63vavZwAo2emODxR@AAkQAEFQtguN0Ys7xXTtx0/GN5OzC1bkYvJwsvCsUAjOt8wBuYJxfQ0fllnBXBacwFnGQ2RKdQjL0lqktdHEq9qoy2VNUHJarWwT@QaRVVnZMWXql5iMK@a95L1Q1xqR452JBLRRJU16L9pCdRnz97mavzSpmW@Rj4VwtdTkwY523xv4Fsw3SFCnEKxNRCcStNwQEn7H9oSqqGtxRNn1EhlF6o7xpkvRHPAiMVJnlWKbgSmMUQOuUjIIQ7IqwpLpjPdpKmIBp1BH9I1jcnRNKAXKs5Aoc6XUDM1yATtjCLwBm4mCr0omxQZyadLCRpQlnSxvJB4bl1qz1uis321NCeFKeppVZh0dRs9NVUFSuJM2EKtL2YOt2BPY4dfawUvHuuSS63xIm/uMm2TNZ7AnngaPhSR1rJ0SRzoeOu9ScNmSagmxtLRhKYKJGEAJVilbQolW6EAIcylaBvb7CESLc2RDtGYtB8pNiY4Ih8nNjoGJwPC7lahRQZ0b3KsSTjNdGoJYk5V0ooAbQJAcRpL5RgwyLyn6HmFRVIaTH5UhO8YF0dMmq4n0rINSqHtAouikIDcOaYNS5DLQDrXqbGMOAHxAU@AtikgOJXaIr3ZwT4jKVhA1Zou5rz362DC/SSE0rBsS3BS8Qd1G7IdbjnmUOgiXQlrjyGKBU2tGG63ZlmXGCr0uN/9gr3s@OZUVrBBw6dOB3JMPEpEaDdE@2WtDkqgkG@gFgE22MZoRMLjpRgm6DRsTVAKkrVjROfCesCTjSm2x7uH6DpWhjBpQRJM4DbVYGEXdoGVOmv5itiw0kvuEFJGtcJJy17I9lDACqbGWs0U5MCqBzWAGRPgN1RprX8cW@tcuTRnmJdo3xVrwILciO7YFqCoyZXiAbRE0aMcyB4XfiEBtFTiZ1XghLLUdBFD7Fz29RNrQNMTfXx1LDcKibWt2wg3FfWSG62ydULFMyGA/9zssEBudpcfERt9glm23IRablSfgWCvLzENbatMMHYqlByo/oMURZbaz3YE9B4QXA3rvRgQCdHEdXtY2u99tnXCipk7lMCdRURdETBXjxJ7maKkpSWSMJZJ6gIPY6GFKIEOnXCp5Fz1u7uEyMKIYDnRz8eI@BwUh9FFQR0nJ8aKkL9RT9FSMXniD6fENs8fORPeaJ0Dn7OnAfBNgQbIhVdKD17QRhNqiIqKyVqV24TWkiOa02bXUYLxpKfv@uZLUk@jicxb8gJP5wJwj/4JLX4Yt33ctroNlhsgejz5wRV@6b0G0VrFAHoUG/iBYSSiKRAJ2VDiHri887HuHsCG6uqbuF1xs7VEeXVDkV4QXnYo86hJq2ZD1qBVrCzrHqB3s2P/XbHGkY9pKDz8xGWlnWoSht25l8BjmrpFOJQq@W0b/MjvpiRj4G0h9aecxxV1Ez19AvLd3srVwVGPopY2SxWhkjQ@yhB8tSNhTqW0Ms/kIb29h9iAdJPhMJwnkIcx68Rz0na5B2ts7bcuLWTIJcyPwTomxEnrWW5yPH4@vHo1OtNihBBQnk9FJWqZNGA9y4w5Q6nGvDHonuN1ptCWc2KxfMQfx0R79N96Ag2FGa@FdKGUtwOf5w/xy/mBwxs/nt6OT3vIps9D9y6PFEbxw46e4t8N/lVm@mCevMQ//8nrWT8x7v2kR6A5JgwtPSej5@fiVJ@N8sfyPeMhKiqffiTfu/4MBI7C6N3sviGQGzgY0h@z13LPJ5HRtpJ55fOPLg0/zZ3d3@eLy/Ho5upnCv8r04Xg6vDiI7/3eInuvjSQWyhZB322nt6Ppan92BiOHsYBxDuNNGBcwLmFcwViuwkoDLWDwlYOvgFGt9jlo5qCZg2YOmjlo5qCZg2YOmvkSxjUMBgO0cw6jhAH6eTV59cFrq@n89eyNs/z84mp5/eitx2@/8@5773/w4Ucff/LpZ59/8eVXX3/z7Xff//DjTz//8utvv9@sVrd/PGVVI9eb1j53Ybvbdy/@/Gu1v6qmfwM) New language: pylons (Should be easy ;).

Comment: I am not sure how to get the link for the next toolbox though.

Comment: To get the next toolbox you can copy the last toolbox from the output section into the input section, and replace the number with your post id. (hit share it should be the number in the url starting with `126`...) I've done it for you here.

Comment: @WheatWizard Cool. I thought so, but in trying to work it out I got interrupted by Real Life and it was easier to flail out a comment and wait for an edit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## 18. C# (.NET Core), 33 bytes

```
()=>System.Console.WriteLine(17);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYwbGaS0GhuCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0MTJKoAEUjT0LS1C64sLknN1XPOzyvOz0nVCy/KLEn1ycxL1TA017QGqwUqAzFquWr//wcA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZcyM1EH6Of4UJLLFhFTLOJptsQXEUN8VZQAFx2NVoNDOyNZJWh@1Zjn/Nc@huzdhZjgdNfy2pT7Va4/rYWrO409w0YfrO9Ob47IKXhTx@eLwIvNQIzjfcA3kM4/oaPpw5yT2LXuIqFzFxrXuEVeUc0sYa4nVj9eVVQ1AJ2q1dm8QakdOs6rm2zUsME5qHoMQwaRqDyIveJgLG6ooWQ5BdqXvGw32uES8tGh465FMpfaMMebAl6zsL35KHFgnKlJJ3mZhMolFrQjJs@Y5QnUwjD4hdXyGjSdxz0fY5mj1eZEYZVmu@HpnSWj3iOieDMCSrJqy4YWJIU5lKOIUmoW8Ck2MaQjlQwWKm3FfKcFQrJFjGEEQLOjMFX7XKgi3k0uaNrawqOlnRKjw2oYzhnTVssLaihAitAq1qu0oeoxe2riEpwisXiTWVGsBG7ghs8evc6KXnfXbJ9yFm44EJm7UFBjbxNEQqFYlj7VQ48vHQeVdSqI5EK4ilI4OVjDZhABVopWxJLTtpIiHMpew46B8ikB2ukQ7pMZHsEISMHL8bhas11LRFvbX0hpvKEsT6q5WXJVQ7QXIOCQutHOeCokgHhAVQW0E2a0t6rI9yoC1riAysh2NvBkBTyStJbuxTBGUnVCQLje5da/cAfEBV4C1O0TyU0z6@xsOdIKo6SdTaDea5Cehjy8M6h9DyfkxmW4oWZVu5G2@0wmGi9DmkFQ6WSlxacTK04hvOrJNmVa3/wV4PfHaKlbyUcMFtJV@eH2dkbipEh2SvLM0krfhILwCs2doaTsCi0bWWVPlrG3UGJK152XvwnrAi5VpvsMbhqiqRzWqrR5RQJS5D3ZVW083vuFd2uIQdj60SISNNZCO9otx1fAflikAZrFu2qEZGZ7Ae1cAUfmO9wjo3qYNetc1LlgeF@m25kiKqjWSHFgBVRaqsiGAWQYt6HPdQ5K2M1EKBU6zB4nfUYhBA7V8M9BJpS8sQ/3BNHDUDh7qd3Uo/FveBGa@u81KnKiOLvTtssUBc8o4eDpdCi1l2/ZpYbEyBgOedqliAFtTlFToUR49RsUeLA2Kud/2ePQeEFwP67FpGAnRxPV7Wjt3vrF562VBX8piTpKnjIaaK8XJHa7TVVjRlrSOSe4CH2OgRyoChUz6XvE8BjQe4DJwohgOdW764z0FBSHOYaJKi5ARZ0RfqKQUqxiCDxfSElrtDZ6J7LTKgcw50YKGNsCHrUDrLwcvZSkJdWRPRrNO5XQQDKaI1Y7cdNZhgO8p@eK4V9SS6@ILHMOKsPnLvyb/o85djew99h/tgmyWyw6OPQtOX7luUndM8kkexhb8FXhFKMpOIHRXOoR8KD/vePmyIrmmo@0WfOneYTz5q8ivB601FnkwFtWxJezKadyWdYzIeLA7/MBsc@Zg2KsAPCyNpZmQce@tGxYBhblvldabgu@P037JVgYiFlz/3pW3AFPcJPX8B8d7eqc7BUU2hl7ZalZOJsyGqCn6qIGFPlXEpzuYTvL2l3cHsOINPcp6BPMTZMD0HeW8amB30nXbVxSyrhLUJeKflVEszGzTOp29PHz@ZHBm5xRkQPD6eHOVtxsbpOG/9HiozHYRB7gjNnSZXwYnNhh1zmD7oo3/EG3AwzmgvvAuVaiT4PH9YXM4fjM6E@fx2cjRoPuUOun910DiBF276FG17/C@ZFYt59hrz8C@vZ8PCfPCbNoHsmDS48JSEgcckFIur/wiHlORwBkOi9f8fCyiB3are20RnDnbRwADvBZhtwLmB2jGzA/fs@Ph0ZZWZBXz/q72/82d3d8Xi8uJsMbk5gX@Wk4fTk3u/tsjeayvIHm4JcuPLhfjw4J/cTk6Wu7MzGAWMBYxzGI9gXMC4hPEYxtUyLg3QEoZYevhKGPVyV4BkAZIFSBYgWYBkAZIFSBYgWVzBuIbBYYB0IWBUMEC@qKevHL/62oPXlydvvPmQvXW2OH90cXl1/eTtd997/4MPP/r4k08/@/yLL7/6@ptvv/v@hx9/@vmXm@Xy9tenz3gpqrppV2v3PG22uxe//f7Hn8vd4/rkL2OZgD9q@Tc)

Answer (score 2):

## 20. [TRANSCRIPT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TRANSCRIPT), 45 bytes

```
You can see a Q here.
>SET Q TO 19
>X Q
>QUIT
```

**Explanation:**

TRANSCRIPT is designed to resemble interactive fiction scripts. So rather than using variables, objects and NPCs are used. Commands and dialog (essentially comments) are mixed together.

```
You can see a Q here.    Creates an object named Q
>SET Q TO 19             Assign Q to 19
>X Q                     Display Q
>QUIT                    End the program
```

Chars used: `.19>EIOQSTUXYZacehnorsu`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KylKzCtOLsosKPn/PzK/VCE5MU@hODVVIVEhUCEjtShVj8su2DUEyAnxVzC05LKLUAjksgsM9Qz5/x8A)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZk@M0EH6e/IowsEwCq2Gc2bmW3eIsoLiK4gGqmAy7sizbSmRJqyOJl@Nf8zx0t@xkluNB7q8l9alWy66PrTWLe81NE6bPp7fHZxe8LOTx4@NF4KVGcL7hHsgVjJsb@HDmJPcseomrXMTEte4RVpVzSBtriNeN1ZfXDUElaLd2bRJrRE6zqufaNm8wTGgeghLDpGkMIi96mwgYqytaDEF2pe4ZDw@5RryxaHjokE@l9I0y5MGWrO8sfEseWiQoU0reZWIyiUatCcmw5TtCdTKNPCB2c42MJnHPRdvnaPZ4kRllWK35emRKa/WI65wMwpCsmrDihokhTWUq4RSahL4JTI5pCOVABYuZcl8pw1GtkGAZQxAt6MwUfNUqC7aQS5s3trKq6GRFq/DYhDKGd9awwdqKEiK0CrSq7Sp5jF7YuoakCK9cJNZUagAbuSOwxa9zo5ee99kl34eYjQcmbNYWGNjE0xCpVCSOtVPhyMdD511JoToSrSCWjgxWMtqEAVSglbIlteykiYQwl7LjoH@IQHa4Rjqkx0SyQxAycvxuFK7WUNMW9dbSG24qSxDrr1ZellDtBMk5JCy0cpwLiiIdEBZAbQXZrC3psT7KgbasITKwHo69GQBNJa8kubFPEZSdUJEsNLp3rd0D8AFVgbc4RfNQTvv4Gg93gqjqJFFrN5jnJqCPLQ/rHELL@zGZbSlalG3lbrzRCoeJ0ueQVjhYKnFpxcnQim84s06aVbX@B3sz8NkpVvJSwgW3lXxzfpyRuakQHZK9sjSTtOIjvQCwZmtrOAGLRtdaUuWvbdQZkLTmZe/Be8KKlGu9wRqHq6pENqutHlFClbgMdVdaTTe/417Z4RJ2PLZKhIw0kY30inLX8R2UKwJlsG7ZohoZncF6VANT@I31CuvcpA561TYvWR4U6rflSoqoNpIdWgBUFamyIoJZBC3qcdxDkbcyUgsFTrEGi99Ri0EAtX8x0EukLS1D/MM1cdQMHOp2div9WNwHZry6zkudqows9u6wxQJxyTt6OFwKLWbZ9WtisTEFAp53qmIBWlCXV@hQHD1GxR4tDoi53vV79hwQXgzos2sZCdDF9XhZO/aws3rpZUNdyWNOkqaOh5gqxssdrdFWW9GUtY5I7gEeYqNHKAOGTvlc8j4FNB7gMnCiGA50bvn6IQcFIc1hokmKkhNkRV@opxSoGIMMFtMTWu4OnYnutciAzjnQgYU2woasQ@ksBy9nKwl1ZU1Es07ndhEMpIjWjN121GCC7Sj74ZVW1JPo4gsew4iz@si9J/@iz1@O7T30He6DbZbIDo8@Ck1fum9Rdk7zSB7FFv4WeEUoyUwidlQ4h34oPOx7@7Ahuqah7hd96txhPvmoya8ErzcVeTIV1LIl7clo3pV0jsl4sDj8w2xw5GPaqAA/LIykmZFx7K0bFQOGuW2V15mC747Tf8tWBSIWXv7cl7YBU9wn9Pw1xHt3rzoHRzWFXtpqVU4mzoaoKvipgoS9UMalOJtP8PaWdgez4ww@yXkG8hBnw/Qc5L1pYHbQd9pVF7OsEtYm4J2WUy3NbNA4nz6bXj2dHBm5xRkQPD6eHOVtxsbpOG/9HiozHYRB7gjNnSZXwYnNhh1zmD7oo3/EW3AwzmgvvAuVaiT4PH9cXM4fjc6E@fxucjRoPuUOun910DiBF276Am17/C@ZFYt59hrz8C@vZ8PCfPCbNoHsmDS48JSEgcckFIvr/wiHlORwBkOi9f8fCyiB3are20RnDnbRwAAfBJhtwLmB2jGzA/fy@Ph0ZZWZBXz/q72/85f398Xi8qJ4Mrk9gX@Wk8fTkwe/tsg@aCvIjm8V4sMTj1z@Czq5m5wsd2dnMAoYCxjnMJ7AuIBxCeMKxvUyLg3QEoZYevhKGPVyV4BkAZIFSBYgWYBkAZIFSBYgWVzDuIHBYYB0IWBUMEC@qKdvHb/9zqN3lyez@XvvP2YfnC3On1xcXl0//fDZ848@/uTTzz7/4suvvv7m2@@@/@HHn37@5Xa5vPv1xcuyqhu1WuvOvYqb7a5//dvvf/y53F3VJ38ZywT8Tcu/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## 29. [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), `TL#`

```
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTL#
```

This pushes `10` to the stack 28 times, then gets the length of the stack and prints it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z8ED/BR/v8fAA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbZdts2EH22vkLVaSqpNd1Qjrc06b73dD9dLTcBQZCEBAIIFklMl7/uszszICWnTR/AuQNgVgwGtF1ojF7cKqZrP348vp7cP2NFLibHk4VnhUJwumEOyAWMqyv4sMwK5rLgBK4yHiJTqkNYltYirY0mXtVGnV/WBCWn3co2ka8RWZWVHVOmfoHJuGLeS95P6lojcrwzkYA2qqRF70VbqC5j/i5X8xcWNfMt8rEQrpaaPNiS9Z2Bb8F8gwRlCsHaRHQiQcs1IeG3bEeoiroWB5RdXSKjSNwx3nQpmj1eJEbqrFJsPTCFMWrAVUoGYUhWRVgynfE@TUUs4BTqiL5xTI6uCaVAeRYSZa6UmqFaLsAyhsAb0Jko@KpkEmwglyZtbERZ0snyRuKxcak1a43OemsrSghX0tOqMqvoMHpuqgqSwp20gVhdyh5sxI7AFr/WDl461iWXXOdDMu4zbpI2n4FNPA0eC0niWDsljnQ8dN6l4LIl0RJiaclgKYKJGEAJWilbQolW6EAIcylaBvr7CESLa6RDOExkdghCBIbfjcTVCmraoN5KOM10aQhi/VXSiQKqnSA5hyTzjRjmvKRIe4QFUBlONitDeowLoqdNVhPpWQfHXveApqKTgtzYpwjKjstAFmrV2cbsAfiAqsBbnKJ5KKd9fLWDO0FUtoKoMRvMc@3Rx4b5dQqhYd2QzKbgDco2YjfcaIlDB@FSSCscWSxwacXI0IptWGas0Kty/S/2queTU1nBCgEX3JTixflhRqSmQrRP9srQTFSSDfQMwDpbG80IGDS6VoIqf22CSoCkFSs6B94TlqRcqQ3WOFxVyZNZZdSAIqrEZai7wii6@S1z0vSXsGWhkdwnpIhshJOUu5btoFwRSI11my3KgVEJrAc1MIXfUK2wznVsoVdt05JhXqJ@U6wED3IjskMLgKoiVYYHMIugQT2WOSjyRgRqocDJrMbit9RiEEDtn/X0HGlDyxB/f00sNQOLuq3ZCjcU94EZrq51QsUyIYO922@xQGx0lh4OG32DWbbdmlhsTJ6AY60sMw8tqE0rdCiWHqN8jxYHlNnOdnv2FBBeDOizaxEI0MV1eFnb7G5ndcKJmrqSw5xERR0PMVWMEztao62mpCljLJHUAxzERo9QAhk65VLJu@jRuIfLwIhiONC5xfO7HBSE0IeJOkpKjhclfaGeoqdi9MIbTI9vmD10JrrXPAE6Z08H5psAG5IOqZIcvJyNINQWFRGVtSq1C68hRbSmzbalBuNNS9n3z5SknkQXn7PgB5zUB@Yc@Rdc@jJs775rcR9sM0R2ePSBK/rSfQuitYoF8ig08LfASkJRJBKwo8I5dH3hYd/bhw3R1TV1v@Biaw/z0QVFfkV4vanIoy6hlg1pj1qxtqBzjNqBxf4fZoMjHdNGevhhyUg60yIMvXUjg8cwt410KlHw3TL6b9lKT8TAy5/60tZjiruInj@HeG9uZWvhqMbQSxsli9HIGh9kCT9VkLAnUtsYZvMR3t7C7GB2mMEnOc1AHsKsn56DvNM1zPb6TtrybJZUwtoIvFNirISe9Rrn40fji4ejIy22OAOCk8noKG3TJoyHeeP2UOpxLwxyR2juJNoSTmzW75jD9EEf/SNeg4NhRnvhXShlLcDn@XF@Pr83OOPn85vRUa/5hFno/uVB4wheuPETtO3wv2SWL@bJa8zDf7ye9Qvz3m/aBLJD0uDCUxJ6HpOQLy5fEg4pSeH0hnjj/j8WUAK7ZbW3ic4c7KKBHt4JMNmAcwO1Q2Z77ulkcrIyUs88vv/l3t/509vbfHF@cXY@up7CP8v0eDwdXiPELy1WXLjbF5GnJoCAnurpzWi63N2/DyOHsYBxCuMBjDMY5zAuYFwuA3wLGHzp4CtgVMtdDnI5yOUgl4NcDnI5yOUgl4NcfgnjCgaDAdI5h1HCAPm8emXy6r3XltPZ/PU3jrOTN/PF6YOz86uHbz16/PY77773/gcffvTxJ59@9vkXX3719Tfffvf9Dz/@9PMvv14vlze/PeVl3cjV2thnLsTNdvf89z/@/Gu5u6imf2uTcfirFv8A)

Comment: Great language name!

Answer (score 2):

## 34. [Java (OpenJDK 9)](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJtvz/PzOvJLUoLTE5VSGxurgksSQzWaEsPzNFITcxM08juKQoMy89OjZRszq4srgkNVcvv7RErwAoWKJhbKxpXVv7/z8A), 63 bytes

```java
interface a{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(33);}}
```

I figured this was getting a bit too easy, with all the characters available and all...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJtvz/PzOvJLUoLTE5VSGxurgksSQzWaEsPzNFITcxM08juKQoMy89OjZRszq4srgkNVcvv7RErwAoWKJhbKxpXVv7/z8A)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZt9smEH6@/hWu2/Ta7SWNfHO3nKT7vrene5wmCCEJGwFhsa2cnv7rPqczg2QnXR7QfAPMyjDI9bG1Zvlcc9OE6YPpw9mdC14WcnY2WwZeagTnW@6BXMG4uYEPZ05yz6KXuMpFTFzrHmFVOYe0sYZ43Vh9ed0QVIJ2a9cmsUHkNKt6rm3zEsOE5iEoMUyaxiDyoreJgLG6osUQZFfqnvHwIteIlxYNDx3yqZS@UYY82JH1vYVvyUOLBGVKybtMTCbRqA0hGXZ8T6hOppFHxG6ukdEk7rlo@xzNAS8zowyrNd@MTGmtHnGdk0EYklUTVtwwMaSpTCWcQpPQN4HJMQ2hHKhgMVPuK2U4qhUSLGMIogWdmYKvWmXBFnJp88ZWVhWdrGgVHptQxvDOGjZYW1NChFaBVrVdJ4/RC1vXkBThlYvEmkoNYCv3BHb4dW700vM@u@T7ELPxwITN2gIDm3gaIpWKxLF2Khz5eOi8KylUR6IVxNKRwUpGmzCACrRStqSWnTSREOZSdhz0DxHIDtdIh/SYSHYMQkaO363C1Rpq2qLeWnrDTWUJYv3VyssSqp0gOYeEhVaOc0FRpAPCAqitIJu1JT3WRznQljVEBtbDsTcDoKnklSQ3DimCshMqkoVG9661BwA@oCrwFqdoHsrpEF/j4U4QVZ0kau0W89wE9LHlYZNDaHk/JrMtRYuyrdyPN1rhMFH6HNIaB0slLq05GVrzLWfWSbOuNv9gbwY@O8VKXkq44LaSL8@PMzI3FaJDsteWZpJWfKQXADZsYw0nYNHoRkuq/I2NOgOS1rzsPXhPWJFyrbdY43BVlchmtdUjSqgSl6HuSqvp5nfcKztcwo7HVomQkSaylV5R7jq@h3JFoAzWLVtWI6Mz2IxqYAq/sV5jnZvUQa/a5SXLg0L9tlxLEdVWsmMLgKoiVVZEMIugRT2OeyjyVkZqocAp1mDxO2oxCKD2LwZ6ibSlZYh/uCaOmoFD3c7upB@L@8iMV9d5qVOVkcXeHXZYIC55Rw@HS6HFLLt@Qyw2pkDA805VLEAL6vIKHYqjx6g4oOURMde7/sCeA8KLAX12IyMBurgeL2vHXuysXnrZUFfymJOkqeMhporxck9rtNVWNGWtI5J7gIfY6BHKgKFTPpe8TwGNB7gMnCiGA51bPnuRg4KQ5jjRJEXJCbKiL9RTClSMQQaL6Qktd8fORPdaZEDnHOjAQhthQ9ahdJaDl7OVhLqyJqJZp3O7CAZSRGvG7jpqMMF2lP3wVCvqSXTxBY9hxFl95N6Tf9HnL8f2HvoO98E2S2SPRx@Fpi/dtyg7p3kkj2ILfwu8IpRkJhE7KpxDPxQe9r1D2BBd01D3iz517jiffNTkV4LXm4o8mQpq2ZL2ZDTvSjrHZDxYHP5htjjyMW1VgB8WRtLMyDj21q2KAcPctcrrTMF3x@m/ZacCEQsvf@5Lu4Ap7hN6/gziffRcdQ6Oagq9tNWqnEycDVFV8FMFCXusjEtxvpjg7S3tHmbHGXyS8wzkIc6H6QXIe9PA7KDvdlddzLNKWJuAd1pOtTTzQeNien96dW9yYuQOZ0BwNpuc5G3Gxuk4b/0BKjMdhEHuBM3dTq6CE5sPOxYwfdRH/4gPwcE4p73wLlSqkeDz4qy4XNwanQmLxaPJyaD5NnfQ/aujxgm8cNPHaNvjf8m8WC6y15iHf3k9HxYWg9@0CWTHpMGFpyQMPCahWF7/RzikJIczGBKt//9YQAnsVvXBJjpztIsGBvhCgNkGnBuoHTM7cE9ms9trq8w84PtfHfxdPHn@vFheXi/PJw9P4Z/l9Gx6Or5GiOluI6AXGMHh6UAm/6mcPpqcrvZ37sAoYCxhnMO4C@MCxiWMKxjXq7gyQEsYYuXhK2HUq30BkgVIFiBZgGQBkgVIFiBZgGRxDeMGBocB0oWAUcEA@aJ@Zfbqa7deX52@8eYZe@tOsbx7cXl1fXPv/oO333n3vfc/@PCjjz/59LPPv/jyq6@/@fa773/48aeff/n1t9Xq98dPyna90U/Tbv/sjz9X@6v69C9jmYB/Z/k3)

Comment: That's handy. I didn't know that when using an interface `main` doesn't need `public` and `print` doesn't need the full path! I was going to do `class S{public static void main(String[]a){java.lang.System.out.print(33);}}`, a whole 13 bytes more. Though if you named the interface `S`, then you would save a char.

Comment: Whoops, a was supposed to be lowercase

Comment: Yeah - I feel like the toolbox generator is adding too many chars each time.

Comment: @WheatWizard would you be able to modify the toolbox script to add back fewer chars? Adding 12 each time seems like too much because in most cases, we use less than 12 chars (except for Java that used 28).

Comment: @andrewarchi I think I will leave the character count on this question, I plan on doing a revamped version of this question with a lower character count and some more features to keep it interesting.

Answer (score 2):

## 45. [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), `Ad<T,>`

```
Add<Add<Add<Add<Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>,Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>>,T>,Add<T,T>>,Add<Add<T,T>,Add<Add<Add<Add<T,T>,Add<Add<Add<Add<Add<Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>,Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>>,T>,Add<T,T>>,Add<Add<T,T>,Add<Add<Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>,Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>>,T>>>,T>>,Add<Add<T,T>,Add<T,T>>>,Add<T,T>>>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nNLchJLEkt/v/fMSXFBhsO0Qmx04ExICxMYTsCirAaSH8bCRkIIXAqQDDt/v8HAA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbXlts2EH22vkJR4qyUGI4pe5sTn@Sk93pSVxsbBEESEgjAKJLolL/OszMzIKV1ygMwF2UqBgO4PrbWLJ9rbpowfTS9mt075WUhZ3dmy8BLjeD@lnsg59AuL6HjzEnuWfQSV7mIiWvdI6wq55A21tBYN1afXTQElaDd2rVJbBA5zaqea9u8MGBC8xCUGCZNYxB50dtEwFhd0WIIsit1z3i4OWrEC4uGhw7HqZS@UYYs2JH2vYW@5KFFgjyl5F0mJpNo1IaQDDu@J1Qn08gjYpcXONDE7rlo@@zNAS/zQBlWa74ZB6W1esR1DgZhCFZNWHHDxBCmMpVwCk1C2wQGxzSEsqOCxUy5r5ThKFZI0IwuiBZkZgq2apUZW4ilzRtbWVV0sqJVeGxCGcM7a9igbU0BEVoFWtV2nTx6L2xdQ1CEVy7S0FRqAFu5J7DD3rnRSs/7bJLvQ8zKAxM2SwsMdOJpiFQqYsfcqbDl46HzrqRQHbFW4EtHCisZbUIHKpBK0ZJadtJEQhhL2XGQP3ggO1wjGdJjINnRCRk59luFqzXktEW5tfSGm8oSxPyrlZclZDtBMg4JC60c54IiTweECVBbQTprS3Ksj3KgLWuIDEMPx94MgKaSV5LMOIQI0k6oSBoa3bvWHgDYgKLAWpyieUing3@NhztBVHWSqLVbjHMT0MaWh012oeX9GMy2FC3ytnI/3miFzUTps0trbCyVuLTmpGjNt5xZJ8262vxjeDmMs1Gs5KWEC24r@eL8OCNzUSE6BHttaSZpxUd6CmDDNtZwAhaVbrSkzN/YqDMgbs3L3oP1hBUJ13qLOQ5XVYmsVls9ooQicRnyrrSabn7HvbLDJex4bJUIGWkiW@kVxa7je0hXBMpg3rJlNQ50BptRDExhH@s15rlJHdSqXV6yPCiUb8u1FFFtJTuWAMgqEmVFBLUIWpTjuIckb2WkEgojxRpMfkclBgHk/ulAz5C2tAz@D9fEUTFwKNvZnfRjch8H49V1XupUZWSxdocdJohL3tHD4VJoMcqu39AQC1Mg4HmnKhagBHV5hQ7F0WNUHNDyiJjrXX8Y3geEFwPq7EZGAnRxPV7Wjt2srF562VBV8hiTpKniIaaM8XJPa7TVVjRlrSOSa4AH3@gRyoChUT6nvE8BlQe4DJwougOVWz67OYKEkOY40SRFwQmyoh7yKQVKxiCDxfCElrtjZaJ7LTKgcw50YKGNsCHLUDrzwcvZSkJdWRPRrNO5XAQDIaI1Y3cdFZhgO4p@eKoV1SS6@ILHMOIsPnLvyb7oc8@xvIe@w32wzRLZ49FHoamn@xZl5zSPZFFs4bfAK0JJZhKxosI59EPiYd07uA3eNQ1Vv@hT547zyUdNdiV4vSnJk6kgly1JT0bzrqRzTMaDxuEPs8WWj2mrAnxYGHEzI@NYW7cqBnRz1yqvMwXbHad/y04FIhZe/lyXdgFD3Ce0/Bn4e/1cdQ6Oagq1tNWqnEycDVFV8KmCgD1WxqU4X0zw9pZ2D7PjDD7JeQbiEOfD9AL4vWlgdpB3t6tO51kkrE3AOi2nWpr5IHExfWt6/nByy8gdzgDjbDa5lbcZG6fjvPUHqMx0YAa@W6jubnIVnNh82LGA6aM8@iNegYFxTnvhXahUI8HmxZ3ibHF7NCYsFteTW4Pku9xB9a@OEifwwk0fo26P/5J5sVxkqzEO/7J6PiwsBrtpE/COQYMLT0EYxhiEYnnxH@6QkOzOoEi0/v99ASGwW9UHnWjMUS8qGOANB7MOODcQO0Z2GD2Zze6urTLzgO9/dbB38eT582J5dlmcTq5O6JU9uTM9yR8QRDnJEeXHDNHhE0lbb/wjTq4nJ6v9vXvQCmhLaPehPYB2Cu0M2jm0i1VcGaAlNLHy0Eto9WpfAGcBnAVwFsBZAGcBnAVwFsBZXEC7hMahAXchoFXQgL@oX5q9/MrtV1cni9deZ2/cK5b3H5yenV9cPnzz0dvvvPve@x98@NHHn3z62edffPnV1998@933P/z408@/XK1W178@fsJLUTfteqO7p2m375/99vsff6725/XJX8YyAZ9p@Tc)

Answer (score 1):

## 4. [Python 1](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/) `print+3`

```python
print+3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/v6AoM69E2/j/fwA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZjxs3DH5e/wrXbbE2kFnsON1db5ugaJGiDy2KPhQ9kA0SjaSZka0rOmxP0P72LUnN2JseDxI/HaRIiqTkh9Q7u37UzHZx/nL@enF9w5paLp4t1pE1GsHzPQtA7qDd30PHKi9ZqFKQuMp4ykzrAaEQ3iPtnKWx7py@3XQEFafd2veZ7xB5XYmBadd9NKi4ZjEqPk7aziIKfHCZgHVa0GKM0jR6qFh8Our4R4uWRYPj3MjQKUsaHOj0o4O@YbFHgjyNZKYQW0iyakdIxgM7Emqz7eQZVfcbHGhiD4z3Q7HmhNdloGzVarabBo1zesJtcQZhcFZLWDFb8dFNTW7gFrqMunF0ju0IFUN5lQplQSjLUCyXcDKawHuQWSjoqlVh7MGXrmzspRB0s7xXeG1cWcuMs9V42pYcwrWKtKrdNge0nru2BafwoHyioRVqBHt5JHDA3vtJy8CGolIYYiqHx4q7Ii1WcCbeBs@NInaMHYGtXA/dt5BcGWIVYIuhA4VMLqMBAqSSt6SWRtpECH0pDQP5owXS4BrJkMZt1US5E6iIDOjc6myYTAz7vUKOFuLc4VmtDJZZ4QhiTLYqyAYygCApjKSKvZzmoiLrR4RB0TpOerSO5LiQ5Ej7qiMyDgOEQjcCmspBSVLj5DYIRa4SndDpwffuBEAHFAXa4hTNQ4id7OsC5AlRZSRR5/bo@y6ijj2Lu2JCz4bJwX3De@Tt5XHKcvSjskmGYtIWW5UbXNoyOmjL9qxyXtqt2P1jeD@Oi1JVwxoJSV8u5Mn8NCNLoSE6OnvraCZrxSZ6A2BX7ZxlBBweutOSsmHnki6AuDVrhgDaE1YkXOs9xj2k7xQZ2ukJZRSJyxCLjdNUDQwLyo2JaVjqFY8FaSJ7GRT5zrAjhDACZTGWq7WYBrqA3SQGprBP7RZj32YD9etQlhyLCuW7Zit5UntZncsCRBWJcjzBsQh6lONZgMDvZaKyCiNVdZgQnsoOAoj9m5HeIu1pGewfU8dTgfAo27uDDFNwnwdTOvsgdRYFOazn8YAB4nPw9Jj4HHv0sh92NMRiFQkEZpSoIpQlU1boUjw9UPUJrc@o8oMfTsPngDAxoPbuZCJAiRswWU31tNoGGWRHlSqgT7KmKoiYIibII63RVidoyjlPpNSAALbRw1RAhUqFEvIhRzw8QjIwomgOVHP54ekIAkLa80SXFTknSkE9xFOOFIxRRofuiT3z58pEec0LoHuOdGGxT7ChyFC68MFr2ktCpmmJ6MroUi6iBRfRmnUHQwUmOkPej@@1oppEic9ZihMu4hMLgfRLofQMS34cDO6DbY7IEa8@cU095VuSxmuWSKPUww@CCUJZFpKwosI9DGPgYd07mQ3WdR1VvxSy8ef5HJImvTK86BTk2QqIZUfSs9XMNHSP2QY4cfzX7LGVa9qrCJ@YirgrK9NUW/cqRTTz0KugCwXdPaO/zEFFIg5@A6UuHSK6eMio@Qew982jMh6uag61tNeqmc28i0kJ@GiBw94q63NarmaYvY07wuw0g890mQE/pOU4vQL@YDuYHeVdGXGzLCJhbQbaaTnX0i5Hiav5i/ndl7MLKw84A4yLxeyibLMuzad5F05Q2fnIDHwXeNxV9gJubDnuWMH0WR79G1@DgmlJe@FdEKqToPPqWX27@nxSJq5Wb2YXo@Qr5qH6i7PEGbxw87d4dsC/yrJer4rW6Id/ab0cF1aj3rQJeCenQcKTE8bxav7Jy3m93vyHPSSl2DOexPvw/8aAENg9in1iRBEDdwOck/fG0bvF4mrrlF1GfOPFSafVu8fHen17valnry/hr3L5bH55Sk0c0J8AwfQOId5i9@Tne/lmdvlwvL6GVkNbQ3sO7QtoN9Buod1B2zwk6Bto/CFAL6G1D8ca@Grgq4GvBr4a@Grgq4GvBr56A@0eGoMG3DWHJqDJ@eLTz66u65vN/Vcvvv7m21ffff/Djz/9/Muvv/3@B5dt12@1eb8/HIcPf/71cLxrL/8G)

Answer (score 1):

## 8. [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 1 byte

```powershell
7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f/f/P9/AA)

I had no idea what powershell is, but it turns out that 7 outputs 7 in TIO.

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbrk@M0DP@8/StKGdh25rxsuuwL7ngPj4GB4f3YHneO4yRuHdvnR9vcDPzriyQn7R4cHxz9ZFuyJEtyXB9ba5b3mpsmTJ9M72bnl7ws5OzRbBl4qRFcbLkHcg3j9hY@nDnJPYte4ioXMXGte4RV5RzSxhridWP11U1DUAnarV2bxAaR06zqubbNKwwTmoegxDBpGoPIi94mAsbqihZDkF2pe8bDQ64RrywaHjrkUyl9owxZsKPT9xa@JQ8tEpQpJe8yMZlEozaEZNjxPaE6mUYeEbu9QUaTuOei7bM3B7zMjDKs1nwzMqW1esR1DgZhCFZNWHHDxBCmMpVwC01C2wQGxzSEsqOCxUy5r5ThqFZIOBldEC3ozBRs1SoLthBLmze2sqroZkWr8NqEMoZ31rDhtDUFRGgVaFXbdfLovbB1DUERXrlIrKnUALZyT2CHX@dGKz3vs0m@DzEfHpiwWVtgcCbehkilInHMnQpHvh6670oK1ZFoBb50dGAlo03oQAVaKVpSy06aSAhjKTsO@gcPZIdrpEN2dq1GKmyFhkiPwWVHx2Tk@N0qlKghzy2eVUtvuKksQczJWnlZQgUQJIORsNDKcS4o8n5AmBS1FWRHbUmP9VEOtGUNkYH1kArNAGgqeSXJjEPYIBWFinRCo3vX2gMAG1AVWItTNA8pdvCv8VAnRFUniVq7xdg3AW1sedhkF1rejwFuS9GibCv3Y5VjHJWJ0meX1jhYKnFpzemgNd9yZp0062rzL/Z24LNRrOSlhKLPF/JgfpyRudEQHYK9tjSTtOIjvQSwYRtrOAGLh260pGrY2KgzIGnNy96D9YQVKdd6i3kP5TtmhrZ6RAlV4jLkYmk1dYOOe2WHwux4bJUIGWkiW@kVxa7je0hhBMpgLrNlNTI6g82oBqbwG@s15r5JHfSvXV6yPCjUb8u1FFFtJTu2BcgqUmVFhGMRtKjHcQ@J38pIbRU4xRosCEdtBwHk/uVAr5C2tAz@D6XjqEE41O3sTvoxuY/MWM7OS52qjCz287DDBHHJO3pMXAotRtn1G2KxWQUCnneqYgHaUpdX6FIcPVDFAS2PiLne9Qf2AhAWBvTejYwEqHA9FmvHHnZbL71sqFN5jEnS1AURU8Z4uac12mormrLWEck9wINv9DBlwNAon1Pep4CHBygGThTdgW4uXz7kICGkOU40SVFwgqzoC/mUAiVjkMFieELL3bEzUV2LDOieA11YaCNsyDqUznLwmraSUFfWRDTrdG4XwUCIaM3YXUcNJtiOoh9eaEU9iQpf8BhGnNVH7j3ZF33@cmz5oe9wH2yzRPZ49VFo@lK9Rdk5zSNZFFv4g@AVoSQzidhR4R76IfGw7x3cBu@ahrpf9Klzx/nkoya7ErzolOTJVJDLlrQno3lX0j0m4@HE4b9miyNf01YF@IlhJM2MjGNv3aoY0M1dq7zOFGx3nP5ldioQsfA3kPvSLmCI@4SWvwR/n96rzsFVTaGXtlqVk4mzIaoKfrQgYM@UcSnOFxOs3tLuYXacwWc6z0Ac4nyYXoC8Nw3MDvrOuupynlXC2gSs03KqpZkPGhfTx9Pr9yYnRu5wBgRns8lJ3mZsnI7z1h@gMtNBGORO8Liz5Cq4sfmwYwHTR33033gHBsY57YV3oVKNBJsXj4qrxVujMWGxeDo5GTSfcQfdvzpqnMALN32GZ3v8V5kXy0W2GuPwH6vnw8JisJs2gewYNCh4CsLAL6ZvPJkWy5vX@ENasj/DSaL1/@8MKIHdg9oHTmQ1cDcgOUZv4J7PZmdrq8w84BtfHWxaPL@/L5ZXF8X55O4U/lVOH01PxxcH8YPfW2QftBFkX/ti5n2Qz6dPJ6er/fk5jALGEsYFjHdhXMK4gnEN42YVVwZoCUOsPHwljHq1L0CyAMkCJAuQLECyAMkCJAuQLG5g3MLgMEC6EDAqGCBf1LM333p7dbpgZ@@cX1ze3L7/@IMPP/r4k08/@/yLL7/6@ptvv/v@hx9/@vmXX3/7/Y@71erPZ8@hluqmVeuN7qx74be7ff/yr79X@@v69B8)

Answer (score 1):

## 10. [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), `3+!`

We finally got an `!`!

```
3333333333333333333++++++++++++++++++!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzSlNSf3/3xgTaGMAxf//AQ)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbZlts2DH0ef4U7PenYPVE6cjJbmnTf930bpwlFUhJtimS42FZO21@fAqBkT7o8ULgACRAAQVCuj601ixvNTBOmj6fXx6dnrCrl8d3jRWCVRnB/wzyQCxhXV/BhhZPMF9FLnGU8JqZ1j1AI55A21hCvG6vPLxuCitNq7drE14icLkTPtG1eYgquWQiKD0LTGESe9zYRMFYLmgxBdpXuCxZucw1/adKw0CGfKukbZciDLe2@s/CtWGiRoE4lWZeJySQatSYkw5btCNXJNPKAiqtLZDSpe8bbPkezx4vMKFPUmq1HprJWj7jOySAMyaoJK2YKPqSpShWcQpPQN47JMQ2hHCgvYqbMC2UYmuUSdsYQeAs2MwVftcqKLeTS5oWtFIJOlrcKj40rY1hnTTHstqKEcK0CzWq7Sh6j57auISncKxeJNUINYCN3BLb4dW700rM@u@T7EPPmoeA2WwsF7ImnwVOlSB1rR@DIx0PnLSRXHakKiKWjDYWMNmEAAqxStqSWnTSREOZSdgzsDxHIDufIhuzsSo2UW4GOSI/JLQ6Bycjwu1GoUUOdW9yrlt4wIyxBrMlaeVnBDSBIDiMpQitHWVAU/YCwKGrLyY/akh3roxxoWzREBtZDKTQDIFHySpIb@7RBKXIVaYdG9661ewA@oCnwFkUkhxLbx9d4uCdEVSeJWrvB3DcBfWxZWOcQWtaPCW4r3qJuK3fjLcc8KhOlzyGtcBSpwqkVo41WbMMK66RZifU/2KuBz04VFaskXPp8ILfko0TmRkN0SPbKkiRpxUZ6BmBdrK1hBCxuutaSbsPaRp0BaWtW9R68J6zIuNYbrHu4vmNlaKtHlNAkTkMtVlZTN@iYV3a4mB2LreIhI01kI72i3HVsByWMQBms5WIhRkZnsB7NgAi/sV5h7ZvUQf/a5inLgkL7tlpJHtVGFoe2AFVFpiyPsC2CFu045qHwWxmprQKnigYvhKO2gwBq/2yg50hbmob4h6vjqEE4tO3sVvqxuA/MeJ2dlzqJjCz287DFAnHJO3pMXAotZtn1a2KxWQUCnnVKFAHaUpdn6FAcPVDlHi0OqHC96/fsfUB4MaD3rmUkQBfX42Xtitvd1ksvG@pUHnOSNHVBxFQxXu5ojpZaQSJrHZHcAzzERg9TBgU65XPJ@xRw8wCXgRHFcKCbyxe3OSgIaQ6CJilKTpCCvlBPKVAxBhkspie0zB06E91rngGdc6ADC22EBdmG0lkPXtNWEuqqmoguOp3bRTCQIpozdttRgwm2o@yH51pRT6KLz1kMI87mI/Oe/Is@fxm2/NB3uA6WWSI7PPrINX3pvkXZOc0ieRRb@INgglCSmUTsqHAO/VB42Pf2YUN0TUPdL/rUuYM8@ajJrwQvOhV5MgJq2ZL1ZDTrKjrHZDzsOPzXbHDkY9qoAD8xBWkXRsaxt25UDBjmtlVeZwq@O0b/MlsViFj4G8h9aRswxX1Cz19AvE9uVOfgqKbQS1utqsnE2RCVgB8tSNhTZVyKs/kEb29ldyAdJfhMZwnkIc4G8Rz0vWlAOti714mzWTYJcxPwTsuplmY2WJxPH00vHk6OjNyiBBSPjydHeZmxcTrKrd9DZaaDMugd4Xb3khNwYrNhxRzEB3v033gNDsYZrYV3QahGgs/zu@X5/M7oTJjPn0yOBsv3mIPuLw4WJ/DCTZ/i3h7/VWblYp69xjz8y@vZMDEf/KZFoDsmDS48JWHg59NXHk/LxeV/xENWcjzDTrz1/x8MGIHVg9lbQWQzcDagOWZv4J4dH99bWWVmAd94sfdp/uzmplycPzgtJ9cn8K9ycnd6Mr44iG/93iJ7q41kFsoWQW6fJ08mJ8vd6SmMEsYCxn0YD2CcwTiHcQHjchmXBmgFgy89fCWMerkrQbMEzRI0S9AsQbMEzRI0S9AsL2FcwWAwQLvkMAQM0C/r6fGrd15bnsxfL944LRdnF5dXD9989Nbb77z73vsffPjRx598@tnnX3z51dfffPvd9z/8@NPPv/z62/Vy@eT3p89YJepWrdadse65DzFttrv@xR9//rXcXdQnfwM)

### Explanation

`9` is 57 in ASCII, which is 3 times 19.  So in order to get `9` we add 19 3s and use `!` to output.

Comment: Two number 9s??

Comment: @OrphanBot Sorry this is number 10, still works though :)

Answer (score 1):

## 11. [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 1 byte

```
A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P/f8f9/AA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbZlts2DH0ef4U7PenYPVE68mS2NOm@7/sWpwlFUhJtimS42FZO21@fAqBkT7o8ULgACRAAQVCuj601ixvNTBOmj6aPj0/PWVXK47vHi8AqjeBswzyQSxjX1/BhhZPMF9FLnGU8JqZ1j1AI55A21hCvG6svrhqCitNq7drE14icLkTPtG1eYgquWQiKD0LTGESe9zYRMFYLmgxBdpXuCxZucw1/adKw0CGfKukbZciDLe2@s/CtWGiRoE4lWZeJySQatSYkw5btCNXJNPKAiusrZDSpe8bbPkezx4vMKFPUmq1HprJWj7jOySAMyaoJK2YKPqSpShWcQpPQN47JMQ2hHCgvYqbMC2UYmuUSdsYQeAs2MwVftcqKLeTS5oWtFIJOlrcKj40rY1hnTTHstqKEcK0CzWq7Sh6j57auISncKxeJNUINYCN3BLb4dW700rM@u@T7EPPmoeA2WwsF7ImnwVOlSB1rR@DIx0PnLSRXHakKiKWjDYWMNmEAAqxStqSWnTSREOZSdgzsDxHIDufIhuzsSo2UW4GOSI/JLQ6Bycjwu1GoUUOdW9yrlt4wIyxBrMlaeVnBDSBIDiMpQitHWVAU/YCwKGrLyY/akh3roxxoWzREBtZDKTQDIFHySpIb@7RBKXIVaYdG9661ewA@oCnwFkUkhxLbx9d4uCdEVSeJWrvB3DcBfWxZWOcQWtaPCW4r3qJuK3fjLcc8KhOlzyGtcBSpwqkVo41WbMMK66RZifU/2OuBz04VFaskXPp8ILfko0TmRkN0SPbKkiRpxUZ6DmBdrK1hBCxuutaSbsPaRp0BaWtW9R68J6zIuNYbrHu4vmNlaKtHlNAkTkMtVlZTN@iYV3a4mB2LreIhI01kI72i3HVsByWMQBms5WIhRkZnsB7NgAi/sV5h7ZvUQf/a5inLgkL7tlpJHtVGFoe2AFVFpiyPsC2CFu045qHwWxmprQKnigYvhKO2gwBq/3ygF0hbmob4h6vjqEE4tO3sVvqxuA/MeJ2dlzqJjCz287DFAnHJO3pMXAotZtn1a2KxWQUCnnVKFAHaUpdn6FAcPVDlHi0OqHC96/fsGSC8GNB71zISoIvr8bJ2xe1u66WXDXUqjzlJmrogYqoYL3c0R0utIJG1jkjuAR5io4cpgwKd8rnkfQq4eYDLwIhiONDN5YvbHBSENAdBkxQlJ0hBX6inFKgYgwwW0xNa5g6die41z4DOOdCBhTbCgmxD6awHr2krCXVVTUQXnc7tIhhIEc0Zu@2owQTbUfbDc62oJ9HF5yyGEWfzkXlP/kWfvwxbfug7XAfLLJEdHn3kmr5036LsnGaRPIot/EEwQSjJTCJ2VDiHfig87Hv7sCG6pqHuF33q3EGefNTkV4IXnYo8GQG1bMl6Mpp1FZ1jMh52HP5rNjjyMW1UgJ@YgrQLI@PYWzcqBgxz2yqvMwXfHaN/ma0KRCz8DeS@tA2Y4j6h5y8g3ic3qnNwVFPopa1W1WTibIhKwI8WJOypMi7F2XyCt7eyO5COEnymswTyEGeDeA763jQgHezd68T5LJuEuQl4p@VUSzMbLM6nD6eXDyZHRm5RAorHx5OjvMzYOB3l1u@hMtNBGfSOcLt7yQk4sdmwYg7igz36b3wMDsYZrYV3QahGgs/zu@XF/M7oTJjPn0yOBsv3mIPuLw4WJ/DCTZ/i3h7/VWblYp69xjz8y@vZMDEf/KZFoDsmDS48JWHg59NXHk3LxdV/xENWcjzDTrz1/x8MGIHVg9lbQWQzcDagOWZv4J4dH99bWWVmAd94sfdp/uzmplxc3D89mzw@gX@Vk7vTk/HFQXzr9xbZW20ks1C2CHL7PHkyOVnuTk9hlDAWMM5g3IdxDuMCxiWMq2VcGqAVDL708JUw6uWuBM0SNEvQLEGzBM0SNEvQLEGzvIJxDYPBAO2SwxAwQL@sp8ev3nlteTJ/vXjjtFycX15dP3jz4Vtvv/Pue@9/8OFHH3/y6Weff/HlV19/8@133//w408///Lrb4@Xyye/P33GKlG3arXujHXPfYhps931L/7486/l7rI@@Rs)

Answer (score 1):

## 12. [Logicode](https://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode), 6 bytes

```
out 11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8lPz0zOT0n9/z@/tETB0PD/fwA)

trivial, right language for 11

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbZlts2DH0ef4XrntR2TzQdOZktTbrv@76NpwlFURJtimS42FZO21@fAqBkO10eKFyABAiAIETbhcboxZ1iuvbjJ@Obydk5K3IxuT9ZeFYoBA82zAG5hHF9DR@WWcFcFpzAWcZDZEp1CMvSWqS10cSr2qiLq5qg5LRa2SbyNSKrsrJjytQvMRlXzHvJe6GuNSLHOxMJaKNKmvRetIXqMuaPuZq/NKmZb5GPhXC11OTBlnbfGfgWzDdIUKcQrE1EJxK0XBMSfst2hKqoa3FA2fUVMorUHeNNl6LZ40VipM4qxdYDUxijBlylZBCGZFWEJdMZ79NUxAJOoY7oG8fk6JpQCpRnIVHmSqkZmuUCdsYQeAM2EwVflUyKDeTSpIWNKEs6Wd5IPDYutWat0Vm/24oSwpX0NKvMKjqMnpuqgqRwJ20gVpeyBxuxI7DFr7WDl451ySXX@ZA29xk3yZrPYE88DR4LSepYOyWOdDx03qXgsiXVEmJpacNSBBMxgBKsUraEEq3QgRDmUrQM7PcRiBbnyIZozUoOlJsSHREOk5sdAhOB4XcjUaOCOje4VyWcZro0BLEmK@lEATeAIDmMJPONGGReUvQ9wqKoDCc/KkN2jAuip01WE@lZB6VQ94BE0UlBbuzTBqXIZaAdatXZxuwB@ICmwFsUkRxKbB9f7eCeEJWtIGrMBnNfe/SxYX6dQmhYNyS4KXiDuo3YDbcc8yh1EC6FtMKRxQKnVow2WrENy4wVelWu/8Fe93xyKitYIeDSpwM5kg8SkRoN0T7ZK0OSqCQb6DmAdbY2mhEwuOlaCboNaxNUAqStWNE58J6wJONKbbDu4foOlaGMGlBEkzgNtVgYRd2gZU6a/mK2LDSS@4QUkY1wknLXsh2UMAKpsZazRTkwKoH1YAZE@A3VCmtfxxb61zZNGeYl2jfFSvAgNyI7tAWoKjJleIBtETRoxzIHhd@IQG0VOJnVeCEstR0EUPvnPb1A2tA0xN9fHUsNwqJta7bCDcV9YIbrbJ1QsUzIYD/3WywQG52ln4mNvsEs225NLDYrT8CxVpaZh7bUphk6FEs/qHyPFgeU2c52e/YBILwY0HvXIhCgi@vwsrbZcbd1womaOpXDnERFXRAxVYwTO5qjpaYkkTGWSOoBDmKjH1MCGTrlUsm76HFzD5eBEcVwoJuLF8ccFITQB0EdJSXHi5K@UE/RUzF64Q2mxzfMHjoT3WueAJ2zpwPzTYAFyYZUSQ/@po0g1BYVEZW1KrULryFFNKfNtqUG401L2ffPlaSeRBefs@AHnMwH5hz5F1z6Mmz5vmtxHSwzRHZ49IEr@tJ9C6K1igXyKDTwgmAloSgSCdhR4Ry6vvCw7@3DhujqmrpfcLG1B3l0QZFfEf7oVORRl1DLhqxHrVhb0DlG7WDH/l2zwZGOaSM9PGIy0s60CENv3cjgMcxtI51KFHy3jN4yW@mJGHgNpL609ZjiLqLnLyDe2zvZWjiqMfTSRsliNLLGB1nCQwsS9lRqG8NsPsLbW5gdSAcJ/qaTBPIQZr14DvpO1yDt7Z225fksmYS5EXinxFgJPestzsePx5ePRidabFECipPJ6CQt0yaMB7lxeyj1uFcGvRPc7jTaEk5s1q@Yg/hgj96NN@BgmNFa@C@Ushbg8/x@fjG/Nzjj5/Pb0Ulv@ZRZ6P7lweII/nDjp7i3w7fKLF/Mk9eYh395Pesn5r3ftAh0h6TBhack9Px8/MqTcb64@o94yEqKp9@JN@7/gwEjsLo3exREMgNnA5pD9nru2WRyujJSzzz@48u9T/Nnd3f54uLh2eXoZgpvlen98Xh69KYFfnrUOxILtYog9czp7Wi63J2dwchhLGA8gPEQxjmMCxiXMK6WYamBFjD40sFXwKiWuxw0c9DMQTMHzRw0c9DMQTMHzfwKxjUMBgO0cw6jhAH6eTWevHrvteV0/nr2xtni/PLq@tGbj996@51333v/gw8/@viTTz/7/Isvv/r6m2@/@/6HH3/6@Zdff7tZLm9/f/qMFWXVyNW61fa585vtrnvxx59/LXeX1fRv)

Comment: Was fiddling with this to see if I could get it to print `11` as ascii characters rather than binary-11, couldn't get it to do them on the same line.

Comment: I am not sure your toolbox is correct. It is taking a post number of `26407` and your answer is actually `126407`

Comment: does it looks correct now?

Comment: Yep. I hadn't noticed the discrepancy until after I did #13 and was getting its toolbox and I was like "hold on a moment..." And it totally invalidated the entry.

Answer (score 1):

## 16. Scala, 13 bytes

```
()=>print(15)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8/z8/KSs1uUTBsZpLQSElNU0hNzEzTyPRyrGoKLEyOrikKDMvPVYTJKmgUJZYpJCmYAtmKyhoaNraFQClSzQMTTXBYmkaILqWq/b/fwA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXf9s2EH@2PoWqNrXUmq4pxytNf91772G5DgiCJCQQQDAkMR3fus/u3YGUnI4H8P4H4CYOB9ouNEbP7xTTtR@/Mb6enJyxIheTo8ncs0IhOF0zB@QCxtUVfFhmBXNZcAJXGQ@RKdUhLEtrkdZGE69qo84va4KS025lm8hXiKzKyo4pUz/HZFwx7yXvJ3WtETnemUhAG1XSoveiLVSXMX@fq/lzi5r5FvlYCFdLTR5syPrWwLdgvkGCMoVgbSI6kaDlipDwG7YlVEVdiz3Kri6RUSTuGG@6FM0OzxMjdVYpthqYwhg14ColgzAkqyIsmc54n6YiFnAKdUTfOCZH14RSoDwLiTJXSs1QLRdgGUPgDehMFHxVMgk2kEuTNjaiLOlkeSPx2LjUmrVGZ721JSWEK@lpVZlldBg9N1UFSeFO2kCsLmUP1mJLYINfawcvHeuSS67zIRn3GTdJm8/AJp4Gj4UkcaydEkc6HjrvUnDZkmgJsbRksBTBRAygBK2ULaFEK3QghLkULQP9fQSixTXSIRwmMtsHIQLD71riagU1bVBvJZxmujQEsf4q6UQB1U6QnEOS@UYMc15SpD3CAqgMJ5uVIT3GBdHTJquJ9KyDY697QFPRSUFu7FIEZcdlIAu16mxjdgB8QFXgLU7RPJTTLr7awZ0gKltB1Jg15rn26GPD/CqF0LBuSGZT8AZlG7EdbrTEoYNwKaQljiwWuLRkZGjJ1iwzVuhlufoHe9XzyamsYIWAC25K8fz8MCNSUyHaJ3tpaCYqyQZ6BmCVrYxmBAwaXSlBlb8yQSVA0ooVnQPvCUtSrtQaaxyuquTJrDJqQBFV4jLUXWEU3fyWOWn6S9iy0EjuE1JE1sJJyl3LtlCuCKTGus3m5cCoBFaDGpjCb6iWWOc6ttCrNmnJMC9RvymWgge5Ftm@BUBVkSrDA5hF0KAeyxwUeSMCtVDgZFZj8VtqMQig9s96eo60oWWIv78mlpqBRd3WbIQbinvPDFfXOqFimZDB3u03WCA2OksPh42@wSzbbkUsNiZPwLFWlpmHFtSmFToUS49RvkPzPcpsZ7sdewoILwb02ZUIBOjiOrysbXa/szrhRE1dyWFOoqKOh5gqxoktrdFWU9KUMZZI6gEOYqNHKIEMnXKp5F30aNzDZWBEMRzo3OLZfQ4KQuj9RB0lJceLkr5QT9FTMXrhDabHN8zuOxPda54AnbOnA/NNgA1Jh1RJDl7ORhBqi4qIylqV2oXXkCJa02bTUoPxpqXs@6dKUk@ii89Z8ANO6gNzjvwLLn0ZtnfftbgPthkiWzz6wBV96b4F0VrFAnkUGvhbYCWhKBIJ2FHhHLq@8LDv7cKG6Oqaul9wsbX7@eiCIr8ivN5U5FGXUMuGtEetWFvQOUbtwGL/D7PGkY5pLT38sGQknWkRht66lsFjmJtGOpUo@G4Z/bdspCdi4OVPfWnjMcVdRM@fQbw3d7K1cFRj6KWNksVoZI0PsoSfKkjYrdQ2hulshLe3MFuYHWbwSU4zkIcw7adnIO90DbO9vuO2PJsmlbA2Au@UGCuhp73G2fjx@OLR6ECLDc6A4GQyOkjbtAnjYd64HZR63AuD3AGaO462hBOb9jtmML3XR/@I1@BgmNJeeBdKWQvweXaUn88eDM742exmdNBrPmYWun@51ziCF258i7Yd/pdM8/kseY15@JfX035h1vtNm0B2SBpceEpCz2MS8vnlf4RDSlI4vSHeuP@PBZTAblntbKIze7tooIf3Akw24NxA7ZDZnnsymRwvjdRTj@9/ufN39uTuLp@fP7w6H10fwj/L4dH48N6vLbL32gqy@1uCXP8fhXB4xA5vRoeL7ckJjBzGHMYpjIcwzmCcw7iAcbkICw20gMEXDr4CRrXY5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5pcwrmAwGCCdcxglDJDPq/ELkxdfevDy4vCVV4@y49dO5qcPzy8urx69/vjNt95@59333v/gw48@/uTTzz7/4suvvv7m2@@@/@HHn37@5XqxuPn19gkreCmqulmuVGue@rjebLtnv/3@x5@L7UV1@Jc2GYc/a/E3)

Answer (score 1):

## 17. [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable) (Prints 16)

```
4n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fJO//fwA)

```
4  # Push 4
 n # Square it
```

[Next Toolbox, new language: golfscript](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4pxytNuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5HQ/gfQfgJg4H2i40Rs9vFdO1Hz8aX09OzliRi8nRZO5ZoRCcrpkDcgHj6go@LLOCuSw4gauMh8iU6hCWpbVIa6OJV7VR55c1Qclpt7JN5CtEVmVlx5Spn2Myrpj3kveTutaIHO9MJKCNKmnRe9EWqsuYv8vV/LlFzXyLfCyEq6UmDzZkfWvgWzDfIEGZQrA2EZ1I0HJFSPgN2xKqoq7FHmVXl8goEneMN12KZofniZE6qxRbDUxhjBpwlZJBGJJVEZZMZ7xPUxELOIU6om8ck6NrQilQnoVEmSulZqiWC7CMIfAGdCYKviqZBBvIpUkbG1GWdLK8kXhsXGrNWqOz3tqSEsKV9LSqzDI6jJ6bqoKkcCdtIFaXsgdrsSWwwa@1g5eOdckl1/mQjPuMm6TNZ2ATT4PHQpI41k6JIx0PnXcpuGxJtIRYWjJYimAiBlCCVsqWUKIVOhDCXIqWgf4@AtHiGukQDhOZ7YMQgeF3LXG1gpo2qLcSTjNdGoJYf5V0ooBqJ0jOIcl8I4Y5LynSHmEBVIaTzcqQHuOC6GmT1UR61sGx1z2gqeikIDd2KYKy4zKQhVp1tjE7AD6gKvAWp2geymkXX@3gThCVrSBqzBrzXHv0sWF@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@MbZvedie41T4DO2dOB@SbAhqRDqiQHL2cjCLVFRURlrUrtwmtIEa1ps2mpwXjTUvb9UyWpJ9HF5yz4ASf1gTlH/gWXvgzbu@9a3AfbDJEtHn3gir5034JorWKBPAoN/C2wklAUiQTsqHAOXV942Pd2YUN0dU3dL7jY2v18dEGRXxFebyryqEuoZUPao1asLegco3Zgsf@HWeNIx7SWHn5YMpLOtAhDb13L4DHMTSOdShR8t4z@WzbSEzHw8qe@tPGY4i6i588g3ptb2Vo4qjH00kbJYjSyxgdZwk8VJOyx1DaG6WyEt7cwW5gdZvBJTjOQhzDtp2cg73QNs72@47Y8myaVsDYC75QYK6GnvcbZ@OH44sHoQIsNzoDgZDI6SNu0CeNh3rgdlHrcC4PcAZo7jraEE5v2O2YwvddH/4jX4GCY0l54F0pZC/B5dpSfz@4NzvjZ7GZ00Gs@Zha6f7nXOIIXbvwYbTv8L5nm81nyGvPwL6@n/cKs95s2geyQNLjwlISexyTk88v/CIeUpHB6Q7xx/x8LKIHdstrZRGf2dtFAD@8EmGzAuYHaIbM992QyOV4aqace3/9y5@/sye1tPj@/f3Uxuj6Ef5bDo/HhnV9bZO@0FWT3twS5/j8K4fCIHd6MDhfbkxMYOYw5jFMY92GcwTiHcQHjchEWGmgBgy8cfAWMarHNQTIHyRwkc5DMQTIHyRwkc5DML2FcwWAwQDrnMEoYIJ9X4xcmL7507@XF4XT2yqtH2fFrJ/n89P7Z@cXl1YPXHz5648233n7n3ffe/@DDjz7@5NPPPv/iy6@@/ubb777/4ceffv7lerG4@fXxE1bwUlR1I5cr1Wpjnzof4nqz7Z799vsffy62F9XhX9pkHH6yxd8)

Answer (score 1):

## 19. [pbrain](http://www.parkscomputing.com/applications/pbrain/), 58 bytes

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++.
```

Prints ASCII values 49 and 56 (`18`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gqSszM@/9fm1SgB6P//wcA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZt9s0EH5ufkUIlJtwqlLn9m49ZT3sOxzgADeXVpZlW4ksqVqSuCz/mucyM7KTW5YHeb6RNKtGI7s@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@tjxscggt78dktqVoUbaV@/FGKxwmSp9DWuNgqcSlNSdDa77lzDpp1tXmH@zVwGenWMlLCRfcVvLl@XFG5qZCdEj22tJM0oqP9AzAhm2s4QQsGt1oSZW/sVFnQNKal70H7wkrUq71FmscrqoS2ay2ekQJVeIy1F1pNd38jntlh0vY8dgqETLSRLbSK8pdx/dQrgiUwbply2pkdAabUQ1M4TfWa6xzkzroVbu8ZHlQqN@Waymi2kp2bAFQVaTKighmEbSox3EPRd7KSC0UOMUaLH5HLQYB1P7ZQM@RtrQM8Q/XxFEzcKjb2Z30Y3EfmfHqOi91qjKy2LvDDgvEJe/o4XAptJhl12@IxcYUCHjeqYoFaEFdXqFDcfQYFQe0PCLmetcf2FNAeDGgz25kJEAX1@Nl7djtzuqllw11JY85SZo6HmKqGC/3tEZbbUVT1joiuQd4iI0eoQwYOuVzyfsU0HiAy8CJYjjQueXz2xwUhDTHiSYpSk6QFX2hnlKgYgwyWExPaLk7dia61yIDOudABxbaCBuyDqWzHLycrSTUlTURzTqd20UwkCJaM3bXUYMJtqPsh2daUU@iiy94DCPO6iP3nvyLPn85tvfQd7gPtlkiezz6KDR96b5F2TnNI3kUW/hb4BWhJDOJ2FHhHPqh8LDvHcKG6JqGul/0qXPH@eSjJr8SvN5U5MlUUMuWtCejeVfSOSbjweLwD7PFkY9pqwL8sDCSZkbGsbduVQwY5q5VXmcKvjtO/y07FYhYePlzX9oFTHGf0PPnEO/NC9U5OKop9NJWq3IycTZEVcFPFSTsiTIuxfligre3tHuYHWfwSc4zkIc4H6YXIO9NA7ODvvtddTbPKmFtAt5pOdXSzAeNi@nj6cWjyR0jdzgDgrPZ5E7eZmycjvPWH6Ay00EY5O6gufvJVXBi82HHAqaP@ugf8RocjHPaC@9CpRoJPi/uFeeLu6MzYbG4mdwZNN/nDrp/ddQ4gRdu@gRte/wvmRfLRfYa8/Avr@fDwmLwmzaB7Jg0uPCUhIHHJBTLy/8Ih5TkcAZDovX/Hwsogd2qPthEZ4520cAAbwWYbcC5gdoxswP3dDa7v7bKzAO@/9XB38XTFy@K5flZcTq5PoF/lpN705Nbv7bI3moryB5vCXLjy4X4@OCf3ExOVvsHD2AUMJYwTmE8hHEG4xzGBYzLVVwZoCUMsfLwlTDq1b4AyQIkC5AsQLIAyQIkC5AsQLK4hHEFg8MA6ULAqGCAfFFPX5m9@trd11cnizfusTcfFMvTh2fnF5dXjx6//c67773/wYcfffzJp599/sWXX339zbffff/Djz/9/Mv1anXz65OnvBRV3bRqvdHGumc@pO1u//y33//4c7W/qE/@MpYJ@LeWfwM)

Answer (score 1):

## 22. [MarioLANG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 44 bytes

```
+++++++++++++++++++++:
=====================
```

Boring but shortest.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fGxuw4rLFBv7//5qXr5ucmJyRCgA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZf9s2DH@OP4XnrYu9X5RVTuMkW3ff933GaUtRlESbIlkettUd33rPGQBKdrrjgcQfJAECIAjSdqExen6rmK79@I3x9eT@OStyMTmZzD0rFIKzDXNALqBdXUHHMiuYy4ITOMt4iEypDmFZWou0Npp4VRu1uKwJSk6rlW0iXyOyKis7pkz9HJNxxbyXvB/UtUbkeGciAW1USZPei7ZQXcb8Xa7mz01q5lvkYyFcLTVZsKXddwb6gvkGCcoUgrWJ6ESClmtCwm/ZjlAVdS0OKLu6REaRuGO86ZI3ezxPjNRZpdh6YApj1ICrFAzCEKyKsGQ6432YiljAKdQRbeMYHF0TSo7yLCTKXCk1Q7VcwM7oAm9AZ6Jgq5JJsIFYmrSwEWVJJ8sbicfGpdasNTrrd1tRQLiSnmaVWUWH3nNTVRAU7qQNxOpS9mAjdgS22Fs7WOlYl0xynQ9pc59xk7T5DPbE0@CxkCSOuVNiS8dD510KLlsSLcGXljYsRTARHShBK0VLKNEKHQhhLEXLQH/vgWhxjnQIh4HMDk6IwLDfSJytIKcN6q2E00yXhiDmXyWdKCDbCZJxSDLfiGHMS/K0R5gAleG0Z2VIj3FB9LTJaiI96@DY6x7QUHRSkBn7EEHacRloh1p1tjF7ADagKrAWh2gc0mnvX@3gThCVrSBqzAbjXHu0sWF@nVxoWDcEsyl4g7KN2A03WmLTQbjk0gpbFgucWjHaaMU2LDNW6FW5/gd71fPJqKxghYALbkrx/PgwIlJRIdoHe2VoJCrJBnoOYJ2tjWYEDG66VoIyf22CSoCkFSs6B9YTlqRcqQ3mOFxVydO2yqgBRVSJ05B3hVF081vmpOkvYctCI7lPSBHZCCcpdi3bQboikBrzNpuXA6MSWA9qYAj7UK0wz3VsoVZt05RhXqJ@U6wED3IjskMJgKwiVYYH2BZBg3osc5DkjQhUQoGTWY3Jb6nEIIDcP@/pAmlD0@B/f00sFQOLuq3ZCjck94EZrq51QsUyIYO1228xQWx0lh4OG32DUbbdmlgsTJ6AY60sMw8lqE0zdCiWHqN8j@YHlNnOdnv2DBBeDKizaxEI0MV1eFnb7G5ldcKJmqqSw5hERRUPMWWMEzuao6WmpCFjLJFUAxz4Ro9QAhka5VLKu@hxcw@XgRFFd6Byi2d3OUgIoQ8DdZQUHC9K6iGfoqdk9MIbDI9vmD1UJrrXPAE6Z08H5psAC5IOqZIcvJyNINQWFRGVtSqVC68hRDSnzbalAuNNS9H3T5WkmkQXn7PgB5zUB@Yc2Rdc6hmWd9@1uA6WGSI7PPrAFfV034JorWKBLAoN/BZYSSiKRAJWVDiHrk88rHt7t8G7uqbqF1xs7WE8uqDIrgivNyV51CXksiHtUSvWFnSOUTvYsf/DbLClY9pIDx@WjKQzLcJQWzcyeHRz20inEgXbLaN/y1Z6IgZe/lSXth5D3EW0/Bn4e3MrWwtHNYZa2ihZjEbW@CBL@FRBwB5LbWOYzkZ4ewuzg9FhBJ/kNAJxCNN@eAbyTtcw2us7bcvzaVIJcyOwTomxEnraa5yNH44vXhsdabHFERCcTEZHaZk2YTyMG7eHUo97YZA7wu1Ooy3hxKb9ihkMH/TRH/EaDAxTWgvvQilrATbPTvLF7N5gjJ/NbkZHveZTZqH6lweNI3jhxo9xb4f/kmk@nyWrMQ7/snraT8x6u2kRyA5BgwtPQeh5DEI@v/wPd0hJcqffiDfu/30BJbBaVvs90ZjDvrhBD@84mPaAcwO1Q2R77slkcroyUk89vv/l3t7Zk9vbfL5YLM5G18fwZzk@GR/f@doie6esIDu8VYgPTzxy6Rd0fDM6Xu7u34eWQ5tDO4P2ANo5tAW0C2iXywB9AY0vHfQCWrXc5SCXg1wOcjnI5SCXg1wOcjnI5ZfQrqAxaCCdc2glNJDPq/ELkxdfuvfy8ng6e@UkO301n589OF9cXF69/vDNt95@59333v/gw48@/uTTzz7/4suvvv7m2@@@/@HHn37@5dfr5fLm0eMnrOClqOpGrtaq1cY@dT7EzXbXPfvt9z/@XO4uquO/tMk4/K7F3w)

Comment: Hah! You beat me by 13 seconds. I'll change mine to 23

Answer (score 1):

## 24. [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), 12 bytes

```scm
(display 23)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K07OSM1N1QWSVf//a6RkFhfkJFYqGBlr/v8PAA)
[Next toolbox.](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4pxyttuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5bfoA3ncAbuJwoO1CY/T8VjFd@/HD8fXk5IwVuZgcTeaeFQrB6Zo5IBcwrq7gwzIrmMuCE7jKeIhMqQ5hWVqLtDaaeFUbdX5ZE5ScdivbRL5CZFVWdkyZ@hkm44p5L3k/qWuNyPHORALaqJIWvRdtobqM@btczZ9Z1My3yMdCuFpq8mBD1rcGvgXzDRKUKQRrE9GJBC1XhITfsC2hKupa7FF2dYmMInHHeNOlaHZ4nhips0qx1cAUxqgBVykZhCFZFWHJdMb7NBWxgFOoI/rGMTm6JpQC5VlIlLlSaoZquQDLGAJvQGei4KuSSbCBXJq0sRFlSSfLG4nHxqXWrDU6660tKSFcSU@ryiyjw@i5qSpICnfSBmJ1KXuwFlsCG/xaO3jpWJdccp0PybjPuEnafAY28TR4LCSJY@2UONLx0HmXgsuWREuIpSWDpQgmYgAlaKVsCSVaoQMhzKVoGejvIxAtrpEO4TCR2T4IERh@1xJXK6hpg3or4TTTpSGI9VdJJwqodoLkHJLMN2KY85Ii7REWQGU42awM6TEuiJ42WU2kZx0ce90DmopOCnJjlyIoOy4DWahVZxuzA@ADqgJvcYrmoZx28dUO7gRR2Qqixqwxz7VHHxvmVymEhnVDMpuCNyjbiO1woyUOHYRLIS1xZLHApSUjQ0u2ZpmxQi/L1b/Yq55PTmUFKwRccFOKZ@eHGZGaCtE@2UtDM1FJNtAzAKtsZTQjYNDoSgmq/JUJKgGSVqzoHHhPWJJypdZY43BVJU9mlVEDiqgSl6HuCqPo5rfMSdNfwpaFRnKfkCKyFk5S7lq2hXJFIDXWbTYvB0YlsBrUwBR@Q7XEOtexhV61SUuGeYn6TbEUPMi1yPYtAKqKVBkewCyCBvVY5qDIGxGohQInsxqL31KLQQC1f9bTc6QNLUP8/TWx1Aws6rZmI9xQ3HtmuLrWCRXLhAz2br/BArHRWXo4bPQNZtl2K2KxMXkCjrWyzDy0oDat0KFYeozyHZrvUWY72@3YU0B4MaDPrkQgQBfX4WVts7ud1QknaupKDnMSFXU8xFQxTmxpjbaakqaMsURSD3AQGz1CCWTolEsl76JH4x4uAyOK4UDnFk/vclAQQu8n6igpOV6U9IV6ip6K0QtvMD2@YXbfmehe8wTonD0dmG8CbEg6pEpy8HI2glBbVERU1qrULryGFNGaNpuWGow3LWXfP1GSehJdfM6CH3BSH5hz5F9w6cuwvfuuxX2wzRDZ4tEHruhL9y2I1ioWyKPQwN8CKwlFkUjAjgrn0PWFh31vFzZEV9fU/YKLrd3PRxcU@RXh9aYij7qEWjakPWrF2oLOMWoHFvt/mDWOdExr6eGHJSPpTIsw9Na1DB7D3DTSqUTBd8vov2UjPREDL3/qSxuPKe4iev4U4r25la2FoxpDL22ULEYja3yQJfxUQcIeSW1jmM5GeHsLs4XZYQaf5DQDeQjTfnoG8k7XMNvrO27Ls2lSCWsj8E6JsRJ62mucjd8YXzwYHWixwRkQnExGB2mbNmE8zBu3g1KPe2GQO0Bzx9GWcGLTfscMpvf66B/xGhwMU9oL70IpawE@z47y89m9wRk/m92MDnrNx8xC9y/3Gkfwwo0foW2H/yXTfD5LXmMe/uP1tF@Y9X7TJpAdkgYXnpLQ85iEfH75nHBISQqnN8Qb9/@xgBLYLaudTXRmbxcN9PBOgMkGnBuoHTLbc48nk@OlkXrq8f0vd/7OHt/e5vPz84vT0fUh/LMcHo0P7/zaIjs8Toj3bzpyz61kXLjbNA9vRoeL7ckJjBzGHMYpjPswzmCcw7iAcbkICw20gMEXDr4CRrXY5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5pcwrmAwGCCdcxglDJDPqxcmL7507@XF4SuvHmXHr53k98/OLy6vHrz@xsM333r7nXffe/@DDz/6@JNPP/v8iy@/@vqbb7/7/ocff/r5l1@vF4ub3x49ZgUXVd0sV602T1yI68326e9//PnXYntRHf6tTcbhR1v8Aw) Arcyóu is the new language.

Comment: +1 I was going to do `(printf "23")`, but yours is shorter

Answer (score 1):

## 28. [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 6 bytes

```hs
f x=27
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwtbI/H9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKahuZ/AA) Declares a function `f` which takes any argument and returns `27`.

[Next toolbox:](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqDklt6Jpyvdp0772n5SQgCJKQQADBkMR0/Os@u3cHUnLa9AG87wDcxOFA24XG6MWtYrr24zfH15OTM1bkYnJvsvCsUAhON8wBuYBxdQUfllnBXBacwFXGQ2RKdQjL0lqktdHEq9qo88uaoOS0W9km8jUiq7KyY8rUTzEZV8x7yftJXWtEjncmEtBGlbTovWgL1WXM3@Vq/tSiZr5FPhbC1VKTB1uyvjPwLZhvkKBMIVibiE4kaLkmJPyW7QhVUdfigLKrS2QUiTvGmy5Fs8eLxEidVYqtB6YwRg24SskgDMmqCEumM96nqYgFnEId0TeOydE1oRQoz0KizJVSM1TLBVjGEHgDOhMFX5VMgg3k0qSNjShLOlneSDw2LrVmrdFZb21FCeFKelpVZhUdRs9NVUFSuJM2EKtL2YON2BHY4tfawUvHuuSS63xIxn3GTdLmM7CJp8FjIUkca6fEkY6HzrsUXLYkWkIsLRksRTARAyhBK2VLKNEKHQhhLkXLQH8fgWhxjXQIh4nMDkGIwPC7kbhaQU0b1FsJp5kuDUGsv0o6UUC1EyTnkGS@EcOclxRpj7AAKsPJZmVIj3FB9LTJaiI96@DY6x7QVHRSkBv7FEHZcRnIQq0625g9AB9QFXiLUzQP5bSPr3ZwJ4jKVhA1ZoN5rj362DC/TiE0rBuS2RS8QdlG7IYbLXHoIFwKaYUjiwUurRgZWrENy4wVelWu/8Ve9XxyKitYIeCCm1I8PT/MiNRUiPbJXhmaiUqygZ4BWGdroxkBg0bXSlDlr01QCZC0YkXnwHvCkpQrtcEah6sqeTKrjBpQRJW4DHVXGEU3v2VOmv4Stiw0kvuEFJGNcJJy17IdlCsCqbFus0U5MCqB9aAGpvAbqhXWuY4t9KptWjLMS9RvipXgQW5EdmgBUFWkyvAAZhE0qMcyB0XeiEAtFDiZ1Vj8lloMAqj9s56eI21oGeLvr4mlZmBRtzVb4YbiPjDD1bVOqFgmZLB3@y0WiI3O0sNho28wy7ZbE4uNyRNwrJVl5qEFtWmFDsXSY5Tv0eKAMtvZbs@eAsKLAX12LQIBurgOL2ub3e2sTjhRU1dymJOoqOMhpopxYkdrtNWUNGWMJZJ6gIPY6BFKIEOnXCp5Fz0a93AZGFEMBzq3eHKXg4IQ@jBRR0nJ8aKkL9RT9FSMXniD6fENs4fORPeaJ0Dn7OnAfBNgQ9IhVZKDl7MRhNqiIqKyVqV24TWkiNa02bbUYLxpKfv@sZLUk@jicxb8gJP6wJwj/4JLX4bt3Xct7oNthsgOjz5wRV@6b0G0VrFAHoUG/hZYSSiKRAJ2VDiHri887Hv7sCG6uqbuF1xs7WE@uqDIrwivNxV51CXUsiHtUSvWFnSOUTuw2P/DbHCkY9pIDz8sGUlnWoSht25k8BjmtpFOJQq@W0b/LVvpiRh4@VNf2npMcRfR8ycQ782tbC0c1Rh6aaNkMRpZ44Ms4acKEvZQahvDbD7C21uYHcwOM/gkpxnIQ5j103OQd7qG2V7fcVuezZJKWBuBd0qMldCzXuN8fH988froSIstzoDgZDI6Stu0CeNh3rg9lHrcC4PcEZo7jraEE5v1O@YwfdBH/4jX4GCY0V54F0pZC/B5fi8/n784OOPn85vRUa/5mFno/uVB4wheuPFDtO3wv2SWL@bJa8zDf7ye9Qvz3m/aBLJD0uDCUxJ6HpOQLy6fEQ4pSeH0hnjj/j8WUAK7ZbW3ic4c7KKBHt4JMNmAcwO1Q2Z77tFkcrwyUs88vv/l3t/5o9vbfHF@cXYyup7CP8v03ng6vEaIn1msuHC3LyJPTYAWsOlOb0bT5e7kBEYOYwHjFMZrMM5gnMO4gHG5DPAtYPClg6@AUS13OcjlIJeDXA5yOcjlIJeDXA5y@SWMKxgMBkjnHEYJA@Tz6rnJ8y@8tJzO5i@/cvxqfnp@9cb9t95@59333v/gw48@/uTTzz7/4suvvv7m2@@@/@HHn37@5dffrpfLmwePoE@u1vaxC3GzffL7H3/@tdxdVNO/tck4/EyLfwA)

```hs
['elf', 'logicode', 'visual-basic-net-mono', 'python2-pypy', 'silos', 'pushy', 'agony']
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f!"#$%&\'()*+,-./1234569:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^`cdghijkopqrtuvwxz{|}~\x7f'
```

Answer (score 1):

## 30. Visual Basic .NET (Mono), 9 bytes

```
MSGBOX 29
```

Pops up a system dialog box containing 29. Very similar to `alert` in javascript. It is case insensitive, but is usually written as `MsgBox`.

This can't be tested on TIO because `MsgBox` is a system window and that can't be seen online. The easiest way to test it is by pasting the code into a `.vbs` text file and running it on Windows. A `.vbs` file uses VBScript, a scripting version of VB that is very similar (`MsgBox` is the same between the two).

It's fun to use `MsgBox` again as that was the very first thing I ever programmed. In fifth grade, I made a series of `MsgBox` scripts to mess with friends.

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZk@M0EH7e/IowxTIJjId1Zudalqs4iqsooIACJsOuLMm2ElnS6kji5fjXPA/dLTuZ5XiQ@2tJfarVsutja83iTjPThOm705ujR@esKuXRydEisEojONswD@QSxvU1fFjhJPNF9BJXGY@Jad0jFMI5pI01xOvG6ourhqDitFu7NvE1IqcL0TNtm1eYgmsWguLDpGkMIs97mwgYqwUthiC7SvcFC/e5hr@yaFjokE@V9I0y5MGWrO8sfCsWWiQoU0nWZWIyiUatCcmwZTtCdTKNPKDi@goZTeKe8bbP0ezxIjPKFLVm65GprNUjrnMyCEOyasKKmYIPaapSBafQJPSNY3JMQygHyouYKfNCGYZquQTLGAJvQWem4KtWWbCFXNq8sZVC0MnyVuGxcWUM66wpBmsrSgjXKtCqtqvkMXpu6xqSwr1ykVgj1AA2ckdgi1/nRi8967NLvg8xGw8Ft1lbKMAmngZPlSJxrB2BIx8PnbeQXHUkKiCWjgwKGW3CAARopWxJLTtpIiHMpewY6B8ikB2ukQ7pMZHFIQgZGX43CldrqGmLemvpDTPCEsT6q5WXFVQ7QXIOSRFaOc4FRZEOCAugtpxs1pb0WB/lQNuiITKwHo69GQBNJa8kubFPEZQdV5EsNLp3rd0D8AFVgbc4RfNQTvv4Gg93gqjqJFFrN5jnJqCPLQvrHELL@jGZbcVblG3lbrzRCoeJ0ueQVjiKVOHSipGhFduwwjppVmL9D/Z64LNTRcUqCRfcCvnq/Dgjc1MhOiR7ZWkmacVGeg5gXaytYQQsGl1rSZW/tlFnQNKaVb0H7wkrUq71Bmscrqri2ay2ekQJVeIy1F1lNd38jnllh0vYsdgqHjLSRDbSK8pdx3ZQrgiUwbotFmJkdAbrUQ1M4TfWK6xzkzroVdu8ZFlQqN9WK8mj2sji0AKgqkiV5RHMImhRj2MeiryVkVoocKposPgdtRgEUPvnA71A2tIyxD9cE0fNwKFuZ7fSj8V9YMar67zUSWRksXeHLRaIS97Rw@FSaDHLrl8Ti40pEPCsU6II0IK6vEKH4ugxKvdocUCF612/Z88A4cWAPruWkQBdXI@XtSvud1YvvWyoK3nMSdLU8RBTxXi5ozXaagVNWeuI5B7gITZ6hDIo0CmfS96ngMYDXAZGFMOBzi1f3uegIKQ5TDRJUXKCFPSFekqBijHIYDE9oWXu0JnoXvMM6JwDHVhoI2zIOpTOcvBytpJQV9VEdNHp3C6CgRTRmrHbjhpMsB1lP7zQinoSXXzOYhhxVh@Z9@Rf9PnLsL2HvsN9sM0S2eHRR67pS/ctys5pFsmj2MLfAhOEkswkYkeFc@iHwsO@tw8bomsa6n7Rp84d5pOPmvxK8HpTkScjoJYtaU9Gs66ic0zGg8XhH2aDIx/TRgX4YSlIujAyjr11o2LAMLet8jpT8N0x@m/ZqkDEwsuf@9I2YIr7hJ6/hHhv71Tn4Kim0EtbrarJxNkQlYCfKkjYM2VcirP5BG9vZXcwO87gk5xnIA9xNkzPQd6bBmYHfaedOJ9llbA2Ae@0nGppZoPG@fTp9PLJ5IGRW5wBwaOjyYO8zdg4Heet30NlpoMwyD1Ac6fJCTix2bBjDtMHffSPeAMOxhnthXdBqEaCz/OT8mL@cHQmzOe3kweD5lPmoPuLg8YJvHDTZ2jb43/JrFzMs9eYh395PRsW5oPftAlkx6TBhackDDwmoVxc/Uc4pCSHMxjirf//WEAJ7Fb13iY6c7CLBgZ4L8BsA84N1I6ZHbjnR0enK6vMLOD7L/b@zp/f3ZWLi8uLcnJzDP8sxyfT4/E1Qny//SFPdx0BvcgI9k/J8e3keLl79AhGCWMB4wzGYxjnMC5gXMK4WsalAVrB4EsPXwmjXu5KkCxBsgTJEiRLkCxBsgTJEiTLKxjXMBgMkC45DAED5Mv6taPXH76xPJ7N33zrpDh9uzx7fH5x9eSdp@@@9/4HH3708Seffvb5F19@9fU33373/Q8//vTzLzfL5e2vz54zLmTdtGq11p2x7oWPabPdvfzt9z/@XO4u6@O/jC04/E3LvwE)

Answer (score 1):

## 31. [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), `print-31`

```python
print--31-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ItqCyo/P@/oCgzr0RX19hQ1/D/fwA)

`--31` is the same thing as `31`, then `-1` subtracts 1, making it 30.

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZne9s2EP5s/QpVbWqpNV1TjleadDzd8@leluuAIEhCAgEEQxLT8a/72b07kJLT8QG89wDcxOFA24XG6PmdYrr24yfj68nJGStyMTmazD0rFILTNXNALmBcXcGHZVYwlwUncJXxEJlSHcKytBZpbTTxqjbq/LImKDntVraJfIXIqqzsmDL1C0zGFfNe8n5S1xqR452JBLRRJS16L9pCdRnz97mav7ComW@Rj4VwtdTkwYasbw18C@YbJChTCNYmohMJWq4ICb9hW0JV1LXYo@zqEhlF4o7xpkvR7PA8MVJnlWKrgSmMUQOuUjIIQ7IqwpLpjPdpKmIBp1BH9I1jcnRNKAXKs5Aoc6XUDNVyAZYxBN6AzkTBVyWTYAO5NGljI8qSTpY3Eo@NS61Za3TWW1tSQriSnlaVWUaH0XNTVZAU7qQNxOpS9mAttgQ2@LV28NKxLrnkOh@ScZ9xk7T5DGziafBYSBLH2ilxpOOh8y4Fly2JlhBLSwZLEUzEAErQStkSSrRCB0KYS9Ey0N9HIFpcIx3CYSKzfRAiMPyuJa5WUNMG9VbCaaZLQxDrr5JOFFDtBMk5JJlvxDDnJUXaIyyAynCyWRnSY1wQPW2ymkjPOjj2ugc0FZ0U5MYuRVB2XAayUKvONmYHwAdUBd7iFM1DOe3iqx3cCaKyFUSNWWOea48@NsyvUggN64ZkNgVvULYR2@FGSxw6CJdCWuLIYoFLS0aGlmzNMmOFXparf7BXPZ@cygpWCLjgphQvzg8zIjUVon2yl4ZmopJsoGcAVtnKaEbAoNGVElT5KxNUAiStWNE58J6wJOVKrbHG4apKnswqowYUUSUuQ90VRtHNb5mTpr@ELQuN5D4hRWQtnKTctWwL5YpAaqzbbF4OjEpgNaiBKfyGaol1rmMLvWqTlgzzEvWbYil4kGuR7VsAVBWpMjyAWQQN6rHMQZE3IlALBU5mNRa/pRaDAGr/rKfnSBtahvj7a2KpGVjUbc1GuKG498xwda0TKpYJGezdfoMFYqOz9HDY6BvMsu1WxGJj8gQca2WZeWhBbVqhQ7H0GOU7NN@jzHa227GngPBiQJ9diUCALq7Dy9pm9zurE07U1JUc5iQq6niIqWKc2NIabTUlTRljiaQe4CA2eoQSyNApl0reRY/GPVwGRhTDgc4tnt/noCCE3k/UUVJyvCjpC/UUPRWjF95genzD7L4z0b3mCdA5ezow3wTYkHRIleTg5WwEobaoiKisValdeA0pojVtNi01GG9ayr5/piT1JLr4nAU/4KQ@MOfIv@DSl2F7912L@2CbIbLFow9c0ZfuWxCtVSyQR6GBvwVWEooikYAdFc6h6wsP@94ubIiurqn7BRdbu5@PLijyK8LrTUUedQm1bEh71Iq1BZ1j1A4s9v8waxzpmNbSww9LRtKZFmHorWsZPIa5aaRTiYLvltF/y0Z6IgZe/tSXNh5T3EX0/DnEe3MnWwtHNYZe2ihZjEbW@CBL@KmChN1KbWOYzkZ4ewuzhdlhBp/kNAN5CNN@egbyTtcw2@s7bsuzaVIJayPwTomxEnraa5yNH48vHo0OtNjgDAhOJqODtE2bMB7mjdtBqce9MMgdoLnjaEs4sWm/YwbTe330j3gNDoYp7YV3oZS1AJ9nR/n57MHgjJ/NbkYHveZjZqH7l3uNI3jhxrdo2@F/yTSfz5LXmId/eT3tF2a937QJZIekwYWnJPQ8JiGfX/5HOKQkhdMb4o37/1hACeyW1c4mOrO3iwZ6eC/AZAPODdQOme25p5PJ8dJIPfX4/pc7f2dP7@7y@fnF@eno@hD@WQ6PxofDa4SY7jYCeoER7J4OZNzq8GZ0uNienMDIYcxhnMJ4COMMxjmMCxiXi7DQQAsYfOHgK2BUi20OkjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZg2R@CeMKBoMB0jmHUcIA@bwavzR5@ZUHry4Op7PXXj86fuNk/vDs/OLy6tGbj5@89fY77773/gcffvTxJ59@9vkXX3719Tfffvf9Dz/@9PMv14vFza@3T1nBS1HVzXKlWvPMx/Vm@/y33//4c7G9qA7/0ibj8B8t/gY)

Answer (score 1):

## 33. [Minkolang](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 9 bytes

```
"332"(O).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83My87PScxL//9fydjYSEnDX1Pv/38A)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##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@EcOclxRpj7AAKsPJZmVIj3FB9LTJaiI96@DY6x7QVHRSkBu7FEHZcRnIQq0625gdAB9QFXiLUzQP5bSLr3ZwJ4jKVhA1Zo15rj362DC/SiE0rBuS2RS8QdlGbIcbLXHoIFwKaYkjiwUuLRkZWrI1y4wVelmu/sFe9XxyKitYIeCCm1LcnR9mRGoqRPtkLw3NRCXZQM8ArLKV0YyAQaMrJajyVyaoBEhasaJz4D1hScqVWmONw1WVPJlVRg0ookpchrorjKKb3zInTX8JWxYayX1CishaOEm5a9kWyhWB1Fi32bwcGJXAalADU/gN1RLrXMcWetUmLRnmJeo3xVLwINci27cAqCpSZXgAswga1GOZgyJvRKAWCpzMaix@Sy0GAdT@WU/PkTa0DPH318RSM7Co25qNcENx75nh6lonVCwTMti7/QYLxEZn6eGw0TeYZdutiMXG5Ak41soy89CC2rRCh2LpMcp3aL5Hme1st2NPAeHFgD67EoEAXVyHl7XNbndWJ5yoqSs5zElU1PEQU8U4saU12mpKmjLGEkk9wEFs9AglkKFTLpW8ix6Ne7gMjCiGA51bPL/NQUEIvZ@oo6TkeFHSF@opeipGL7zB9PiG2X1nonvNE6Bz9nRgvgmwIemQKsnBy9kIQm1REVFZq1K78BpSRGvabFpqMN60lH3/TEnqSXTxOQt@wEl9YM6Rf8GlL8P27rsW98E2Q2SLRx@4oi/dtyBaq1ggj0IDfwusJBRFIgE7KpxD1xce9r1d2BBdXVP3Cy62dj8fXVDkV4TXm4o86hJq2ZD2qBVrCzrHqB1Y7P9h1jjSMa2lhx@WjKQzLcLQW9cyeAxz00inEgXfLaP/lo30RAy8/KkvbTymuIvo@XOI9/pGthaOagy9tFGyGI2s8UGW8FMFCXsitY1hOhvh7S3MFmaHGXyS0wzkIUz76RnIO13DbK/vuC3PpkklrI3AOyXGSuhpr3E2fji@eDA60GKDMyA4mYwO0jZtwniYN24HpR73wiB3gOaOoy3hxKb9jhlM7/XRP@JjcDBMaS@8C6WsBfg8O8rPZ/cGZ/xsdj066DUfMwvdv9xrHMELN36Cth3@l0zz@Sx5jXn4l9fTfmHW@02bQHZIGlx4SkLPYxLy@eV/hENKUji9Id64/48FlMBuWe1sojN7u2igh7cCTDbg3EDtkNmeezqZHC@N1FOP73@583f29OYmn59f5hejx4fwz3J4ND4cXiPEdLcR0AuMYPd0IJP@VBDdeWgPr0eHi@3JCYwcxhzGKYz7MM5gnMO4gHG5CAsNtIDBFw6@Aka12OYgmYNkDpI5SOYgmYNkDpI5SOaXMK5gMBggnXMYJQyQz6vxC5MXX7r38uJwOnvl1aPs@LWTfH56/@z84vLqwesPH73x5ltvv/Pue@9/8OFHH3/y6Weff/HlV19/8@133//w408///J4sbj@9cnTgpeiqpvlSrXa2Gc@xPVm2z3/7fc//lxsL6rDv7TJOPxki78B)

Never heard of this one before, I have no idea how it works. It just did weird stuff and I went "ok fine" and got it to print what I wanted. :D

Answer (score 1):

## 38. [Go](https://golang.org/), 20 bytes

First 20 byte Go solution on PPCG..? :P

```go
func()int{return 37}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZx8WVmVuQX1SioJSWW6LExZVWmpcMltDQrOZSAII0BSvb/yBRDc3MvJLqotSS0qI8BWPz2v9g2dwSvYAioIRGmoamJlftfwA)

[Next toolbox.](https://tio.run/##dVZXk9s2EH4@/QrlEs9JyeFiyr7m2JPeey8nxwZBkIQEAjCKJHoy@dd5dnYXpHROeVjuh7IViwVdH1trFi80N02YPpreHN8952Uhj0@PF4GXGsG9DffALoGur@HDmZPcs@glrnIRE9e6R1hVziFvrKGxbqy@uGoIKkG7tWuTWCNymlU917Z5acCE5iEoMUyaxiDyoreJgLG6osUQZFfqnvFwe9SIlxYNDx2OUyl9owx5sCXrOwvfkocWGcqUkneZmcyiUWtCMmz5jlCdTCMPiF1f4UCTuOei7XM0e7zIA2VYrfl6HJTW6hHXORmEIVk1YcUNE0OaylTCKTQJfROYHNMQyoEKFjPnvlKGo1ohwTKGIFrQmTn4qlUWbCGXNm9sZVXRyYpW4bEJZQzvrGGDtRUlRGgVaFXbVfIYvbB1DUkRXrlIQ1OpAWzkjsAWv86NXnreZ5d8H2I2HpiwWVtgYBNPQ6RSkTjWToWUj4fOu5JCdSRaQSwdGaxktAkDqEArZUtq2UkTCWEuZcdB/xCB7HCNdEiPiWSHIGTk@N0oXK2hpi3qraU33FSWINZfrbwsodoJknPIWGjlOBcURTogLIDaCrJZW9JjfZQDb1lDbBh6OPZmADSVvJLkxj5FUHZCRbLQ6N61dg/AB1QF3uIUzUM57eNrPNwJ4qqTxK3dYJ6bgD62PKxzCC3vx2S2pWhRtpW78UYrJBOlzyGtkFgqcWnFydCKbzizTppVtf7H8HoYZ6dYyUsJF9xW8uX5cUbmpkJ8SPbK0kzSio/8HMCara3hBCwaXWtJlb@2UWdA0pqXvQfvCStSrvUGaxyuqhLZrLZ6RAlV4jLUXWk13fyOe2WHS9jx2CoRMtLENtIryl3Hd1CuCJTBumWLahzoDNajGpjCb6xXWOcmddCrtnnJ8qBQvy1XUkS1kezQAqCqSJUVEcwiaFGP4x6KvJWRWiiMFGuw@B21GARQ@@cDv0De0jLEP1wTR83AoW5nt9KPxX0YjFfXealTlZHF3h22WCAueUcPh0uhxSy7fk1DbEyBgOedqliAFtTlFToUR49RsUeLA2Kud/1@eA8QXgzos2sZCdDF9XhZO3a7s3rpZUNdyWNOkqaOh5gqxssdrdFWW9GUtY5Y7gEeYqNHKAOGTvlc8j4FNB7gMnDiGA50bvn89ggKQprDRJMUJSfIir5QTylQMQYZLKYntNwdOhPda5EBnXOgAwtthA1Zh9JZDl7OVhLqypqYZp3O7SIYSBGtGbvtqMEE21H2wzOtqCfRxRc8hhFn9ZF7T/5Fn78c23voO9wH2yyxHR59FJq@dN@i7JzmkTyKLfwt8IpQkplF7KhwDv1QeNj39mFDdE1D3S/61LnDfPJRk18JXm8q8mQqqGVL2pPRvCvpHJPxYHH4h9kg5WPaqAA/LIykmZFx7K0bFQOGuW2V15mD747Tf8tWBWIWXv7cl7YBU9wn9Pw5xPv4heocHNUUemmrVTmZOBuiquCnChL2RBmX4mw@wdtb2h3MjjP4JOcZyEOcDdNzkPemgdlB31lXnc@ySlibgHdaTrU0s0HjfPpwevlgcmTkFmdA8Ph4cpS3GRun47z1e6jMdBAGuSM0d5ZcBSc2G3bMYfqgj/4Rb8DBOKO98C5UqpHg8/y0uJjfGZ0J8/njydGg@Yw76P7VQeMEXrjpE7Tt8b9kVizm2WvMw7@8ng0L88Fv2gSyY9LgwlMShjEmoVhc/Uc4pCSHMxgSrf//WEAJ7Fb13iY6c7CLBgZ4K8BsA84N1I6ZHUZPj4/PVlaZWcD3v9r7O3/64kWxuLi6uJzcnIzP0Mnp9IQuNQJ6ehHkvxJEUHrI9g3t5PHkZLm7WwDdA7oPdA50AXQJdLWMSwO8BBJLD18JVC93xV0gkCoWQCBZgGQBkgVIFiBZXAFdA3EgkC4EUAUE8kU9feX41dfuLE9ef@OUnb15t1jcP7@4un7w1sNHb7/z7nvvf/DhRx9/8ulnn3/x5Vdff/Ptd9//8ONPP//y6283y@Xj35885WXVtKu17qx7FjbbXf/8jz@Xu8v65C9jmYDfZ/k3)

Answer (score 1):

## 39. [wsf](https://github.com/dkudriavtsev/wsf), 58 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9O@/9fAQ64wAgTcAIRFydIjpMTSZTz/38A)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZc9s2EH62foXqNmOpNV1Tia80md73fR92moAASEICAQSHJGY6/dd9dncXpOT0eAD3WwB7YrGg62NrzeJWM9OE6ePp9eHpGatKeXh8uAis0gjur5kHcgHj6go@rHCS@SJ6iauMx8S07hEK4RzSxhridWP1@WVDUHHarV2b@AqR04XombbNS0zBNQtB8WHSNAaR571NBIzVghZDkF2l@4KFu1zDX1o0LHTIp0r6RhnyYEPWtxa@FQstEpSpJOsyMZlEo1aEZNiwLaE6mUbuUXF1iYwmcc942@dodniRGWWKWrPVyFTW6hHXORmEIVk1YcVMwYc0VamCU2gS@sYxOaYhlAPlRcyUeaEMQ7VcgmUMgbegM1PwVass2EIubd7YSiHoZHmr8Ni4MoZ11hSDtSUlhGsVaFXbZfIYPbd1DUnhXrlIrBFqAGu5JbDBr3Ojl5712SXfh5iNh4LbrC0UYBNPg6dKkTjWjsCRj4fOW0iuOhIVEEtHBoWMNmEAArRStqSWnTSREOZSdgz0DxHIDtdIh/SYyGIfhIwMv2uFqzXUtEW9tfSGGWEJYv3VyssKqp0gOYekCK0c54KiSAeEBVBbTjZrS3qsj3KgbdEQGVgPx94MgKaSV5Lc2KUIyo6rSBYa3bvW7gD4gKrAW5yieSinXXyNhztBVHWSqLVrzHMT0MeWhVUOoWX9mMy24i3KtnI73miFw0Tpc0hLHEWqcGnJyNCSrVlhnTRLsfoHezXw2amiYpWEC26FfHl@nJG5qRAdkr20NJO0YiM9A7AqVtYwAhaNrrSkyl/ZqDMgac2q3oP3hBUp13qNNQ5XVfFsVls9ooQqcRnqrrKabn7HvLLDJexYbBUPGWkia@kV5a5jWyhXBMpg3RYLMTI6g9WoBqbwG@sl1rlJHfSqTV6yLCjUb6ul5FGtZbFvAVBVpMryCGYRtKjHMQ9F3spILRQ4VTRY/I5aDAKo/bOBniNtaRniH66Jo2bgULezG@nH4t4z49V1XuokMrLYu8MGC8Ql7@jhcCm0mGXXr4jFxhQIeNYpUQRoQV1eoUNx9BiVO7TYo8L1rt@x9wHhxYA@u5KRAF1cj5e1K@52Vi@9bKgrecxJ0tTxEFPFeLmlNdpqBU1Z64jkHuAhNnqEMijQKZ9L3qeAxgNcBkYUw4HOLV/c5aAgpNlPNElRcoIU9IV6SoGKMchgMT2hZW7fmehe8wzonAMdWGgjbMg6lM5y8HK2klBX1UR00encLoKBFNGasZuOGkywHWU/PNeKehJdfM5iGHFWH5n35F/0@cuwvYe@w32wzRLZ4tFHrulL9y3KzmkWyaPYwt8CE4SSzCRiR4Vz6IfCw763CxuiaxrqftGnzu3nk4@a/ErwelORJyOgli1pT0azrqJzTMaDxeEfZo0jH9NaBfhhKUi6MDKOvXWtYsAwN63yOlPw3TH6b9moQMTCy5/70iZgivuEnr@AeJ/cqs7BUU2hl7ZaVZOJsyEqAT9VkLCnyrgUZ/MJ3t7KbmF2nMEnOc9AHuJsmJ6DvDcNzA76TjpxNssqYW0C3mk51dLMBo3z6aPpxcPJgZEbnAHBw8PJQd5mbJyO89bvoDLTQRjkDtDcSXICTmw27JjD9F4f/SNeg4NxRnvhXRCqkeDz/Lg8n98bnQnz@ZPJwaD5hDno/mKvcQIv3PQp2vb4XzIrF/PsNebhX17PhoX54DdtAtkxaXDhKQkDj0koF5f/EQ4pyeEMhnjr/z8WUAK7Vb2zic7s7aKBAd4JMNuAcwO1Y2YH7tnh4cnSKjML@P6Lnb/zZ7e35eL88uLB5PpofIaOjqdHdKkR0NOLIP@VINp1MmTE0ZPJ0c32tIRxH8YDGGcwzmFcwLiEUcHgNx6@EkZ9sy1PYYBEuYABUiVIlSBVglQJUiVIlVcwGAyQLjkMAQPky/qVw1dfu3dz9Pobx8XJm6fl4sHZ@eXVw7cePX77nXffe/@DDz/6@JNPP/v8iy@/@vqbb7/7/ocff/r5l19/u765efL702esEk27XOnOuudhvdn2L/7482Z7UR/9ZWzB4b9Z/g0)

Answer (score 1):

## 42. [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 8 bytes `print 41`

```
print 41
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/7@gKDOvRMHE8P9/AA)

Little boring, but it works

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4p17acNt177xW5CQiCJCQQQDAkMR3/us/u3YGUnI6H430YN3E40HahMXp@q5iu/fjB@OHk7IIVuZicTOaeFQrB@YY5YFdA19fwYZkVzGXBCVxlPESmVIewLK1FXhtNY1UbdbmoCUpOu5VtIl8jsiorO6ZM/cwg44p5L3k/qWuNyPHORALaqJIWvRdtobqM@bujmj@zqJlvcRwL4WqpyYMtWd8Z@BbMN8hQphCsTUwnFrRcExJ@y3aEqqhrcUDZ9QIHisQd402XotnjeRpInVWKrYdBYYwacJWSQRiSVRGWTGe8T1MRCziFOqJvHJOja0IpUJ6FxJkrpWaolguwjCHwBnQmDr4qmQQbyKVJGxtRlnSyvJF4bFxqzVqjs97aihLClfS0qswqOoyem6qCpHAnbaChLmUPNmJHYItfawcvHeuSS67zIRn3GTdJm8/AJp4Gj4UkcaydEikdD513KbhsSbSEWFoyWIpgIgZQglbKllCiFToQwlyKloH@PgLR4hrpEA4TmR2CEIHhdyNxtYKaNqi3Ek4zXRqCWH@VdKKAaidIziHLfCOGOS8p0h5hAVSGk83KkB7jguh5k9XE@qGDY697QFPRSUFu7FMEZcdlIAu16mxj9gB8QFXgLU7RPJTTPr7awZ0gLltB3JgN5rn26GPD/DqF0LBuSGZT8AZlG7EbbrRE0kG4FNIKKYsFLq0YGVqxDcuMFXpVrv8xvO7HyamsYIWAC25K8ez8MCNSUyHeJ3tlaCYqyQZ@AWCdrY1mBAwaXStBlb82QSVA0ooVnQPvCUtSrtQGaxyuquTJrDJqQBFV4jLUXWEU3fyWOWn6S9iy0EjuE1LENsJJyl3LdlCuCKTGus3m5TBQCawHNTCF31CtsM51bKFXbdOSYV6iflOsBA9yI7JDC4CqIlWGBzCLoEE9ljko8kYEaqEwklmNxW@pxSCA2r/o@SXyhpYh/v6aWGoGFnVbsxVuKO7DYLi61gkVy4QM9m6/xQKx0Vl6OGz0DWbZdmsaYmPyBBxrZZl5aEFtWqFDsfQY5Xs0P6DMdrbbD88B4cWAPrsWgQBdXIeXtc3udlYnnKipKznMSVTU8RBTxTixozXaakqaMsYSSz3AQWz0CCWQoVMulbyLHo17uAyMOIYDnVs8vTuCghD6MFFHScnxoqQv1FP0VIxeeIPp8Q2zh85E95onQOfs6cB8E2BD0iFVkoOXsxGE2qIiprJWpXbhNaSI1rTZttRgvGkp@/6JktST6OJzFvyAk/rAnCP/gktfhu3ddy3ug22G2A6PPnBFX7pvQbRWsUAehQb@FlhJKIrEAnZUOIeuLzzse/uwIbq6pu4XXGztYT66oMivCK83FXnUJdSyIe1RK9YWdI5RO7DY/8NskNIxbaSHH5aMpDMtwtBbNzJ4DHPbSKcSB98to/@WrfTEDLz8qS9tPaa4i@j5U4j35la2Fo5qDL20UbIYjazxQZbwUwUJeyS1jWE6G@HtLcwOZocZfJLTDOQhTPvpGcg7XcNsr@@0LS@mSSWsjcA7JcZK6GmvcTZ@fXx1f3SkxRZnQHAyGR2lbdqE8TBv3B5KPe6FQe4IzZ1GW8KJTfsdM5g@6KN/xIfgYJjSXngXSlkL8Hl2kl/O7g3O@NnsZnTUaz5lFrp/edA4ghdu/AhtO/wvmebzWfIa8/Avr6f9wqz3mzaB7JA0uPCUhH6MScjni/8Ih5SkcHpDvHH/Hwsogd2y2ttEZw520UAP7wSYbMC5gdohs/3o8WRyujJSTz2@/@Xe39nj29t8frlYnI8eHg/P0PHJ@JheXATpZwRRiZ9U9Yj21@v4ZnS83J2dAeVAc6BzoFeBLoAuga6AFsuw1MALIL508BVA1XKXg2QOkjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZL4CugRgQSOccqAQC@bx6bvL8C/deXB5PZy@9fJKdvnI2P7@4vFpc33/t9QdvvPnW2@@8@977H3z40ceffPrZ5198@dXX33z73fc//PjTz788XC5vfn30mBW8FFXdrNaqNU983Gx33dPffv/jz@Xuqjr@S5uMw9@0@Bs)

Comment: Welcome to SILOS

Answer (score 1):

## 43. [Logicode](https://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode), 19 bytes

```
out @110100+@110010
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8lPz0zOT0n9/z@/tETBwdDQwNDAQBtEAxn//wMA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZpm9smEP4c/wp323TtPtE28mavNGmf3vd9N04TBEjCRkA4bCs9/nU/b2cGyd70@IDmHWBOhkGuj601i2vNTBOmD6ePju6esaqUR3eOFoFVGsHphnkgFzCuruDDCieZL6KXuMp4TEzrHqEQziFtrCFeN1afXzYEFafd2rWJrxE5XYieadu8wBRcsxAUHyZNYxB53ttEwFgtaDEE2VW6L1i4yTX8hUXDQod8qqRvlCEPtmR9Z@FbsdAiQZlKsi4Tk0k0ak1Ihi3bEaqTaeQBFVeXyGgS94y3fY5mjxeZUaaoNVuPTGWtHnGdk0EYklUTVswUfEhTlSo4hSahbxyTYxpCOVBexEyZF8owVMslWMYQeAs6MwVftcqCLeTS5o2tFIJOlrcKj40rY1hnTTFYW1FCuFaBVrVdJY/Rc1vXkBTulYvEGqEGsJE7Alv8Ojd66VmfXfJ9iNl4KLjN2kIBNvE0eKoUiWPtCBz5eOi8heSqI1EBsXRkUMhoEwYgQCtlS2rZSRMJYS5lx0D/EIHscI10SI@JLA5ByMjwu1G4WkNNW9RbS2@YEZYg1l@tvKyg2gmSc0iK0MpxLiiKdEBYALXlZLO2pMf6KAfaFg2RgfVw7M0AaCp5JcmNfYqg7LiKZKHRvWvtHoAPqAq8xSmah3Lax9d4uBNEVSeJWrvBPDcBfWxZWOcQWtaPyWwr3qJsK3fjjVY4TJQ@h7TCUaQKl1aMDK3YhhXWSbMS63@wVwOfnSoqVkm44FbIF@fHGZmbCtEh2StLM0krNtIzAOtibQ0jYNHoWkuq/LWNOgOS1qzqPXhPWJFyrTdY43BVFc9mtdUjSqgSl6HuKqvp5nfMKztcwo7FVvGQkSaykV5R7jq2g3JFoAzWbbEQI6MzWI9qYAq/sV5hnZvUQa/a5iXLgkL9tlpJHtVGFocWAFVFqiyPYBZBi3oc81DkrYzUQoFTRYPF76jFIIDaPxvoOdKWliH@4Zo4agYOdTu7lX4s7gMzXl3npU4iI4u9O2yxQFzyjh4Ol0KLWXb9mlhsTIGAZ50SRYAW1OUVOhRHj1G5R4sDKlzv@j17CggvBvTZtYwE6OJ6vKxdcbOzeullQ13JY06Spo6HmCrGyx2t0VYraMpaRyT3AA@x0SOUQYFO@VzyPgU0HuAyMKIYDnRu@fwmBwUhzWGiSYqSE6SgL9RTClSMQQaL6Qktc4fORPeaZ0DnHOjAQhthQ9ahdJaDl7OVhLqqJqKLTud2EQykiNaM3XbUYILtKPvhmVbUk@jicxbDiLP6yLwn/6LPX4btPfQd7oNtlsgOjz5yTV@6b1F2TrNIHsUW/haYIJRkJhE7KpxDPxQe9r192BBd01D3iz517jCffNTkV4LXm4o8GQG1bEl7Mpp1FZ1jMh4sDv8wGxz5mDYqwA9LQdKFkXHsrRsVA4a5bZXXmYLvjtF/y1YFIhZe/tyXtgFT3Cf0/DnE@/hadQ6Oagq9tNWqmkycDVEJ@KmChD1RxqU4m0/w9lZ2B7PjDD7JeQbyEGfD9BzkvWlgdtB30omzWVYJaxPwTsuplmY2aJxPH0wv7k9uGbnFGRA8OprcytuMjdNx3vo9VGY6CIPcLTR3kpyAE5sNO@YwfdBH/4iPwME4o73wLgjVSPB5fqc8n98enQnz@ePJrUHzCXPQ/cVB4wReuOkTtO3xv2RWLubZa8zDv7yeDQvzwW/aBLJj0uDCUxIGHpNQLi7/IxxSksMZDPHW/38soAR2q3pvE5052EUDA7wRYLYB5wZqx8wO3NOjo5OVVWYW8P0Xe3/nT6@vy8X55dVi8uiYXtnjO9Pj/AOCSOAnVzqi/ZVCJj9vx48nx8vd3bswShgLGKcw7sE4g3EO4wLG5TIuDdAKBl96@EoY9XJXgmQJkiVIliBZgmQJkiVIliBZXsK4gsFggHTJYQgYIF/WLx29/MrtV5fHs/lrd4qT1xen987OLy6v7r/x4OGbb739zrvvvf/Bhx99/Mmnn33@xZdfff3Nt999/8OPP/38y6Pl8vGvT56yigtZN61arXVn3DMfNttd//y33//4c7m7qI//Mrbg8C8t/wY)

Comment: I didn't know that Logicode could output anything other than 1 and 0, I thought we were going to have to wait until 100.

Comment: @WheatWizard: Yeah, at a first glance I was thinking the same but discovered that it could :)

Comment: Well brainbool got added an it can't output anything other than 1 and 0 *for sure*.  So it looks like we are going to have to wait on that one.

Comment: @WheatWizard surely brainbool could output the correct number in base2? You said in the comments of the OP that outputting in a base other than 10 is acceptible if it's the standard way of outputting in that language

Comment: @Mayube Yes seems like it I forgot I said that.

Comment: @WheatWizard I attempted a solution at #7 (IIRC) that output the value in base 2. I just didn't have all of the symbols required (cough, `out`, cough). But yes, logicode *can* output ascii.

Answer (score 1):

## 46. [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), `PRINt45`

```
4PRINt45
```

I ran out of uppercase letters, so I used a lowercase `t`! I guess you could call it PRIN-t or Printy!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fRCEgyNMvRMHE9P9/AA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXk9s2EH4@/QpFiXNSYl5MOdccO71NymQymVTrYoMASEICARhFEp3yr/Ps7C5I6ZzyAOyHshWLBVwfW2uWLzQzTZg@mj6e3TtnVSlnd2fLwCqN4P6WeSCX0K6voWOFk8wX0UtcZTwmpnWPUAjnkDbW0Fg3Vl9cNQQVp93atYlvEDldiJ5p27w0KLhmISg@TJrGIPK8t4mAsVrQYgiyq3RfsHB71PCXFg0LHY5TJX2jDFmwI@17C33FQosEeSrJukxMJtGoDSEZdmxPqE6mkUdUXF/hQBO7Z7ztszcHvMwDZYpas804qKzVI65zMAhDsGrCipmCD2GqUgWn0CS0jWNwTEMoO8qLmCnzQhmGYrkEzegCb0FmpmCrVpmxhVjavLGVQtDJ8lbhsXFlDOusKQZtawoI1yrQqrbr5NF7busagsK9cpGGRqgBbOWewA5750YrPeuzSb4PMSsPBbdZWihAJ54GT5UidswdgS0fD523kFx1xCrAl44UChltQgcESKVoSS07aSIhjKXsGMgfPJAdrpEM6TGQxdEJGRn2W4WrNeS0Rbm19IYZYQli/tXKywqynSAZh6QIrRzngiJPB4QJUFtOOmtLcqyPcqBt0RAZhh6OvRkATSWvJJlxCBGkHVeRNDS6d609ALABRYG1OEXzkE4H/xoPd4Ko6iRRa7cY5yagjS0Lm@xCy/oxmG3FW@Rt5X680QqbidJnl9bYilTh0pqRojXbssI6adZi84/h9TDORhUVqyRccCvky/PjjMxFhegQ7LWlmaQVG@k5gE2xsYYRsKh0oyVl/sZGnQFxa1b1HqwnrEi41lvMcbiqime12uoRJRSJy5B3ldV08zvmlR0uYcdiq3jISBPZSq8odh3bQ7oiUAbztliKcaAz2IxiYAr7WK8xz03qoFbt8pJlQaF8W60lj2ori2MJgKwiUZZHUIugRTmOeUjyVkYqoTBSRYPJ76jEIIDcPx/oBdKWlsH/4Zo4KgYOZTu7k35M7uNgvLrOS51ERhZrd9hhgrjkHT0cLoUWo@z6DQ2xMAUCnnVKFAFKUJdX6FAcPUblAS2PqHC96w/D@4DwYkCd3chIgC6ux8vaFbcrq5deNlSVPMYkaap4iCljvNzTGm21gqasdURyDfDgGz1CGRRolM8p71NA5QEuAyOK7kDlls9vjyAhpDlONElRcIIU1EM@pUDJGGSwGJ7QMnesTHSveQZ0zoEOLLQRNmQZSmc@eDlbSairaiK66HQuF8FAiGjN2F1HBSbYjqIfnmlFNYkuPmcxjDiLj8x7si/63DMs76HvcB9ss0T2ePSRa@rpvkXZOc0iWRRb@C0wQSjJTCJWVDiHfkg8rHsHt8G7pqHqF33q3HE@@ajJrgSvNyV5MgJy2ZL0ZDTrKjrHZDxoHP4wW2z5mLYqwIelIO7CyDjW1q2KAd3ctcrrTMF2x@jfslOBiIWXP9elXcAQ9wktfw7@3rxQnYOjmkItbbWqJhNnQ1QCPlUQsCfKuBTniwne3sruYXacwSc5z0Ac4nyYXgC/Nw3MDvLOOnE@zyJhbQLWaTnV0swHiYvpw@nlg8mJkTucAcbZbHKStxkbp@O89QeozHRgBr4TVHeWnIATmw87FjB9lEd/xMdgYJzTXngXhGok2Ly4W14s7ozGhMXiZnIySD5jDqq/OEqcwAs3fYK6Pf5L5uVyka3GOPzL6vmwsBjspk3AOwYNLjwFYRhjEMrl1X@4Q0KyO4Mi3vr/9wWEwG5VH3SiMUe9qGCAtxzMOuDcQOwY2WH0dDY7W1tl5gHff3Gwd/H0xYtyeXFdXk0en9Ire3p3epo/IIjyE4bo8HWkDbd@D7SNXsDTm8npan/vHrQS2hLafWhvQzuHdgHtEtrVKq4M0AoaX3noJbR6tS@BswTOEjhL4CyBswTOEjhL4CyvoF1DY9CAu@TQBDTgL@tXZq@@duf11el88cabxdlb98rl/YvLq@sH7zx89O5773/w4Ucff/LpZ59/8eVXX3/z7Xff//DjTz//8ni1uvn1yVNWcSHrpl1vdGfcMx/Sbt8//@33P/5c7S/r07@MLTj8qOXf)

Answer (score 1):

## 48. [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), `cake eating peril (#47)`

```
#lang racket (print 47)
```

"Cake eating peril?!?", you might ask.
Well, if I said `peak #7 in a rectilinear triple integral r(4)` instead, then you'd all be confused and `pinkcartgel() #47` just doesn't make sense, so `cake eating peril (#47)` was a natural choice. Plus, maybe Racket eats cake in it's free time. We'll never know.

It's no fun to say the chars you used sorted alphabetically. Anagrams are better. I'd suggest you do the same :).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@f9fOScxL12hCMxT0CgoyswrUTAx1/z/HwA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4p1ytNuvfey3ISEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5HQ/gfTjgJg4H2i40Rs9vFdO1Hz8cX09OzliRi8nRZO5ZoRCcrpkDcgHj6go@LLOCuSw4gauMh8iU6hCWpbVIa6Nprmqjzi9rgpLTbmWbyFeIrMrKjilTPzfJuGLeS94zda0ROd6ZSEAbVdKi96ItVJcxf3dW8@cWNfMtzmMhXC01ebAh61sD34L5BgnKFIK1iehEgpYrQsJv2JZQFXUt9ii7usSJInHHeNOlaHZ4niZSZ5Viq2FSGKMGXKVkEIZkVYQl0xnv01TEAk6hjugbx@TomlAKlGchUeZKqRmq5QIsYwi8AZ2Jgq9KJsEGcmnSxkaUJZ0sbyQeG5das9borLe2pIRwJT2tKrOMDqPnpqogKdxJG2iqS9mDtdgS2ODX2sFLx7rkkut8SMZ9xk3S5jOwiafBYyFJHGunxJGOh867FFy2JFpCLC0ZLEUwEQMoQStlSyjRCh0IYS5Fy0B/H4FocY10CIeJzPZBiMDwu5a4WkFNG9RbCaeZLg1BrL9KOlFAtRMk55BkvhEDz0uKtEdYAJXhZLMypMe4IHraZDWRfurg2OseECs6KciNXYqg7LgMZKFWnW3MDoAPqAq8RRbxoZx28dUO7gRR2Qqixqwxz7VHHxvmVymEhnVDMpuCNyjbiO1woyUOHYRLIS1xZLHApSUjQ0u2ZpmxQi/L1T@mV/08OZUVrBBwwU0pnucPHJGaCtE@2UtDnKgkG@gZgFW2MpoRMGh0pQRV/soElQBJK1Z0DrwnLEm5UmuscbiqkiezyqgBRVSJy1B3hVF081vmpOkvYctCI7lPSBFZCycpdy3bQrkikBrrNpuXw0QlsBrUAAu/oVpinevYQq/apCXDvET9plgKHuRaZPsWAFVFqgwPYBZBg3osc1DkjQjUQmEmsxqL31KLQQC1f9bTc6QNLUP8/TWx1Aws6rZmI9xQ3PvJcHWtEyqWCRns3X6DBWKjs/Rw2OgbzLLtVjTFxuQJONbKMvPQgtq0Qodi6THKd2i@R5ntbLebngLCiwF9diUCAbq4Di9rm93trE44UVNXcpiTqKjjIaaKcWJLa7TVlMQyxhJJPcBBbPQIJZChUy6VvIsejXu4DIwohgOdWzy7O4OCEHrPqKOk5HhR0hfqKXoqRi@8wfT4htl9Z6J7zROgc/Z0YL4JsCHpkCrJwcvZCEJtURFRWatSu/AaUkRr2mxaajDetJR9/1RJ6kl08TkLfsBJfWDOkX/BpS/D9u67FvfBNkNki0cfuKIv3bcgWqtYII9CA38LrCQURSIBOyqcQ9cXHva9XdgQXV1T9wsutnbPjy4o8ivC601FHnUJtWxIe9SKtQWdY9QOLPb/MGsc6ZjW0sMPS0bSmRZh6K1rGTyGuWmkU4mC75bRf8tGeiIGXv7UlzYeU9xF9PwZxHtzK1sLRzWGXtooWYxG1vggS/ipgoQ9ltrGMJ2N8PYWZgvcgYNPcuJAHsK0Z89A3ukauL2@47Y8myaVsDYC75QYK6GnvcbZ@MH44v7oQIsNckBwMhkdpG3ahPHAN24HpR73wiB3gOaOoy3hxKb9jhmw9/roH/EaHAxT2gvvQilrAT7PjvLz2b3BGT@b3YwOes3HzEL3L/caR/DCjR@jbYf/JdN8PkteYx7@5fW0X5j1ftMmkB2SBheektDPMQn5/PI/wiElKZzeEG/c/8cCSmC3rHY20Zm9XTTQwzsBJhtwbqB2yGw/ezKZHC@N1FOP73@583f25PY2n59fzc9G14f0yh4ejQ/TDwii9IQh2v06EptePETD7/fhzehwsT05gZHDmMM4hfE6jDMY5zAuYFwuwkIDLWDwhYOvgFEttjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZg2QOkvkljCsYDAZI5xxGCQPk82r8wuTFl@69vDh85dWj7Pi1k3x@enZ@eXX/jQcP33zr7Xfefe/9Dz786ONPPv3s8y@@/Orrb7797vsffvzp519@vV4sbh49flKUVbNszVMf15tt9@y33//4c7G9qA7/0ibj8C8t/gY)

Answer (score 1):

## 54. [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 2 bytes

```
53
```

Sorry for taking your numbers but there's really no better solution.

(oh wait, 5 and 3 got added to the toolbox again)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/39T4/38A)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4pxytNuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5HQ/gfTjgJg4H2i40Rs9vFdO1Hz8aX09OzliRi8nRZO5ZoRCcrpkDcgHj6go@LLOCuSw4gauMh8iU6hCWpbVIa6Nprmqjzi9rgpLTbmWbyFeIrMrKjilTPzfJuGLeS94zda0ROd6ZSEAbVdKi96ItVJcxf3dW8@cWNfMtzmMhXC01ebAh61sD34L5BgnKFIK1iehEgpYrQsJv2JZQFXUt9ii7usSJInHHeNOlaHZ4niZSZ5Viq2FSGKMGXKVkEIZkVYQl0xnv01TEAk6hjugbx@TomlAKlGchUeZKqRmq5QIsYwi8AZ2Jgq9KJsEGcmnSxkaUJZ0sbyQeG5das9borLe2pIRwJT2tKrOMDqPnpqogKdxJG2iqS9mDtdgS2ODX2sFLx7rkkut8SMZ9xk3S5jOwiafBYyFJHGunxJGOh867FFy2JFpCLC0ZLEUwEQMoQStlSyjRCh0IYS5Fy0B/H4FocY10CIeJzPZBiMDwu5a4WkFNG9RbCaeZLg1BrL9KOlFAtRMk55BkvhEDz0uKtEdYAJXhZLMypMe4IHraZDWRfurg2OseECs6KciNXYqg7LgMZKFWnW3MDoAPqAq8RRbxoZx28dUO7gRR2Qqixqwxz7VHHxvmVymEhnVDMpuCNyjbiO1woyUOHYRLIS1xZLHApSUjQ0u2ZpmxQi/L1T@mV/08OZUVrBBwwU0pnucPHJGaCtE@2UtDnKgkG@gZgFW2MpoRMGh0pQRV/soElQBJK1Z0DrwnLEm5UmuscbiqkiezyqgBRVSJy1B3hVF081vmpOkvYctCI7lPSBFZCycpdy3bQrkikBrrNpuXw0QlsBrUAAu/oVpinevYQq/apCXDvET9plgKHuRaZPsWAFVFqgwPYBZBg3osc1DkjQjUQmEmsxqL31KLQQC1f9bTc6QNLUP8/TWx1Aws6rZmI9xQ3PvJcHWtEyqWCRns3X6DBWKjs/Rw2OgbzLLtVjTFxuQJONbKMvPQgtq0Qodi6THKd2i@R5ntbLebngLCiwF9diUCAbq4Di9rm93trE44UVNXcpiTqKjjIaaKcWJLa7TVlMQyxhJJPcBBbPQIJZChUy6VvIsejXu4DIwohgOdWzy7O4OCEHrPqKOk5HhR0hfqKXoqRi@8wfT4htl9Z6J7zROgc/Z0YL4JsCHpkCrJwcvZCEJtURFRWatSu/AaUkRr2mxaajDetJR9/1RJ6kl08TkLfsBJfWDOkX/BpS/D9u67FvfBNkNki0cfuKIv3bcgWqtYII9CA38LrCQURSIBOyqcQ9cXHva9XdgQXV1T9wsutnbPjy4o8ivC601FHnUJtWxIe9SKtQWdY9QOLPb/MGsc6ZjW0sMPS0bSmRZh6K1rGTyGuWmkU4mC75bRf8tGeiIGXv7UlzYeU9xF9PwZxHtzK1sLRzWGXtooWYxG1vggS/ipgoQ9ltrGMJ2N8PYWZgvcgYNPcuJAHsK0Z89A3ukauL2@47Y8myaVsDYC75QYK6GnvcbZ@OH44sHoQIsNckBwMhkdpG3ahPHAN24HpR73wiB3gOaOoy3hxKb9jhmw9/roH/EaHAxT2gvvQilrAT7PjvLz2b3BGT@b3YwOes3HzEL3L/caR/DCjR@jbYf/JdN8PkteYx7@5fW0X5j1ftMmkB2SBheektDPMQn5/PI/wiElKZzeEG/c/8cCSmC3rHY20Zm9XTTQwzsBJhtwbqB2yGw/ezKZHC@N1FOP73@583f25PY2n1@cnM5H14f0yh4ejQ/Tg4Zo@OFAXBvioAIE/c/U4c3ocLE9OYGRw5jDOIVxH8YZjHMYFzAuF2GhgRYw@MLBV8CoFtscJHOQzEEyB8kcJHOQzEEyB8n8EsYVDAYDpHMOo4QB8nk1fmHy4kv3Xl4cTmevvHqUHb92ks/vn19cXj14/eGjN9586@133n3v/Q8@/OjjTz797PMvvvzq62@@/e77H3786edfrheLm18fP2EFL0VVN3K5Uq029qnzIa432@7Zb7//8edie1Ed/qVNxuGPWvwN)

Answer (score 1):

## 56. [Go](https://golang.org/)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   fmt.Println("55")
}
```

I learned this language just for this challenge. If I understood the challenge correctly, this should be valid.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8///78gMTk7MT1VITcxM49LAQjARGZuQX5RiYJSWm6JEkI0rTQvGaxQQ1OhGiwCEswt0QsoyswrycnTUDI1VdIES9T@/w8A)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZne9s2EP4c/QrVbWqpNV1TjleadO/5dA/bTUAAJCGBAIIhifnz7t2BlJyOD@C9B@AmDge6PrbWLO40M02YPp1eH5ycsaqUB0cHi8AqjeB0zTyQCxhXV/BhhZPMF9FLXGU8JqZ1j1AI55A21hCvG6vPLxuCitNu7drEV4icLkTPtG1eYQquWQiKD5OmMYg8720iYKwWtBiC7CrdFyzc5xr@yqJhoUM@VdI3ypAHG7K@tfCtWGiRoEwlWZeJySQatSIkw4ZtCdXJNHKPiqtLZDSJe8bbPkezw4vMKFPUmq1GprJWj7jOySAMyaoJK2YKPqSpShWcQpPQN47JMQ2hHCgvYqbMC2UYquUSLGMIvAWdmYKvWmXBFnJp88ZWCkEny1uFx8aVMayzphisLSkhXKtAq9ouk8foua1rSAr3ykVijVADWMstgQ1@nRu99KzPLvk@xGw8FNxmbaEAm3gaPFWKxLF2BI58PHTeQnLVkaiAWDoyKGS0CQMQoJWyJbXspImEMJeyY6B/iEB2uEY6pMdEFvsgZGT4XStcraGmLeqtpTfMCEsQ669WXlZQ7QTJOSRFaOU4FxRFOiAsgNpysllb0mN9lANti4bIwHo49mYANJW8kuTGLkVQdlxFstDo3rV2B8AHVAXe4hTNQznt4ms83AmiqpNErV1jnpuAPrYsrHIILevHZLYVb1G2ldvxRiscJkqfQ1riKFKFS0tGhpZszQrrpFmK1T/Yq4HPThUVqyRccCvkq/PjjMxNheiQ7KWlmaQVG@kZgFWxsoYRsGh0pSVV/spGnQFJa1b1HrwnrEi51muscbiqimez2uoRJVSJy1B3ldV08zvmlR0uYcdiq3jISBNZS68odx3bQrkiUAbrtliIkdEZrEY1MIXfWC@xzk3qoFdt8pJlQaF@Wy0lj2oti30LgKoiVZZHMIugRT2OeSjyVkZqocCposHid9RiEEDtnw30HGlLyxD/cE0cNQOHup3dSD8W954Zr67zUieRkcXeHTZYIC55Rw@HS6HFLLt@RSw2pkDAs06JIkAL6vIKHYqjx6jcocUeFa53/Y49BYQXA/rsSkYCdHE9XtauuN9ZvfSyoa7kMSdJU8dDTBXj5ZbWaKsVNGWtI5J7gIfY6BHKoECnfC55nwIaD3AZGFEMBzq3fHmfg4KQZj/RJEXJCVLQF@opBSrGIIPF9ISWuX1nonvNM6BzDnRgoY2wIetQOsvBy9lKQl1VE9FFp3O7CAZSRGvGbjpqMMF2lP3wQivqSXTxOYthxFl9ZN6Tf9HnL8P2HvoO98E2S2SLRx@5pi/dtyg7p1kkj2ILfwtMEEoyk4gdFc6hHwoP@94ubIiuaaj7RZ86t59PPmryK8HrTUWejIBatqQ9Gc26is4xGQ8Wh3@YNY58TGsV4IelIOnCyDj21rWKAcPctMrrTMF3x@i/ZaMCEQsvf@5Lm4Ap7hN6/hLivb1TnYOjmkIvbbWqJhNnQ1QCfqogYc@UcSnO5hO8vZXdwuw4g09ynoE8xNkwPQd5bxqYHfQdd@JsllXC2gS803KqpZkNGufTJ9OLx5MHRm5wBgQPDiYP8jZj43Sct34HlZkOwiD3AM0dJyfgxGbDjjlM7/XRP@I1OBhntBfeBaEaCT7Pj8rz@cPRmTCf304eDJqPmYPuL/YaJ/DCTZ@hbY//JbNyMc9eYx7@5fVsWJgPftMmkB2TBheekjDwmIRycfkf4ZCSHM5giLf@/2MBJbBb1Tub6MzeLhoY4L0Asw04N1A7Znbgnh8cHC@tMrOA77/Y@Tt/fncHtk7OTybXh/kdOzyaHo7/GYRRAsHw94Rwd7WQyff38HZyeLM9OYFRwljAOIXxCMYZjHMYFzAub@KNAVrB4DcevhJGfbMtQbIEyRIkS5AsQbIEyRIkS5AsL2FcwWAwQLrkMAQMkC/r6Wuvv/HwzZvDt94@Kt45KRenj84vLq8ev/vk6Xvvf/DhRx9/8ulnn3/x5Vdff/Ptd9//8ONPP//y62@///Hn9c3tX8@eV6JdvgjrzbZ/efg3)

Answer (score 0):

## 13. [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 14 bytes

```
2+2+2+2+2+2+2,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMyc8r/v/fSBsJ6vz/DwA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZpe9s2DP4c/wrPe7rYe6Iscpqra3ff933FWUpRlESbIlkettUd/3qfMwCU7HTHBwovSAIEQACi7UJj9PxOMV378ZPx9eTkjBW5mBxN5p4VCsHpmjkgFzCuruDDMiuYy4ITuMp4iEypDmFZWou0Npp4VRt1flkTlJx2K9tEvkJkVVZ2TJn6BSbjinkveT@pa43I8c5EAtqokha9F22huoz5@1zNX1jUzLfIx0K4WmqyYEOnbw18C@YbJChTCNYmohMJWq4ICb9hW0JV1LXYo@zqEhlF4o7xpkve7PA8MVJnlWKrgSmMUQOuUjAIQ7AqwpLpjPdhKmIBt1BHtI1jcHRNKDnKs5Aoc6XUDNVyASejC7wBnYmCrUomwQZiadLGRpQl3SxvJF4bl1qz1uisP21JAeFKelpVZhkdes9NVUFQuJM2EKtL2YO12BLY4NfawUrHumSS63xIh/uMm6TNZ3Am3gaPhSRxzJ0SR7oeuu9ScNmSaAm@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@jElkKFRLqW8ix4P91AMjCi6A91cPL/PQUIIvZ@oo6TgeFHSF/IpekpGL7zB8PiG2X1norrmCdA9e7ow3wTYkHRIleTgb9oIQm1REVFZq1K78BpCRGvabFpqMN60FH3/TEnqSVT4nAU/4KQ@MOfIvuDSl2HL912L@2CbIbLFqw9c0ZfqLYjWKhbIotDAC4KVhKJIJGBHhXvo@sTDvrdzG7yra@p@wcXW7uejC4rsivBHpySPuoRcNqQ9asXagu4xagcn9u@aNY50TWvp4RGTkXSmRRh661oGj25uGulUomC7ZfSW2UhPxMBrIPWljccQdxEtfw7@3tzJ1sJVjaGXNkoWo5E1PsgSHloQsFupbQzT2QirtzBbmB1m8DedZiAOYdpPz0De6Rpme33HbXk2TSphbQTWKTFWQk97jbPx4/HFo9GBFhucAcHJZHSQtmkTxsO8cTso9bgXBrkDPO442hJubNrvmMH0Xh@9G6/BwDClvfBfKGUtwObZUX4@ezAY42ezm9FBr/mYWej@5V7jCP5w41s82@FbZZrPZ8lqjMO/rJ72C7PebtoEskPQoOApCD2PQcjnl//hDilJ7vQH8cb9vy@gBHb3Wu/5kNTA1YDkELyeezqZHC@N1FOPv/hyZ9Ls6d1dPj9/mM9H14fwVDk8Gh/ee9Eie69zJBYyFQH9gRHsS@PwZnS42J6cwMhhzGGcwngI4wzGOYwLGJeLsNBACxh84eArYFSLbQ6SOUjmIJmDZA6SOUjmIJmDZH4J4woGgwHSOYdRwgD5vBq/NHn5wSuLw9mrR9nxayenD88uLq8evf74yRtvvvX2O@@@9/4HH3708Seffvb5F19@9fU33373/Q8//vTzL9eLxc2vt09ZwcuqbuRy1Wpjnzkf15tt9/y33//4c7G9qA7/0ibj8JoWfwM)

(We now have all the characters)

Comment: Could you have done `2+2+2`... to save characters?

Comment: I don't understand the next toolbox, could someone please edit it in?

Comment: @WheatWizard The current toolbox contains 4 `e`s, is there some bug in the implementation?

Comment: @Laikoni Yes there is you can count it as a single `e`.

Answer (score 0):

## 14. [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 2 bytes

I'll try to be a bit more creative next time.

```
13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/39D4/38A)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZpe9s2DP4c/wrPWxd7i7LIaa6u3X3f9xVnLUVREm2KZHnYVnf8633OAFCy0x16HgovSAIEQBCk7UJj9PxWMV378aPx9eTkjBW5mBxN5p4VCsHpmjkgF9CuruDHMiuYy4ITOMp4iEypDmFZWou0Npp4VRt1flkTlJxmK9tEvkJkVVZ2TJn6OSbjinkved@pa43I8c5EAtqokga9F22huoz5u1zNnxvUzLfIx0K4WmqyYEOrbw38C@YbJChTCNYmohMJWq4ICb9hW0JV1LXYo@zqEhlF4o7xpkve7PA8MVJnlWKrgSmMUQOuUjAIQ7AqwpLpjPdhKmIBu1BHtI1jcHRNKDnKs5Aoc6XUDNVyASujC7wBnYmCrUomwQZiadLERpQl7SxvJG4bl1qz1uisX21JAeFKehpVZhkdes9NVUFQuJM2EKtL2YO12BLY4N/awUrHumSS63xIi/uMm6TNZ7Am7gaPhSRxzJ0SW9oe2u9ScNmSaAm@tLRgKYKJ6EAJWilaQolW6EAIYylaBvp7D0SLY6RDtGYpB8pNiYYIh8HN9o6JwPC/lihRQZ4bXKsSTjNdGoKYk5V0ooATQJAMRpL5Rgx9XpL3PcKkqAwnOypDeowLoqdNVhPpWQepUPeAuqKTgszYhQ1SkctAK9Sqs43ZAbABVYG12EX9kGI7/2oH54SobAVRY9YY@9qjjQ3zq@RCw7ohwE3BG5RtxHY45RhHqYNwyaUltiwWOLRktNCSrVlmrNDLcvUP9qrnk1FZwQoBhz5tyJ3@oUekQkO0D/bSUE9Ukg30DMAqWxnNCBhcdKUEnYaVCSoBklas6BxYT1iScqXWmPdwfIfMUEYNKKJKHIZcLIyiatAyJ01/MFsWGsl9QorIWjhJsWvZFlIYgdSYy9m8HBiVwGpQA134D9USc1/HFurXJg0Z5iXqN8VS8CDXItuXBcgqUmV4gGURNKjHMgeJ34hAZRU4mdV4ICyVHQSQ@2c9PUfa0DD43x8dSwXCom5rNsINyb1nhuNsnVCxTMhgPfcbTBAbnaXLxEbfYJRttyIWi5Un4Fgry8xDWWrTCG2KpQsq36H5HmW2s92OPQWEBwNq70oEAnRwHR7WNrtbbZ1woqZK5TAmUVEVREwZ48SWxmiqKanLGEsk1QAHvtHFlECGRrmU8i56XNzDYWBE0R2o5uLZXQ4SQuh9Rx0lBceLkv6QT9FTMnrhDYbHN8zuKxOda54A7bOnDfNNgAlJh1RJDm7TRhBqi4qIylqVyoXXECIa02bTUoHxpqXo@6dKUk2ig89Z8ANO6gNzjuwLLv0ZlnzftTgPphkiW9z6wBX96bwF0VrFAlkUGnhBsJJQFIkErKiwD12feFj3dm6Dd3VN1S@42Np9f3RBkV0RbnRK8qhLyGVD2qNWrC1oH6N2sGL/rlljS9u0lh4eMRlJZ1qEobauZfDo5qaRTiUKtltGb5mN9EQMvAZSXdp4DHEX0fJn4O/NrWwtbNUYammjZDEaWeODLOGhBQF7LLWNYTob4ektzBZ6hx68plMPxCFM@@4ZyDtdQ2@v77gtz6ZJJYyNwDolxkroaa9xNn44vngwOtBigz0gOJmMDtI0bcJ46DduB6Ue98Igd4DLHUdbwo5N@xkz6N7ro3fjNRgYpjQX7oVS1gJsnh3l57N7gzF@NrsZHfSaj5mF6l/uNY7ghhs/xrUdvlWm@XyWrMY4/MvqaT8w6@2mSSA7BA0OPAWh5zEI@fzyP9whJcmdfiHeuP/3BZTA7F7rHR@SGtgakByC13NPJpPjpZF66vGKL3cmzZ7c3ubz8/un89H1ITxVDo/Gh3detMjeqRyJhUxFQDcwgv3ROLwZHS62JyfQcmhzaKfQ7kM7g3YO7QLa5SIsNNACGl84@Ato1WKbg2QOkjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZX0K7gsaggXTOoZXQQD6vxi9MXnzp3suLw@nslVePsuPXTub3z84vLq8evP7w0RtvvvX2O@@@9/4HH3708Seffvb5F19@9fU33373/Q8//vTzL9eLxc2vj5@wgpcCvqpu5HKlWm3sU@dDXG@23bPffv/jz8X2ojr8S5uMw7ta/A0)

Comment: Next character set: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWWWWWWWWWWWWWXYZ` What? 13 `W`s?

Comment: Must be a bug in the python script

Answer (score 0):

## 21. [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d)

```
"20"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyktKslJTfn/X8nIQOn/fwA)

[Next Toolbox:](https://tio.run/##dVbpl9s0EP/c/BVhoWwCq1Kn3au03I8bHvAe52ZpZVm2lciSqiOJy/Ff83mZGdnJluODPL@RNKdGI7s@ttYsbjQ3TZg@mV4d3T/lZSGPTo4WgZcawYMN90DOYVxewoczJ7ln0Utc5SImrnWPsKqcQ9pYQ7xurD67aAgqQbu1a5NYI3KaVT3XtnmJYULzEJQYJk1jEHnR20TAWF3RYgiyK3XPeLjNNeKlRcNDh3wqpW@UIQ@2ZH1n4Vvy0CJBmVLyLhOTSTRqTUiGLd8RqpNp5AGxywtkNIl7Lto@R7PHi8wow2rN1yNTWqtHXOdkEIZk1YQVN0wMaSpTCafQJPRNYHJMQygHKljMlPtKGY5qhQTLGIJoQWem4KtWWbCFXNq8sZVVRScrWoXHJpQxvLOGDdZWlBChVaBVbVfJY/TC1jUkRXjlIrGmUgPYyB2BLX6dG730vM8u@T7EbDwwYbO2wMAmnoZIpSJxrJ0KRz4eOu9KCtWRaAWxdGSwktEmDKACrZQtqWUnTSSEuZQdB/1DBLLDNdIhPSaSHYKQkeN3o3C1hpq2qLeW3nBTWYJYf7XysoRqJ0jOIWGhleNcUBTpgLAAaivIZm1Jj/VRDrRlDZGB9XDszQBoKnklyY19iqDshIpkodG9a@0egA@oCrzFKZqHctrH13i4E0RVJ4lau8E8NwF9bHlY5xBa3o/JbEvRomwrd@ONVjhMlD6HtMLBUolLK06GVnzDmXXSrKr1P9jLgc9OsZKXEi64reTL8@OMzE2F6JDslaWZpBUf6SmANVtbwwlYNLrWkip/baPOgKQ1L3sP3hNWpFzrDdY4XFUlsllt9YgSqsRlqLvSarr5HffKDpew47FVImSkiWykV5S7ju@gXBEog3XLFtXI6AzWoxqYwm@sV1jnJnXQq7Z5yfKgUL8tV1JEtZHs0AKgqkiVFRHMImhRj@MeiryVkVoocIo1WPyOWgwCqP3TgZ4hbWkZ4h@uiaNm4FC3s1vpx@I@MOPVdV7qVGVksXeHLRaIS97Rw@FSaDHLrl8Ti40pEPC8UxUL0IK6vEKH4ugxKvZocUDM9a7fsw8A4cWAPruWkQBdXI@XtWO3O6uXXjbUlTzmJGnqeIipYrzc0RpttRVNWeuI5B7gITZ6hDJg6JTPJe9TQOMBLgMniuFA55YvbnNQENIcJpqkKDlBVvSFekqBijHIYDE9oeXu0JnoXosM6JwDHVhoI2zIOpTOcvBytpJQV9ZENOt0bhfBQIpozdhtRw0m2I6yH55rRT2JLr7gMYw4q4/ce/Iv@vzl2N5D3@E@2GaJ7PDoo9D0pfsWZec0j@RRbOFvgVeEkswkYkeFc@iHwsO@tw8bomsa6n7Rp84d5pOPmvxK8HpTkSdTQS1b0p6M5l1J55iMB4vDP8wGRz6mjQrww8JImhkZx966UTFgmNtWeZ0p@O44/bdsVSBi4eXPfWkbMMV9Qs9fQLzXN6pzcFRT6KWtVuVk4myIqoKfKkjYU2VcirP5BG9vaXcwO87gk5xnIA9xNkzPQd6bBmYHffe66nSWVcLaBLzTcqqlmQ0a59PH0/NHkztGbnEGBI@OJnfyNmPjdJy3fg@VmQ7CIHcHzd1LroITmw075jB90Ef/iFfgYJzRXngXKtVI8Hl@UpzN747OhPn8enJn0HyPO@j@1UHjBF646VO07fG/ZFYs5tlrzMO/vJ4NC/PBb9oEsmPS4MJTEgYek1AsLv4jHFKSwxkMidb/fyygBHarem8TnTnYRQMDvBVgtgHnBmrHzA7cs6OjeyurzCzg@1/t/Z0/u7kpFmdnxWJydQz/LMcn0@Nbv7bI3moryI5vFeLDE49c/gs6vp4cL3f378MoYCxgPIDxEMYpjDMY5zAulnFpgJYwxNLDV8Kol7sCJAuQLECyAMkCJAuQLECyAMniAsYlDA4DpAsBo4IB8kU9feXV1@6@vjyezd9484S9VTx4eHp2fnH56O3HT9559733P/jwo48/@fSzz7/48quvv/n2u@9/@PGnn3@5Wi6vf336rKzqplWrte6Mdc993Gx3/Yvffv/jz@XuvD7@y1gm4Lda/g0)

```
['elf', 'assembly-as', 'scheme-chez', 'logicode', 'golfscript', 'dstack', 'mariolang']
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f'
```

Answer (score 0):

## 25. [Arcyóu](https://github.com/Nazek42/arcyou)

```
24
```

Boring, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKrswv/f/fyOT/fwA)

[Next Toolbox:](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4p1ytNuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5bfoA3ncAbuJwoO1CY/T8VjFd@/HD8fXk5IwVuZgcTeaeFQrB6Zo5IBcwrq7gwzIrmMuCE7jKeIhMqQ5hWVqLtDaaeFUbdX5ZE5ScdivbRL5CZFVWdkyZ@hkm44p5L3k/qWuNyPHORALaqJIWvRdtobqM@btczZ9Z1My3yMdCuFpq8mBD1rcGvgXzDRKUKQRrE9GJBC1XhITfsC2hKupa7FF2dYmMInHHeNOlaHZ4nhips0qx1cAUxqgBVykZhCFZFWHJdMb7NBWxgFOoI/rGMTm6JpQC5VlIlLlSaoZquQDLGAJvQGei4KuSSbCBXJq0sRFlSSfLG4nHxqXWrDU6660tKSFcSU@ryiyjw@i5qSpICnfSBmJ1KXuwFlsCG/xaO3jpWJdccp0PybjPuEnafAY28TR4LCSJY@2UONLx0HmXgsuWREuIpSWDpQgmYgAlaKVsCSVaoQMhzKVoGejvIxAtrpEO4TCR2T4IERh@1xJXK6hpg3or4TTTpSGI9VdJJwqodoLkHJLMN2KY85Ii7REWQGU42awM6TEuiJ42WU2kZx0ce90DmopOCnJjlyIoOy4DWahVZxuzA@ADqgJvcYrmoZx28dUO7gRR2Qqixqwxz7VHHxvmVymEhnVDMpuCNyjbiO1woyUOHYRLIS1xZLHApSUjQ0u2ZpmxQi/L1b/Yq55PTmUFKwRccFOKZ@eHGZGaCtE@2UtDM1FJNtAzAKtsZTQjYNDoSgmq/JUJKgGSVqzoHHhPWJJypdZY43BVJU9mlVEDiqgSl6HuCqPo5rfMSdNfwpaFRnKfkCKyFk5S7lq2hXJFIDXWbTYvB0YlsBrUwBR@Q7XEOtexhV61SUuGeYn6TbEUPMi1yPYtAKqKVBkewCyCBvVY5qDIGxGohQInsxqL31KLQQC1f9bTc6QNLUP8/TWx1Aws6rZmI9xQ3HtmuLrWCRXLhAz2br/BArHRWXo4bPQNZtl2K2KxMXkCjrWyzDy0oDat0KFYeozyHZrvUWY72@3YU0B4MaDPrkQgQBfX4WVts7ud1QknaupKDnMSFXU8xFQxTmxpjbaakqaMsURSD3AQGz1CCWTolEsl76JH4x4uAyOK4UDnFk/vclAQQu8n6igpOV6U9IV6ip6K0QtvMD2@YXbfmehe8wTonD0dmG8CbEg6pEpy8HI2glBbVERU1qrULryGFNGaNpuWGow3LWXfP1GSehJdfM6CH3BSH5hz5F9w6cuwvfuuxX2wzRDZ4tEHruhL9y2I1ioWyKPQwN8CKwlFkUjAjgrn0PWFh31vFzZEV9fU/YKLrd3PRxcU@RXh9aYij7qEWjakPWrF2oLOMWoHFvt/mDWOdExr6eGHJSPpTIsw9Na1DB7D3DTSqUTBd8vov2UjPREDL3/qSxuPKe4iev4U4r25la2FoxpDL22ULEYja3yQJfxUQcIeSW1jmM5GeHsLs4XZYQaf5DQDeQjTfnoG8k7XMNvrO27Ls2lSCWsj8E6JsRJ62mucjR@ML@6PDrTY4AwITiajg7RNmzAe5o3bQanHvTDIHaC542hLOLFpv2MG03t99I94DQ6GKe2Fd6GUtQCfZ0f5@eze4IyfzW5GB73mY2ah@5d7jSN44caP0LbD/5JpPp8lrzEP//F62i/Mer9pE8gOSYMLT0noeUxCPr98TjikJIXTG@KN@/9YQAnsltXOJjqzt4sGengnwGQDzg3UDpntuceTyfHSSD31@P6XO39nj29v8/n5@eV8dH0I/yyHR@PDO7@2yA6PE@L9m47ccysZF@42zcOb0eFie3ICI4cxh3EK43UYZzDOYVzAuFyEhQZawOALB18Bo1psc5DMQTIHyRwkc5DMQTIHyRwk80sYVzAYDJDOOYwSBsjn1fiFyYsv3Xt5cTidvfLqUXb82kl@enZ@cXl1/40HD9986@133n3v/Q8@/OjjTz797PMvvvzq62@@/e77H3786edffr1eLG5@e/SYFbwUVd3I5Uq12tgnzoe43my7p7//8edfi@1Fdfi3NhmHP27xDw)

```
['elf', 'assembly-as', 'logicode', 'golfscript', 'visual-basic-net-mono', 'python2-pypy', 'silos']
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f'
```

Answer (score 0):

## 26. [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 2 bytes

```
25
```

GolfScript makes this way too easy.

It pushes `25` to the stack, then when the program ends, it prints the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/38j0/38A)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4pxyttuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5bfoA3ncAbuJwoO1CY/T8VjFd@/HD8fXk5IwVuZgcTeaeFQrB6Zo5IBcwrq7gwzIrmMuCE7jKeIhMqQ5hWVqLtDaaeFUbdX5ZE5ScdivbRL5CZFVWdkyZ@hkm44p5L3k/qWuNyPHORALaqJIWvRdtobqM@btczZ9Z1My3yMdCuFpq8mBD1rcGvgXzDRKUKQRrE9GJBC1XhITfsC2hKupa7FF2dYmMInHHeNOlaHZ4nhips0qx1cAUxqgBVykZhCFZFWHJdMb7NBWxgFOoI/rGMTm6JpQC5VlIlLlSaoZquQDLGAJvQGei4KuSSbCBXJq0sRFlSSfLG4nHxqXWrDU6660tKSFcSU@ryiyjw@i5qSpICnfSBmJ1KXuwFlsCG/xaO3jpWJdccp0PybjPuEnafAY28TR4LCSJY@2UONLx0HmXgsuWREuIpSWDpQgmYgAlaKVsCSVaoQMhzKVoGejvIxAtrpEO4TCR2T4IERh@1xJXK6hpg3or4TTTpSGI9VdJJwqodoLkHJLMN2KY85Ii7REWQGU42awM6TEuiJ42WU2kZx0ce90DmopOCnJjlyIoOy4DWahVZxuzA@ADqgJvcYrmoZx28dUO7gRR2Qqixqwxz7VHHxvmVymEhnVDMpuCNyjbiO1woyUOHYRLIS1xZLHApSUjQ0u2ZpmxQi/L1b/Yq55PTmUFKwRccFOKZ@eHGZGaCtE@2UtDM1FJNtAzAKtsZTQjYNDoSgmq/JUJKgGSVqzoHHhPWJJypdZY43BVJU9mlVEDiqgSl6HuCqPo5rfMSdNfwpaFRnKfkCKyFk5S7lq2hXJFIDXWbTYvB0YlsBrUwBR@Q7XEOtexhV61SUuGeYn6TbEUPMi1yPYtAKqKVBkewCyCBvVY5qDIGxGohQInsxqL31KLQQC1f9bTc6QNLUP8/TWx1Aws6rZmI9xQ3HtmuLrWCRXLhAz2br/BArHRWXo4bPQNZtl2K2KxMXkCjrWyzDy0oDat0KFYeozyHZrvUWY72@3YU0B4MaDPrkQgQBfX4WVts7ud1QknaupKDnMSFXU8xFQxTmxpjbaakqaMsURSD3AQGz1CCWTolEsl76JH4x4uAyOK4UDnFk/vclAQQu8n6igpOV6U9IV6ip6K0QtvMD2@YXbfmehe8wTonD0dmG8CbEg6pEpy8HI2glBbVERU1qrULryGFNGaNpuWGow3LWXfP1GSehJdfM6CH3BSH5hz5F9w6cuwvfuuxX2wzRDZ4tEHruhL9y2I1ioWyKPQwN8CKwlFkUjAjgrn0PWFh31vFzZEV9fU/YKLrd3PRxcU@RXh9aYij7qEWjakPWrF2oLOMWoHFvt/mDWOdExr6eGHJSPpTIsw9Na1DB7D3DTSqUTBd8vov2UjPREDL3/qSxuPKe4iev4U4r25la2FoxpDL22ULEYja3yQJfxUQcIeSW1jmM5GeHsLs4XZYQaf5DQDeQjTfnoG8k7XMNvrO27Ls2lSCWsj8E6JsRJ62mucjd8YXzwYHWixwRkQnExGB2mbNmE8zBu3g1KPe2GQO0Bzx9GWcGLTfscMpvf66B/xGhwMU9oL70IpawE@z47y89m9wRk/m92MDnrNx8xC9y/3Gkfwwo0foW2H/yXTfD5LXmMe/uP1tF@Y9X7TJpAdkgYXnpLQ85iEfH75nHBISQqnN8Qb9/@xgBLYLaudTXRmbxcN9PBOgMkGnBuoHTLbc48nk@OlkXrq8f0vd/7OHt/e5vPz86t8dH0I/yyHR@PDO7@2yA6PE@Ln1i4u3G2TyFNPOLwZHS62JycwchhzGKcw7sM4g3EO4wLG5SIsNNACBl84@AoY1WKbg2QOkjlI5iCZg2QOkjlI5iCZX8K4gsFggHTOYZQwQD6vxi9MXnzp3suLw@nslVePsuPXTvLT@@cXl1cPXn/j4Ztvvf3Ou@@9/8GHH338yaefff7Fl199/c23333/w48//fzLr9eLxc1vjx6zgpeiqhu5XKlWG/vE@RDXm2339Pc//vxrsb2oDv/WJuPwsy3@AQ)

**Available Languages**

- elf
- assembly-as
- logicode
- visual-basic-net-mono
- python2-pypy
- silos
- haskell

Answer (score 0):

## 32. [rk](https://github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang), 27 bytes

```
rk:start print: "31" rk:end
```

Chars used: `"13:adeiknprst`

The code is pretty self explanatory, but what surprised me is that rk was created by a [13 year old](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124790/70606).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8r@/78o26q4JLGoRKGgKDOvxEpBydhQSQEomJqX8v8/AA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXg9s2DH4@/wr32vTs9niNnNxqm@6994qvCUVREm2KZDhsKx3/us8pAEp20vFA4QNJTIKgXB9baxZPNDdNmN6b3j@@fc7LQh6fHi8CLzWCOxvugVzCuL6GD2dOcs@il7jKRUxc6x5hVTmHtLGGeN1YfXHVEFSCdmvXJrFG5DSreq5t8wzDhOYhKDFMmsYg8qK3iYCxuqLFEGRX6p7x8DTXiGcWDQ8d8qmUvlGGPNiS9Z2Fb8lDiwRlSsm7TEwm0ag1IRm2fEeoTqaRB8Sur5DRJO65aPsczR4vMqMMqzVfj0xprR5xnZNBGJJVE1bcMDGkqUwlnEKT0DeByTENoRyoYDFT7itlOKoVEixjCKIFnZmCr1plwRZyafPGVlYVnaxoFR6bUMbwzho2WFtRQoRWgVa1XSWP0Qtb15AU4ZWLxJpKDWAjdwS2@HVu9NLzPrvk@xCz8cCEzdoCA5t4GiKVisSxdioc@XjovCspVEeiFcTSkcFKRpswgAq0Uraklp00kRDmUnYc9A8RyA7XSIf0mEh2CEJGjt@NwtUaatqi3lp6w01lCWL91crLEqqdIDmHhIVWjnNBUaQDwgKorSCbtSU91kc50JY1RAbWw7E3A6Cp5JUkN/YpgrITKpKFRveutXsAPqAq8BanaB7KaR9f4@FOEFWdJGrtBvPcBPSx5WGdQ2h5PyazLUWLsq3cjTda4TBR@hzSCgdLJS6tOBla8Q1n1kmzqtb/YK8HPjvFSl5KuOC2ks/OjzMyNxWiQ7JXlmaSVnyk5wDWbG0NJ2DR6FpLqvy1jToDkta87D14T1iRcq03WONwVZXIZrXVI0qoEpeh7kqr6eZ33Cs7XMKOx1aJkJEmspFeUe46voNyRaAM1i1bVCOjM1iPamAKv7FeYZ2b1EGv2uYly4NC/bZcSRHVRrJDC4CqIlVWRDCLoEU9jnso8lZGaqHAKdZg8TtqMQig9s8HeoG0pWWIf7gmjpqBQ93ObqUfi/vAjFfXealTlZHF3h22WCAueUcPh0uhxSy7fk0sNqZAwPNOVSxAC@ryCh2Ko8eo2KPFATHXu37P3gGEFwP67FpGAnRxPV7Wjj3dWb30sqGu5DEnSVPHQ0wV4@WO1mirrWjKWkck9wAPsdEjlAFDp3wueZ8CGg9wGThRDAc6t3z8NAcFIc1hokmKkhNkRV@opxSoGIMMFtMTWu4OnYnutciAzjnQgYU2woasQ@ksBy9nKwl1ZU1Es07ndhEMpIjWjN121GCC7Sj74ZFW1JPo4gsew4iz@si9J/@iz1@O7T30He6DbZbIDo8@Ck1fum9Rdk7zSB7FFv4WeEUoyUwidlQ4h34oPOx7@7Ahuqah7hd96txhPvmoya8ErzcVeTIV1LIl7clo3pV0jsl4sDj8w2xw5GPaqAA/LIykmZFx7K0bFQOGuW2V15mC747Tf8tWBSIWXv7cl7YBU9wn9PwxxHvzRHUOjmoKvbTVqpxMnA1RVfBTBQl7oIxLcTaf4O0t7Q5mxxl8kvMM5CHOhuk5yHvTwOyg76yrzmdZJaxNwDstp1qa2aBxPn19evnq5MjILc6A4PHx5ChvMzZOx3nr91CZ6SAMckdo7iy5Ck5sNuyYw/RBH/0j3gcH44z2wrtQqUaCz/PT4mJ@a3QmzOc3k6NB8xl30P2rg8YJvHDTB2jb43/JrFjMs9eYh395PRsW5oPftAlkx6TBhackDDwmoVhc/Uc4pCSHMxgSrf//WEAJ7Fb13iY6c7CLBgb4VIDZBpwbqB0zO3APj4/PVlaZWcD3v9r7O3/45EmxuLi8LCb3T@Cf5eR0ejK@RojpbiOgFxjB/ulAJv@pnNxMTpa727dhFDAWMO7AuAvjHMYFjEsYV8u4NEBLGGLp4Sth1MtdAZIFSBYgWYBkAZIFSBYgWYBkcQXjGgaHAdKFgFHBAPmifu75F269uDyZzV96@ZSdvXJ7cff84vLq@rXX773x5ltvv/Pue@9/8OFHH3/y6Weff/HlV19/8@133//w408//3J/ubz59cHDUtRNu9KdfZQ2213/@Lff//hzubusT/4ylgn4j5Z/Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## 36. [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 10 bytes

```
&2+1$h&5$h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fzUjbUCVDzVQl4/9/AA)

God I hope I understood this challenge correctly.

Chars used: `$&+125h`

### Explanation

```
&2+1$h&5$h
&2          Set current cell to 2
  +1        Add 1 to current cell
    $h      Print as hexadecimal (i was taken so couldn't print as decimal
              thankfully 0-10 are the same in hex as in decimal)
      &5    Set current cell to 5
        $h  Print as hexadecimal
```

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZZc9s2EH6OfoXqTsdSx3BNxWea9J7e993abgKCIAkJBBAckph2@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@yUWdA0pqXvQfvCStSrvUaaxyuqhLZrLZ6RAlV4jLUXWk13fyOe2WHS9jx2CoRMtJE1tIryl3Ht1CuCJTBumWLapzoDFajGmDhN9ZLrHOTOuhVm7xkeVCo35ZLKaJaS7ZvAVBVpMqKCGYRtKjHcQ9F3spILRRmijVY/I5aDAKo/bOBniNtaRniH66Jo2bgULezG@nH4t5PxqvrvNSpyshi7w4bLBCXvKOHw6XQYpZdv6IpNqZAwPNOVSxAC@ryCh2Ko8eo2KHFHjHXu343fQgILwb02ZWMBOjierysHbvfWb30sqGu5DEnSVPHQ0wV4@WW1mirrYhlrSOSe4CH2OgRyoChUz6XvE8BjQe4DJwohgOdW764P4OCkGbPaJKi5ARZ0RfqKQUqxiCDxfSElrt9Z6J7LTKgcw50YKGNsCHrUDrLwcvZSkJdWRPRrNO5XQQDKaI1YzcdNZhgO8p@eK4V9SS6@ILHMOKsPnLvyb/o85djew99h/tgmyWyxaOPQtOX7luUndM8kkexhb8FXhFKMpOIHRXOoR8KD/veLmyIrmmo@0WfOrfnJx81@ZXg9aYiT6aCWrakPRnNu5LOMRkPFod/mDWOfExrFeCHhZE0MzKOvXWtYsAwN63yOlPw3XH6b9moQMTCy5/70iZgivuEnr@AeG/vVOfgqKbQS1utysnE2RBVBT9VkLCnyrgUZ/MJ3t7SboE7cvBJzhzIQ5wN7DnIe9MAd9B33FVns6wS1ibgnZZTLc1s0DifPp5ePJo8MHKDHBA8OJg8yNuMjdORb/0OKjMdhEHuAZo7Tq6CE5sNO@bA3uujf8RrcDDOaC@8C5VqJPg8PyrO56@NzoT5/HbyYNB8zB10/2qvcQIv3PQp2vb4XzIrFvPsNebhX17PhoX54DdtAtkxaXDhKQnDHJNQLC7/IxxSksMZDInW/38soAR2q3pnE53Z20UDA7wXYLYB5wZqx8wOs2cHB8dLq8ws4Ptf7fydP7u7Kxbnl6enk@vD8Rk6PJoe0qVGQE8vgvxXgoiehcPbyeHN9uQUxhmMcxgXMC5v4o0BWsIQMCSM@mZbnMAoYCxgPIQBcgXIFSBXgFxxCYPDALkC5IoKBsgW9SuvvnZzOH/9iL1xcnp@cXn16M3HT956@51333v/gw8/@viTTz/7/Isvv/r6m2@/@/6HH3/6@Zdfr29ubn97@oyXQi1XurPuuY9pvdn2L37/48/Dv4xlAv6O5d8)

Looks like Go's on the menu now, hope to see something awesome from totallyhuman

Comment: now that I think about it perhaps I should've used up `7` and `*` instead of `1`, `2` and `+`.

Comment: @totallyhuman Go is still there.

Comment: Ah, whoops. I was looking at the wrong section in the toolbox. ^^ And it seems I have every character I can possibly have...

Answer (score 0):

## 37. [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 36 bytes

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/9@OCPD/PwA)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXk9s2EH4@/QpFieekzMExZV9z7EnvvZe7iw2CIAkJBGAUSXQy@dd5dnYXpHROeVjuh7IViwVdH1trli80N02YPp5eze6d8rKQs5PZMvBSI7i/4R7YOdDlJXw4c5J7Fr3EVS5i4lr3CKvKOeSNNTTWjdVnFw1BJWi3dm0Sa0ROs6rn2jYvDZjQPAQlhknTGERe9DYRMFZXtBiC7ErdMx5ujxrx0qLhocNxKqVvlCEPtmR9Z@Fb8tAiQ5lS8i4zk1k0ak1Ihi3fEaqTaeQBscsLHGgS91y0fY5mj5d5oAyrNV@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@A9YUXKtd5gjcNVVSKb1VaPKKFKXIa6K62mm99xr@xwCTseWyVCRprYRnpFuev4DsoVgTJYt2xZjQOdwXpUA1P4jfUK69ykDnrVNi9ZHhTqt@VKiqg2kh1aAFQVqbIiglkELepx3EORtzJSC4WRYg0Wv6MWgwBq/3TgZ8hbWob4h2viqBk41O3sVvqxuA@D8eo6L3WqMrLYu8MWC8Ql7@jhcCm0mGXXr2mIjSkQ8LxTFQvQgrq8Qofi6DEq9mh5QMz1rt8P7wPCiwF9di0jAbq4Hi9rx253Vi@9bKgrecxJ0tTxEFPFeLmjNdpqK5qy1hHLPcBDbPQIZcDQKZ9L3qeAxgNcBk4cw4HOLZ/fHkFBSHOYaJKi5ARZ0RfqKQUqxiCDxfSElrtDZ6J7LTKgcw50YKGNsCHrUDrLwcvZSkJdWRPTrNO5XQQDKaI1Y7cdNZhgO8p@eKYV9SS6@ILHMOKsPnLvyb/o85djew99h/tgmyW2w6OPQtOX7luUndM8kkexhb8FXhFKMrOIHRXOoR8KD/vePmyIrmmo@0WfOneYTz5q8ivB601FnkwFtWxJezKadyWdYzIeLA7/MBukfEwbFeCHhZE0MzKOvXWjYsAwt63yOnPw3XH6b9mqQMzCy5/70jZgivuEnj@HeG9eqM7BUU2hl7ZalZOJsyGqCn6qIGFPlHEpzhcTvL2l3cHsOINPcp6BPMT5ML0AeW8amB303e2q03lWCWsT8E7LqZZmPmhcTB9Nzx9Ojozc4gwIzmaTo7zN2Dgd563fQ2WmgzDIHaG5u8lVcGLzYccCpg/66B/xChyMc9oL70KlGgk@L06Ks8Wd0ZmwWNxMjgbNd7mD7l8dNE7ghZs@Qdse/0vmxXKRvcY8/Mvr@bCwGPymTSA7Jg0uPCVhGGMSiuXFf4RDSnI4gyHR@v@PBZTAblXvbaIzB7toYIC3Asw24NxA7ZjZYfR0Nru7ssrMA77/1d7fxdMXL4rl2cXpxeTqeHyGjk@mx3SpEdDTiyD/lSBqLH6hAI9vJrPr3b0C6D7QA6BToDOgc6CL63htgJdAAkgC1de74h4QyBRLIJArQK4AuQLkCpArLoAugTgQyBYgW1RAIF/Ur7z62p3j@eL1E/bGveWDs/OLy4dvPnr81tvvvPve@x98@NHHn3z62edffPnV1998@933P/z408@//Hp1fX3z25OnvBR106rVWnfGumc@xLTZ7vrnv//x5@wvY5mAn2b5Nw)

Answer (score 0):

## 40. [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 7 bytes

```
12+:9O;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v/f0EjbytLf@v9/AA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXk9s2EH4@/QrlEs9JGfNylH0tY096L5PerIsNAiAJCQRgFEl0yr/O82V3QUrnlIflfihbsVjQ9bG1ZnGrmWnC9PH0yfHZOatKeXz/eBFYpRE82DAP7BLo@ho@rHCS@SJ6iauMx8S07hEK4Rzyxhoa68bqi6uGoOK0W7s28TUipwvRM22blwYF1ywExYdJ0xhEnvc2ETBWC1oMQXaV7gsW7o4a/tKiYaHDcaqkb5QhD7ZkfWfhW7HQIkOZSrIuM5NZNGpNSIYt2xGqk2nkARXXVzjQJO4Zb/sczR4v8kCZotZsPQ4qa/WI65wMwpCsmrBipuBDmqpUwSk0CX3jmBzTEMqB8iJmzrxQhqFaLsEyhsBb0Jk5@KpVFmwhlzZvbKUQdLK8VXhsXBnDOmuKwdqKEsK1CrSq7Sp5jJ7buoakcK9cpKERagAbuSOwxa9zo5ee9dkl34eYjYeC26wtFGATT4OnSpE41o5AysdD5y0kVx2JCoilI4NCRpswAAFaKVtSy06aSAhzKTsG@ocIZIdrpEN6TGRxCEJGht@NwtUaatqi3lp6w4ywBLH@auVlBdVOkJxDVoRWjnNBUaQDwgKoLSebtSU91kc58LZoiA1DD8feDICmkleS3NinCMqOq0gWGt271u4B@ICqwFuconkop318jYc7QVx1kri1G8xzE9DHloV1DqFl/ZjMtuItyrZyN95ohWSi9DmkFVKRKlxaMTK0YhtWWCfNSqz/MbwextmpomKVhAtuhXx5fpyRuakQH5K9sjSTtGIjPwewLtbWMAIWja61pMpf26gzIGnNqt6D94QVKdd6gzUOV1XxbFZbPaKEKnEZ6q6ymm5@x7yywyXsWGwVDxlpYhvpFeWuYzsoVwTKYN0WCzEOdAbrUQ1M4TfWK6xzkzroVdu8ZFlQqN9WK8mj2sji0AKgqkiV5RHMImhRj2MeiryVkVoojFTRYPE7ajEIoPbPB36BvKVliH@4Jo6agUPdzm6lH4v7MBivrvNSJ5GRxd4dtlggLnlHD4dLocUsu35NQ2xMgYBnnRJFgBbU5RU6FEePUblHiwMqXO/6/fABILwY0GfXMhKgi@vxsnbF3c7qpZcNdSWPOUmaOh5iqhgvd7RGW62gKWsdsdwDPMRGj1AGBTrlc8n7FNB4gMvAiGM40Lnli7sjKAhpDhNNUpScIAV9oZ5SoGIMMlhMT2iZO3Qmutc8AzrnQAcW2ggbsg6lsxy8nK0k1FU1MV10OreLYCBFtGbstqMGE2xH2Q/PtaKeRBefsxhGnNVH5j35F33@Mmzvoe9wH2yzxHZ49JFr@tJ9i7JzmkXyKLbwt8AEoSQzi9hR4Rz6ofCw7@3Dhuiahrpf9Klzh/nkoya/ErzeVOTJCKhlS9qT0ayr6ByT8WBx@IfZIOVj2qgAPywFSRdGxrG3blQMGOa2VV5nDr47Rv8tWxWIWXj5c1/aBkxxn9DzFxDvza3qHBzVFHppq1U1mTgbohLwUwUJe6qMS3E2n@DtrewOZscZfJLzDOQhzobpOch708DsoO@0E@ezrBLWJuCdllMtzWzQOJ8@ml6@OTkycoszIHh8PDnK24yN03He@j1UZjoIg9wRmjtNTsCJzYYdc5g@6KN/xCfgYJzRXngXhGok@Dy/X17M743OhPn8ZnI0aD5lDrq/OGicwAs3fYq2Pf6XzMrFPHuNefiX17NhYT74TZtAdkwaXHhKwjDGJJSLq/8Ih5TkcAZDvPX/Hwsogd2q3ttEZw520cAA7wSYbcC5gdoxs8Po2fHx6coqMwv4/ou9v/Nnt7fl4uLq8nLy5GR8hk7uT0/oUiOgpxdB/itBJPCTy//kZnKy3J2dAZVAD4AeAp0DXQBdAl0t49IAr4D40sNXAtXLXQlSJUiVCyCQLEGyBMkSJEuQLK@AroEYEEiXHEgAgXxZT185fvW1e8uT2fz1@8XpG2cPzy8urx49fuvtd9597/0PPvzo408@/ezzL7786utvvv3u@x9@/OnnX54slze/Pn3GKi7qpl2tdWfd8xA3213/4rff//hzubusT/4ytuDw@yz/Bg)

Answer (score 0):

## 41. [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 19 bytes

```
-[>+<-----]>+.----.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMS8nP1U0qSszMSytNzv7/XzfaTttGFwRi7bT1QLTe//8A)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbXlts2EH1efYWixGelnOXGlL3NiU96771Yjg0CIAkJBGAUSXTKX@fZmRmQkp3yMJyLMhWDAV0fW2uWzzQzTZjenz6Y3b5gVSlnZ7NlYJVGcGfLPLAroJsb@LDCSeaL6CWuMh4T07pHKIRzyBtraKwbqy@vG4KK027t2sQ3iJwuRM@0bV4YFFyzEBQfJk1jEHne20TAWC1oMQTZVbovWHh@1PAXFg0LHY5TJX2jDHmwI@t7C9@KhRYZylSSdZmZzKJRG0Iy7NieUJ1MI4@ouLnGgSZxz3jb52gOeJkHyhS1ZptxUFmrR1znZBCGZNWEFTMFH9JUpQpOoUnoG8fkmIZQDpQXMXPmhTIM1XIJljEE3oLOzMFXrbJgC7m0eWMrhaCT5a3CY@PKGNZZUwzW1pQQrlWgVW3XyWP03NY1JIV75SINjVAD2Mo9gR1@nRu99KzPLvk@xGw8FNxmbaEAm3gaPFWKxLF2BFI@HjpvIbnqSFRALB0ZFDLahAEI0ErZklp20kRCmEvZMdA/RCA7XCMd0mMii2MQMjL8bhWu1lDTFvXW0htmhCWI9VcrLyuodoLkHLIitHKcC4oiHRAWQG052awt6bE@yoG3RUNsGHo49mYANJW8kuTGIUVQdlxFstDo3rX2AMAHVAXe4hTNQzkd4ms83AniqpPErd1inpuAPrYsbHIILevHZLYVb1G2lfvxRiskE6XPIa2RilTh0pqRoTXbssI6adZi84/hzTDOThUVqyRccCvki/PjjMxNhfiQ7LWlmaQVG/kFgE2xsYYRsGh0oyVV/sZGnQFJa1b1HrwnrEi51luscbiqimez2uoRJVSJy1B3ldV08zvmlR0uYcdiq3jISBPbSq8odx3bQ7kiUAbrtliKcaAz2IxqYAq/sV5jnZvUQa/a5SXLgkL9tlpLHtVWFscWAFVFqiyPYBZBi3oc81DkrYzUQmGkigaL31GLQQC1fzHwS@QtLUP8wzVx1Awc6nZ2J/1Y3MfBeHWdlzqJjCz27rDDAnHJO3o4XAotZtn1GxpiYwoEPOuUKAK0oC6v0KE4eozKA1oeUeF61x@GdwDhxYA@u5GRAF1cj5e1K57vrF562VBX8piTpKnjIaaK8XJPa7TVCpqy1hHLPcBDbPQIZVCgUz6XvE8BjQe4DIw4hgOdWz59fgQFIc1xokmKkhOkoC/UUwpUjEEGi@kJLXPHzkT3mmdA5xzowEIbYUPWoXSWg5ezlYS6qiami07ndhEMpIjWjN111GCC7Sj74YlW1JPo4nMWw4iz@si8J/@iz1@G7T30He6DbZbYHo8@ck1fum9Rdk6zSB7FFv4WmCCUZGYROyqcQz8UHva9Q9gQXdNQ94s@de44n3zU5FeC15uKPBkBtWxJezKadRWdYzIeLA7/MFukfExbFeCHpSDpwsg49tatigHD3LXK68zBd8fov2WnAjELL3/uS7uAKe4Tev4U4n34THUOjmoKvbTVqppMnA1RCfipgoQ9UsalOF9M8PZWdg@z4ww@yXkG8hDnw/QC5L1pYHbQd96Ji3lWCWsT8E7LqZZmPmhcTN@YXt2bnBi5wxkQnM0mJ3mbsXE6zlt/gMpMB2GQO0Fz58kJOLH5sGMB00d99I/4AByMc9oL74JQjQSfF2fl5eLW6ExYLB5OTgbN58xB9xdHjRN44aaP0LbH/5J5uVxkrzEP//J6PiwsBr9pE8iOSYMLT0kYxpiEcnn9H@GQkhzOYIi3/v9jASWwW9UHm@jM0S4aGOBzAWYbcG6gdszsMHo8m52vrTLzgO@/OPi7ePzsWbm8vL4uJw9Ox2fo9Gx6SpcaAT29CPJfCSKBn1z@pw8np6v97dtAJdAdoLtAF0CXQFdA16u4MsArIL7y8JVA9WpfglQJUuUSCCRLkCxBsgTJEiTLa6AbIAYE0iUHEkAgX9bTl2Yvv3JrdTpfvHp2/trt5Z27F5dX1zf3Xr//5ltvv/Pue@9/8OFHH3/y6Weff/HlV19/8@133//w408//7Ja/froMau4qJtWrTe6M9Y98SGm7W7fP/3t9z/@XO2v6tO/jC04/ETLvwE)

Answer (score 0):

## 44. [D](https://dlang.org/),  `"().34;adeilmnoprstvw{}`

```
import std.stdio;void main(){writeln("43");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/n/PzO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrcvyM1MUchMz8zQ0q8uLMktSc/I0lEyMlTSta///BwA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbXlts2EH22vkJR4qyULDZLOdt87PTee9t1bBAESUggAKNIok9O/jrPm5kBKdkpD@DcATAVgwFdH1trlreamyZMH06vZ6dnvCzk7Hi2DLzUCO5tuAdyAePqCj6cOck9i17iKhcxca17hFXlHNLGGuJ1Y/X5ZUNQCdqtXZvEGpHTrOq5ts0LDBOah6DEMGkag8iL3iYCxuqKFkOQXal7xsPzXCNeWDQ8dMinUvpGGfJgS9Z3Fr4lDy0SlCkl7zIxmUSj1oRk2PIdoTqZRh4Qu7pERpO456LtczR7vMyMMqzWfD0ypbV6xHVOBmFIVk1YccPEkKYylXAKTULfBCbHNIRyoILFTLmvlOGoVkiwjCGIFnRmCr5qlQVbyKXNG1tZVXSyolV4bEIZwztr2GBtRQkRWgVa1XaVPEYvbF1DUoRXLhJrKjWAjdwR2OLXudFLz/vsku9DzMYDEzZrCwxs4mmIVCoSx9qpcOTjofOupFAdiVYQS0cGKxltwgAq0ErZklp20kRCmEvZcdA/RCA7XCMd0mMi2SEIGTl@NwpXa6hpi3pr6Q03lSWI9VcrL0uodoLkHBIWWjnOBUWRDggLoLaCbNaW9Fgf5UBb1hAZWA/H3gyAppJXktzYpwjKTqhIFhrdu9buAfiAqsBbnKJ5KKd9fI2HO0FUdZKotRvMcxPQx5aHdQ6h5f2YzLYULcq2cjfeaIXDROlzSCscLJW4tOJkaMU3nFknzapa/4O9GvjsFCt5KeGC20q@OD/OyNxUiA7JXlmaSVrxkZ4BWLO1NZyARaNrLany1zbqDEha87L34D1hRcq13mCNw1VVIpvVVo8ooUpchrorraab33Gv7HAJOx5bJUJGmshGekW56/gOyhWBMli3bFmNjM5gPaqBKfzGeoV1blIHvWqblywPCvXbciVFVBvJDi0AqopUWRHBLIIW9TjuochbGamFAqdYg8XvqMUggNo/G@g50paWIf7hmjhqBg51O7uVfizuAzNeXeelTlVGFnt32GKBuOQdPRwuhRaz7Po1sdiYAgHPO1WxAC2oyyt0KI4eo2KPlgfEXO/6PXsPEF4M6LNrGQnQxfV4WTv2fGf10suGupLHnCRNHQ8xVYyXO1qjrbaiKWsdkdwDPMRGj1AGDJ3yueR9Cmg8wGXgRDEc6Nzy2fMcFIQ0h4kmKUpOkBV9oZ5SoGIMMlhMT2i5O3QmutciAzrnQAcW2ggbsg6lsxy8nK0k1JU1Ec06ndtFMJAiWjN221GDCbaj7IenWlFPoosveAwjzuoj9578iz5/Obb30He4D7ZZIjs8@ig0fem@Rdk5zSN5FFv4W@AVoSQzidhR4Rz6ofCw7@3Dhuiahrpf9Klzh/nkoya/ErzeVOTJVFDLlrQno3lX0jkm48Hi8A@zwZGPaaMC/LAwkmZGxrG3blQMGOa2VV5nCr47Tv8tWxWIWHj5c1/aBkxxn9DzZxDvo1vVOTiqKfTSVqtyMnE2RFXBTxUk7LEyLsX5YoK3t7Q7mB1n8EnOM5CHOB@mFyDvTQOzg76TrjqbZ5WwNgHvtJxqaeaDxsX0wfTi/uSOkVucAcHZbHInbzM2Tsd56/dQmekgDHJ30NxJchWc2HzYsYDpgz76R7wGB@Oc9sK7UKlGgs@L4@J8cXd0JiwWjyZ3Bs0n3EH3rw4aJ/DCTR@jbY//JfNiucheYx7@5fV8WFgMftMmkB2TBheekjDwmIRiefkf4ZCSHM5gSLT@/2MBJbBb1Xub6MzBLhoY4HMBZhtwbqB2zOzAPZnNTlZWmXnA97/a@7t4cntbLM8vry4m10f0yh4dT4/yDwiiXOSI9rcJmfyyIdr/UR49msxudqenMAoYSxj3YLwJ4wzGOYwLGJc38cYALWGIGw9fCaO@2RUgWYBkAZIFSBYgWYBkAZIFSBaXMK5gcBggXQgYFQyQL@qXXn7l7qtHr71@zN44LZZn5xeXV/cfPHzr7Xfefe/9Dz786ONPPv3s8y@@/Orrb7797vsffvzp519@/e365ubR74@flKJu2tX6adr1z/7482Z3Uc/@MpYJ@IWWfwM)

Answer (score 0):

## 47. [Forth](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/) (forth-gforth), `46 .`

```
46 .
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//m5gp6P3/DwA)

Well that was easy.

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXf9s2EH@2PoWqNrXUmq4pxytNuvf4dU/LSUAQJCGBAIIhien41n127w6k5HQ8gPfHATdxONB2oTF6fquYrv340fh6cnLGilxMjiZzzwqF4HTNHJALGFdX8GGZFcxlwQlcZTxEplSHsCytRVobTXNVG3V@WROUnHYr20S@QmRVVnZMmfqFScYV817ynqlrjcjxzkQC2qiSFr0XbaG6jPm7s5q/sKiZb3EeC@FqqcmDDVnfGvgWzDdIUKYQrE1EJxK0XBESfsO2hKqoa7FH2dUlThSJO8abLkWzw/M0kTqrFFsNk8IYNeAqJYMwJKsiLJnOeJ@mIhZwCnVE3zgmR9eEUqA8C4kyV0rNUC0XYBlD4A3oTBR8VTIJNpBLkzY2oizpZHkj8di41Jq1Rme9tSUlhCvpaVWZZXQYPTdVBUnhTtpAU13KHqzFlsAGv9YOXjrWJZdc50My7jNukjafgU08DR4LSeJYOyWOdDx03qXgsiXREmJpyWApgokYQAlaKVtCiVboQAhzKVoG@vsIRItrpEM4TGS2D0IEht@1xNUKatqg3ko4zXRpCGL9VdKJAqqdIDmHJPONGHheUqQ9wgKoDCeblSE9xgXR0yarifRTB8de94BY0UlBbuxSBGXHZSALtepsY3YAfEBV4C2yiA/ltIuvdnAniMpWEDVmjXmuPfrYML9KITSsG5LZFLxB2UZshxstceggXAppiSOLBS4tGRlasjXLjBV6Wa7@Mb3q58mprGCFgAtuSvEif@CI1FSI9sleGuJEJdlAzwCsspXRjIBBoyslqPJXJqgESFqxonPgPWFJypVaY43DVZU8mVVGDSiiSlyGuiuMopvfMidNfwlbFhrJfUKKyFo4Sblr2RbKFYHUWLfZvBwmKoHVoAZY@A3VEutcxxZ61SYtGeYl6jfFUvAg1yLbtwCoKlJleACzCBrUY5mDIm9EoBYKM5nVWPyWWgwCqP2znp4jbWgZ4u@viaVmYFG3NRvhhuLeT4ara51QsUzIYO/2GywQG52lh8NG32CWbbeiKTYmT8CxVpaZhxbUphU6FEuPUb5D8z3KbGe73fQUEF4M6LMrEQjQxXV4Wdvsbmd1womaupLDnERFHQ8xVYwTW1qjraYkljGWSOoBDmKjRyiBDJ1yqeRd9Gjcw2VgRDEc6Nzi@d0ZFITQe0YdJSXHi5K@UE/RUzF64Q2mxzfM7jsT3WueAJ2zpwPzTYANSYdUSQ5ezkYQaouKiMpaldqF15AiWtNm01KD8aal7PtnSlJPoovPWfADTuoDc478Cy59GbZ337W4D7YZIls8@sAVfem@BdFaxQJ5FBr4W2AloSgSCdhR4Ry6vvCw7@3ChujqmrpfcLG1e350QZFfEV5vKvKoS6hlQ9qjVqwt6ByjdmCx/4dZ40jHtJYeflgyks60CENvXcvgMcxNI51KFHy3jP5bNtITMfDyp7608ZjiLqLnzyHem1vZWjiqMfTSRsliNLLGB1nCTxUk7InUNobpbIS3tzBb4A4cfJITB/IQpj17BvJO18Dt9R235dk0qYS1EXinxFgJPe01zsYPxxcPRgdabJADgpPJ6CBt0yaMB75xOyj1uBcGuQM0dxxtCSc27XfMgL3XR/@I1@BgmNJeeBdKWQvweXaUn8/uDc742exmdNBrPmYWun@51ziCF278BG07/C@Z5vNZ8hrz8C@vp/3CrPebNoHskDS48JSEfo5JyOeX/xEOKUnh9IZ44/4/FlACu2W1s4nO7O2igR7eCTDZgHMDtUNm@9nTyeR4aaSeenz/y52/s6e3t/n8/Go@H10f0it7eDQ@TD8giNIThmj360hsevEQpRZ4eDM6XGxPTmDkMOYwTmHch3EG4xzGBYzLRVhooAUMvnDwFTCqxTYHyRwkc5DMQTIHyRwkc5DMQTK/hHEFg8EA6ZzDKGGAfF6NX5q8/Mq9VxeH09lrrx9lx2@c5PPT@2fnF5dXD958@Oitt9959733P/jwo48/@fSzz7/48quvv/n2u@9/@PGnn3/59XqxuHn85CkreCmqupHLlWq1sc@cD3G92XbPf/v9jz8X24vq8C9tMg7/1eJv)

Comment: You used the input of 46's toolbox for your toolbox. I'll fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

## 49. [brainbool](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 26 bytes `+><.`

```
+>+<.>.>.>.>.>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLys/P@f9f285OGwJtQEDPDg7///@al6@bnJickQoA)

Outputs `110000`, which is `48` in base 2

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbXduM2EH22vkJRsrGUYzqmHBdtsie9914sZxcEQRISCGBRJHFT/jrPzsyAlLwpD8BclKkYDGC70Bg9v1NM1378aHwzObtgRS4mJ5O5Z4VCcL5hDsgVtMUCOpZZwVwWnMBVxkNkSnUIy9JapLXRNFa1UZfXNUHJabeyTeRrRFZlZceUqZ8bZFwx7yXvJ3WtETnemUhAG1XSoveiLVSXMX9/VPPnFjXzLY5jIVwtNVmwJe07A33BfIMEeQrB2kR0IkHLNSHht2xHqIq6FgeULa5xoIjdMd50yZs9nqeB1Fml2HoYFMaoAVcpGIQhWBVhyXTG@zAVsYBTqCPaxjE4uiaUHOVZSJS5UmqGYrkAzegCb0BmomCrkomxgViatLERZUknyxuJx8al1qw1Ouu1rSggXElPq8qsokPvuakqCAp30gYa6lL2YCN2BLbYWztY6ViXTHKdD0m5z7hJ0nwGOvE0eCwksWPulNjS8dB5l4LLllhL8KUlhaUIJqIDJUilaAklWqEDIYylaBnI7z0QLa6RDOEwkNnBCREY9huJqxXktEG5lXCa6dIQxPyrpBMFZDtBMg5J5hsxzHlJnvYIE6AynHRWhuQYF0RPm6wm0g8dHHvdA5qKTgoyYx8iSDsuA2moVWcbswdgA4oCa3GK5iGd9v7VDu4EUdkKosZsMM61Rxsb5tfJhYZ1QzCbgjfI24jdcKMlNh2ESy6tsGWxwKUVI0UrtmGZsUKvyvU/hot@nIzKClYIuOCmFM/PDzMiFRWifbBXhmaikmygFwDW2dpoRsCg0rUSlPlrE1QCxK1Y0TmwnrAk4UptMMfhqkqe1CqjBhRRJC5D3hVG0c1vmZOmv4QtC43kPiFFZCOcpNi1bAfpikBqzNtsXg4DlcB6EANT2IdqhXmuYwu1apuWDPMS5ZtiJXiQG5EdSgBkFYkyPIBaBA3KscxBkjciUAmFkcxqTH5LJQYB5P5FTy@RNrQM/vfXxFIxsCjbmq1wQ3IfBsPVtU6oWCZksHb7LSaIjc7Sw2GjbzDKtlvTEAuTJ@BYK8vMQwlq0wodiqXHKN@j@QFltrPdfngOCC8G1Nm1CATo4jq8rG12v7I64URNVclhTKKiioeYMsaJHa3RVlPSlDGWSKoBDnyjRyiBDI1yKeVd9Kjcw2VgRNEdqNzi2f0RJITQh4k6SgqOFyX1kE/RUzJ64Q2GxzfMHioT3WueAJ2zpwPzTYANSYZUiQ9ezkYQaouKiMpalcqF1xAiWtNm21KB8aal6PunSlJNoovPWfADTuIDc47sCy71DMu771rcB9sMkR0efeCKerpvQbRWsUAWhQZ@C6wkFEUiASsqnEPXJx7Wvb3b4F1dU/ULLrb2MB9dUGRXhNebkjzqEnLZkPSoFWsLOseoHWjs/zAbbOmYNtLDhyUj7kyLMNTWjQwe3dw20qlEwXbL6N@ylZ6IgZc/1aWtxxB3ES1/Bv7e3snWwlGNoZY2ShajkTU@yBI@VRCwx1LbGKazEd7ewuxgdpjBJznNQBzCtJ@eAb/TNcz28k7b8mKaRMLaCKxTYqyEnvYSZ@M3xlcPR0dabHEGGCeT0VHapk0YD/PG7aHU454Z@I5Q3Wm0JZzYtN8xg@mDPPoj3oCBYUp74V0oZS3A5tlJfjl7MBjjZ7Pb0VEv@ZRZqP7lQeIIXrjxY9Tt8F8yzeezZDXG4V9WT/uFWW83bQLeIWhw4SkI/RiDkM@v/8MdEpLc6RXxxv2/LyAEdstqrxONOehFBT2852DSAecGYofI9qMnk8npykg99fj@l3t7Z0/u7vL55WK@GN0c0yt7fDI@Th8QROkJI0SPHKLhx007@w/J8e3oeLk7O4OWQ5tDO4f2GrQLaJfQrqBdL8NSAy2g8aWDXkCrlrscOHPgzIEzB84cOHPgzIEzB878GtoCGoMG3DmHVkID/rwavzB58aUHLy@Pp6@cZK@e5fPzi8ur68XD1x@9@dbb77z73vsffPjRx598@tnnX3z51dfffPvd9z/8@NPPv9wsl7e/Pn7CCl6Kqm5Wa9VqY586H@Jmu@ue/fb7H38ud1fV8V/aZBy@1OJv)

Answer (score 0):

## 50. [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 4 bytes

```
->49
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5Fo5VhUlFhpE1xSlJmXbqdZzaUABGWJOQppCrYK1f917Uws/4OEasESBUBVJRppGpqaXLX/AQ)

[Next toolbox.](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmq4pxytNuvfey3ITEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5HQ/AfRg3cTjAdqExen6rmK79@NH4enJyxopcTI4mc88KheB0zRyQC2hXV9CxzArmsuAErjIeIlOqQ1iW1iKtjaaxqo06v6wJSk67lW0iXyGyKis7pkz93CDjinkveT@pa43I8c5EAtqokha9F22huoz5u6OaP7eomW9xHAvhaqnJgg1p3xroC@YbJMhTCNYmohMJWq4ICb9hW0JV1LXYo@zqEgeK2B3jTZe82eF5GkidVYqthkFhjBpwlYJBGIJVEZZMZ7wPUxELOIU6om0cg6NrQslRnoVEmSulZiiWC9CMLvAGZCYKtiqZGBuIpUkbG1GWdLK8kXhsXGrNWqOzXtuSAsKV9LSqzDI69J6bqoKgcCdtoKEuZQ/WYktgg721g5WOdckk1/mQlPuMmyTNZ6ATT4PHQhI75k6JLR0PnXcpuGyJtQRfWlJYimAiOlCCVIqWUKIVOhDCWIqWgfzeA9HiGskQDgOZ7Z0QgWG/lrhaQU4blFsJp5kuDUHMv0o6UUC2EyTjkGS@EcOcl@RpjzABKsNJZ2VIjnFB9LTJaiL90MGx1z2gqeikIDN2IYK04zKQhlp1tjE7ADagKLAWp2ge0mnnX@3gThCVrSBqzBrjXHu0sWF@lVxoWDcEsyl4g7yN2A43WmLTQbjk0hJbFgtcWjJStGRrlhkr9LJc/WN41Y@TUVnBCgEX3JTi@flhRqSiQrQP9tLQTFSSDfQMwCpbGc0IGFS6UoIyf2WCSoC4FSs6B9YTliRcqTXmOFxVyZNaZdSAIorEZci7wii6@S1z0vSXsGWhkdwnpIishZMUu5ZtIV0RSI15m83LYaASWA1iYAr7UC0xz3VsoVZt0pJhXqJ8UywFD3Itsn0JgKwiUYYHUIugQTmWOUjyRgQqoTCSWY3Jb6nEIIDcP@vpOdKGlsH//ppYKgYWZVuzEW5I7v1guLrWCRXLhAzWbr/BBLHRWXo4bPQNRtl2KxpiYfIEHGtlmXkoQW1aoUOx9BjlOzTfo8x2ttsNTwHhxYA6uxKBAF1ch5e1ze5WViecqKkqOYxJVFTxEFPGOLGlNdpqSpoyxhJJNcCBb/QIJZChUS6lvIselXu4DIwougOVWzy7O4KEEHo/UUdJwfGipB7yKXpKRi@8wfD4htl9ZaJ7zROgc/Z0YL4JsCHJkCrxwcvZCEJtURFRWatSufAaQkRr2mxaKjDetBR9/1RJqkl08TkLfsBJfGDOkX3BpZ5hefddi/tgmyGyxaMPXFFP9y2I1ioWyKLQwG@BlYSiSCRgRYVz6PrEw7q3cxu8q2uqfsHF1u7nowuK7IrwelOSR11CLhuSHrVibUHnGLUDjf0fZo0tHdNaeviwZMSdaRGG2rqWwaObm0Y6lSjYbhn9WzbSEzHw8qe6tPEY4i6i5c/A35tb2Vo4qjHU0kbJYjSyxgdZwqcKAvZYahvDdDbC21uYLcwOM/gkpxmIQ5j20zPgd7qG2V7ecVueTZNIWBuBdUqMldDTXuJs/HB88WB0oMUGZ4BxMhkdpG3ahPEwb9wOSj3umYHvANUdR1vCiU37HTOY3sujP@I1GBimtBfehVLWAmyeHeXns3uDMX42uxkd9JKPmYXqX@4ljuCFGz9G3Q7/JdN8PktWYxz@ZfW0X5j1dtMm4B2CBheegtCPMQj5/PI/3CEhyZ1eEW/c//sCQmC3rHY60Zi9XlTQwzsOJh1wbiB2iGw/ejKZHC@N1FOP73@5s3f25PY2n59fnZ6Org/plT08Gh@mDwii9LQhGv7ZtN5/QxDX5vBmdLjYnpxAy6HNoZ1Cuw/tDNo5tAtol4uw0EALaHzhoBfQqsU2B84cOHPgzIEzB84cOHPgzIEzv4R2BY1BA@6cQyuhAX9ejV@YvPjSvZcXh9PZK68eZcevneTz0/tn5xeXVw9ef/jojTffevudd997/4MPP/r4k08/@/yLL7/6@ptvv/v@hx9/@vmX68Xi5tfHT1jBS1HVjVyuVKuNfep8iOvNtnv22@9//LnYXlSHf2mTcfhVi78B)

Answer (score 0):

## 51. [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/programs/unlambda/), `` `.05i ``

```
`.0`.5i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K83LScxNSkn8/z9BzyBBzzTz/38A)

[Next Toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXY9s2EH62foWqNrXUmm4oxytNuvfey3IdEARJSCCAYEhiOv51n927Ayk5HQ/AfRg3cTjAdqExen6rmK79@PH4anL/lBW5mBxN5p4VCsHJmjkg59AuL6FjmRXMZcEJXGU8RKZUh7AsrUVaG01jVRt1dlETlJx2K9tEvkJkVVZ2TJn6uUHGFfNe8n5S1xqR452JBLRRJS16L9pCdRnzd0c1f25RM9/iOBbC1VKTBRvSvjXQF8w3SJCnEKxNRCcStFwREn7DtoSqqGuxR9nlBQ4UsTvGmy55s8PzNJA6qxRbDYPCGDXgKgWDMASrIiyZzngfpiIWcAp1RNs4BkfXhJKjPAuJMldKzVAsF6AZXeANyEwUbFUyMTYQS5M2NqIs6WR5I/HYuNSatUZnvbYlBYQr6WlVmWV06D03VQVB4U7aQENdyh6sxZbABntrBysd65JJrvMhKfcZN0maz0AnngaPhSR2zJ0SWzoeOu9ScNkSawm@tKSwFMFEdKAEqRQtoUQrdCCEsRQtA/m9B6LFNZIhHAYy2zshAsN@LXG1gpw2KLcSTjNdGoKYf5V0ooBsJ0jGIcl8I4Y5L8nTHmECVIaTzsqQHOOC6GmT1UT6oYNjr3tAU9FJQWbsQgRpx2UgDbXqbGN2AGxAUWAtTtE8pNPOv9rBnSAqW0HUmDXGufZoY8P8KrnQsG4IZlPwBnkbsR1utMSmg3DJpSW2LBa4tGSkaMnWLDNW6GW5@sfwsh8no7KCFQIuuCnF8/PDjEhFhWgf7KWhmagkG@gpgFW2MpoRMKh0pQRl/soElQBxK1Z0DqwnLEm4UmvMcbiqkie1yqgBRRSJy5B3hVF081vmpOkvYctCI7lPSBFZCycpdi3bQroikBrzNpuXw0AlsBrEwBT2oVpinuvYQq3apCXDvET5plgKHuRaZPsSAFlFogwPoBZBg3Isc5DkjQhUQmEksxqT31KJQQC5f9rTM6QNLYP//TWxVAwsyrZmI9yQ3PvBcHWtEyqWCRms3X6DCWKjs/Rw2OgbjLLtVjTEwuQJONbKMvNQgtq0Qodi6THKd2i@R5ntbLcbngDCiwF1diUCAbq4Di9rm92trE44UVNVchiTqKjiIaaMcWJLa7TVlDRljCWSaoAD3@gRSiBDo1xKeRc9KvdwGRhRdAcqt3h2dwQJIfR@oo6SguNFST3kU/SUjF54g@HxDbP7ykT3midA5@zpwHwTYEOSIVXig5ezEYTaoiKislalcuE1hIjWtNm0VGC8aSn6/qmSVJPo4nMW/ICT@MCcI/uCSz3D8u67FvfBNkNki0cfuKKe7lsQrVUskEWhgd8CKwlFkUjAigrn0PWJh3Vv5zZ4V9dU/YKLrd3PRxcU2RXh9aYkj7qEXDYkPWrF2oLOMWoHGvs/zBpbOqa19PBhyYg70yIMtXUtg0c3N410KlGw3TL6t2ykJ2Lg5U91aeMxxF1Ey5@Bv9e3srVwVGOopY2SxWhkjQ@yhE8VBOxGahvDdDbC21uYLcwOM/gkpxmIQ5j20zPgd7qG2V7ecVueTpNIWBuBdUqMldDTXuJs/Gh8/nB0oMUGZ4BxMhkdpG3ahPEwb9wOSj3umYHvANUdR1vCiU37HTOY3sujP@IVGBimtBfehVLWAmyeHeVns3uDMX42ux4d9JKPmYXqX@4ljuCFG9@gbof/kmk@nyWrMQ7/snraL8x6u2kT8A5BgwtPQejHGIR8fvEf7pCQ5E6viDfu/30BIbBbVjudaMxeLyro4R0Hkw44NxA7RLYfPZlMjpdG6qnH97/c2Tt7cnubz88uH5yNrg7plT08Gh@mDwii9LQhGv7ZtN5/QxDX5vB6dLjY3r8PLYc2h3YC7QG0U2hn0M6hXSzCQgMtoPGFg15AqxbbHDhz4MyBMwfOHDhz4MyBMwfO/ALaJTQGDbhzDq2EBvx5NX5h8uJL915eHE5nr7x6lL2Wz08enJ1fXD58/dHjN9586@133n3v/Q8@/OjjTz797PMvvvzq62@@/e77H3786edfrhaL619vWMFLUdXNcqVabexT50Ncb7bds99@/@PPxfa8OvxLm4zDh1r8DQ)

Answer (score 0):

## 52. [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 17 bytes

```
USE: io
"51"print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@v8/NNjVSiEzn0vJ1FCpoCgzr@T/fwA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVbZdts2EH2OvkJ1m1pqQ9eU461Nup/u@@npZrsJCIAkJBBAsEhiuvx1n92ZASk5XR7AuRhgVgwGdH1srVncamaaMH08vTo4PmVVKQ8eHCwCqzSCkzXzQM5hXF7ChxVOMl9EL3GV8ZiY1j1CIZxD2lhDc91YfXbREFScdmvXJr5C5HQheqZt88Kk4JqFoPjANI1B5HlvEwFjtaDFEGRX6b5g4e6s4S8sGhY6nKdK@kYZ8mBD1rcWvhULLRKUqSTrMjGZRKNWhGTYsC2hOplG7lFxeYETTeKe8bbP0ezwIk@UKWrNVuOkslaPuM7JIAzJqgkrZgo@pKlKFZxCk9A3jskxDaEcKC9ipswLZRiq5RIsYwi8BZ2Zgq9aZcEWcmnzxlYKQSfLW4XHxpUxrLOmGKwtKSFcq0Cr2i6Tx@i5rWtICvfKRZoaoQawllsCG/w6N3rpWZ9d8n2I2XgouM3aQgE28TR4qhSJY@0IHPl46LyF5KojUQGxdGRQyGgTBiBAK2VLatlJEwlhLmXHQP8QgexwjXRIj4ks9kHIyPC7VrhaQ01b1FtLb5gRliDWX628rKDaCZJzSIrQypEXFEU6ICyA2nKyWVvSY32UA22Lhsgw9XDszQCIlbyS5MYuRVB2XEWy0OjetXYHwAdUBd4ii/hQTrv4Gg93gqjqJFFr15jnJqCPLQurHELL@jGZbcVblG3ldrzRCoeJ0ueQljiKVOHSkpGhJVuzwjpplmL1j@nlMM9OFRWrJFxwK@SL/JEjc1MhOiR7aYmTtGIjPQWwKlbWMAIWja60pMpf2agzIGnNqt6D94QVKdd6jTUOV1XxbFZbPaKEKnEZ6q6ymm5@x7yywyXsWGwVDxlpImvpFeWuY1soVwTKYN0WCzFOdAarUQ2w8BvrJda5SR30qk1esiwo1G@rpeRRrWWxbwFQVaTK8ghmEbSoxzEPRd7KSC0UZqposPgdtRgEUPunAz1D2tIyxD9cE0fNwKFuZzfSj8W9n4xX13mpk8jIYu8OGywQl7yjh8Ol0GKWXb@iKTamQMCzTokiQAvq8godiqPHqNyhxR4Vrnf9bnoCCC8G9NmVjATo4nq8rF1xt7N66WVDXcljTpKmjoeYKsbLLa3RViuIZa0jknuAh9joEcqgQKd8LnmfAhoPcBkYUQwHOrd8fncGBSHNntEkRckJUtAX6ikFKsYgg8X0hJa5fWeie80zoHMOdGChjbAh61A6y8HL2UpCXVUT0UWnc7sIBlJEa8ZuOmowwXaU/fBMK@pJdPE5i2HEWX1k3pN/0ecvw/Ye@g73wTZLZItHH7mmL923KDunWSSPYgt/C0wQSjKTiB0VzqEfCg/73i5siK5pqPtFnzq35ycfNfmV4PWmIk9GQC1b0p6MZl1F55iMB4vDP8waRz6mtQrww1KQdGFkHHvrWsWAYW5a5XWm4Ltj9N@yUYGIhZc/96VNwBT3CT1/DvHe3KrOwVFNoZe2WlWTibMhKgE/VZCwJ8q4FGfzCd7eym6BO3LwSc4cyEOcDew5yHvTAHfQd9SJ01lWCWsT8E7LqZZmNmicTx9Nz9@c3DNygxwQPDiY3MvbjI3TkW/9DiozHYRB7h6aO0pOwInNhh1zYO/10T/iFTgYZ7QX3gWhGgk@zx@UZ/P7ozNhPr@Z3Bs0HzEH3V/sNU7ghZs@Qdse/0tm5WKevcY8/Mvr2bAwH/ymTSA7Jg0uPCVhmGMSysXFf4RDSnI4gyHe@v@PBZTAblXvbKIze7toYIB3Asw24NxA7ZjZYfb04OBoaZWZBXz/xc7f@dPb23Jxdnl6Mbk6pFf28MH0MD9oiMa/a8TjzwfixhIHlR3eTA6vt8fHMEoYCxgnMB7COIVxBuMcxsV1hG8Fg197@EoY9fW2BLkS5EqQK0GuBLkS5EqQK0GuvIBxCYPBAOmSwxAwQL6sX3r5lfuvXh/O5q@9/qA4euN4cfLw7Pzi8q1Hj99@59333v/gw48@/uTTzz7/4suvvv7m2@@@/@HHn37@5er6@ubXJ09ZxYWsm3a50t2zkNabbf/8t9//@PN6e14f/mVsweEnWv4N)

Answer (score 0):

## 53. [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), `6DP*`

```
6DP6DD*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/MJcDMxUXr/38A)

---

```
6       push 6
 D      pop 6, push 6-1=5
  P     pop 5, push the 5th prime = 13
   6DD  push 6-1-1=4
      * pop 13 and 4, push 13*4=52
```

---

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZXk9s2EH4@/QpFiSNpcrwcdb7m2Kkz6WXSy@ligyBIQgIBGEUSnfKv83zZXZDSOeUB3A8LbMViQduFxujFnWK69uMn45vJ6TkrcjE5niw8KxSCsw1zQC5hXF/Dh2VWMJcFJ3CV8RCZUh3CsrQWaW00zVVt1MVVTVBy2q1sE/kakVVZ2TFl6pcmGVfMe8l7pq41Isc7Ewloo0pa9F60heoy5u/Pav7Soma@xXkshKulJg@2ZH1n4Fsw3yBBmUKwNhGdSNByTUj4LdsRqqKuxQFl11c4USTuGG@6FM0eL9JE6qxSbD1MCmPUgKuUDMKQrIqwZDrjfZqKWMAp1BF945gcXRNKgfIsJMpcKTVDtVyAZQyBN6AzUfBVySTYQC5N2tiIsqST5Y3EY@NSa9YanfXWVpQQrqSnVWVW0WH03FQVJIU7aQNNdSl7sBE7Alv8Wjt46ViXXHKdD8m4z7hJ2nwGNvE0eCwkiWPtlDjS8dB5l4LLlkRLiKUlg6UIJmIAJWilbAklWqEDIcylaBno7yMQLa6RDuEwkdkhCBEYfjcSVyuoaYN6K@E006UhiPVXSScKqHaC5BySzDdi4HlJkfYIC6AynGxWhvQYF0RPm6wm0k8dHHvdA2JFJwW5sU8RlB2XgSzUqrON2QPwAVWBt8giPpTTPr7awZ0gKltB1JgN5rn26GPD/DqF0LBuSGZT8AZlG7EbbrTEoYNwKaQVjiwWuLRiZGjFNiwzVuhVuf7H9LqfJ6eyghUCLrgpxcv8gSNSUyHaJ3tliBOVZAM9B7DO1kYzAgaNrpWgyl@boBIgacWKzoH3hCUpV2qDNQ5XVfJkVhk1oIgqcRnqrjCKbn7LnDT9JWxZaCT3CSkiG@Ek5a5lOyhXBFJj3WaLcpioBNaDGmDhN1QrrHMdW@hV27RkmJeo3xQrwYPciOzQAqCqSJXhAcwiaFCPZQ6KvBGBWijMZFZj8VtqMQig9s97eoG0oWWIv78mlpqBRd3WbIUbivswGa6udULFMiGDvdtvsUBsdJYeDht9g1m23Zqm2Jg8AcdaWWYeWlCbVuhQLD1G@R4tDiizne320zNAeDGgz65FIEAX1@FlbbP7ndUJJ2rqSg5zEhV1PMRUMU7saI22mpJYxlgiqQc4iI0eoQQydMqlknfRo3EPl4ERxXCgc4sX92dQEEIfGHWUlBwvSvpCPUVPxeiFN5ge3zB76Ex0r3kCdM6eDsw3ATYkHVIlOXg5G0GoLSoiKmtVahdeQ4poTZttSw3Gm5ay758rST2JLj5nwQ84qQ/MOfIvuPRl2N591@I@2GaI7PDoA1f0pfsWRGsVC@RRaOBvgZWEokgkYEeFc@j6wsO@tw8boqtr6n7BxdYe@NEFRX5FeL2pyKMuoZYNaY9asbagc4zagcX@H2aDIx3TRnr4YclIOtMiDL11I4PHMLeNdCpR8N0y@m/ZSk/EwMuf@tLWY4q7iJ6/gHhv72Rr4ajG0EsbJYvRyBofZAk/VZCwp1LbGGbzEd7ewuyAO3DwSU4cyEOY9ew5yDtdA7fXd9KW57OkEtZG4J0SYyX0rNc4Hz8eXz4aHWmxRQ4ITiajo7RNmzAe@MbtodTjXhjkjtDcSbQlnNis3zEH9kEf/SPegINhRnvhXShlLcDn@XF@MX8wOOPn89vRUa/5hFno/uVB4wheuPFTtO3wv2SWL@bJa8zDv7ye9Qvz3m/aBLJD0uDCUxL6OSYhX1z9RzikJIXTG@KN@/9YQAnsltXeJjpzsIsGengvwGQDzg3UDpntZ88mk5OVkXrm8f0v9/7On93d5YvL09OL0c2UXtnp8XiaHjREww8H4toQBxUg6H@mprej6XJ3egojh7GAcQbjIYxzGBcwLmFcLcNSAy1g8KWDr4BRLXc5SOYgmYNkDpI5SOYgmYNkDpL5FYxrGAwGSOccRgkD5PNq/Mrk1dcevL6czuZvHGcnb57mi7OH55dX14/eevzk7Xfefe/9Dz786ONPPv3s8y@@/Orrb7797vsffvzp519ulsvbX58@YwUvRVU3crVWrbbPnY@b7a578dvvf/y53F1W07@0yTj8TIu/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## 55. [Agony](https://github.com/royvanrijn/JAgony)

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
```

I don't really get this language, but it seems to be a superset of brainfuck.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0zPz6v8/1@bHKCnq/f/PwA)

[Next toolbox](https://tio.run/##dVZne9s2EP5s/QpVbWqpj@macrzSpHvvvSzXAUGQhAQCCIYkpuOvu3cHUnI6PoD34oCbOBxou9AYPb9TTNd@/GR8PTk5Y0UuJkeTuWeFQnC6Zg7IBYyrK/iwzArmsuAErjIeIlOqQ1iW1iKtjaa5qo06v6wJSk67lW0iXyGyKis7pkz9wiTjinkvec/UtUbkeGciAW1USYvei7ZQXcb8/VnNX1jUzLc4j4VwtdTkwYasbw18C@YbJChTCNYmohMJWq4ICb9hW0JV1LXYo@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@ELQuN5D4hRWQtnKTctWwL5YpAaqzbbF4OE5XAalADLPyGaol1rmMLvWqTlgzzEvWbYil4kGuR7VsAVBWpMjyAWQQN6rHMQZE3IlALhZnMaix@Sy0GAdT@WU/PkTa0DPH318RSM7Co25qNcENx7yfD1bVOqFgmZLB3@w0WiI3O0sNho28wy7Zb0RQbkyfgWCvLzEMLatMKHYqlxyjfofkeZbaz3W56CggvBvTZlQgE6OI6vKxtdr@zOuFETV3JYU6ioo6HmCrGiS2t0VZTEssYSyT1AAex0SOUQIZOuVTyLno07uEyMKIYDnRu8fz@DApC6D2jjpKS40VJX6in6KkYvfAG0@MbZvedie41T4DO2dOB@SbAhqRDqiQHL2cjCLVFRURlrUrtwmtIEa1ps2mpwXjTUvb9MyWpJ9HF5yz4ASf1gTlH/gWXvgzbu@9a3AfbDJEtHn3gir5034JorWKBPAoN/C2wklAUiQTsqHAOXV942Pd2YUN0dU3dL7jY2j0/uqDIrwivNxV51CXUsiHtUSvWFnSOUTuw2P/DrHGkY1pLDz8sGUlnWoSht65l8BjmppFOJQq@W0b/LRvpiRh4@VNf2nhMcRfR8@cQ782dbC0c1Rh6aaNkMRpZ44Ms4acKEnYrtY1hOhvh7S3MFrgDB5/kxIE8hGnPnoG80zVwe33HbXk2TSphbQTeKTFWQk97jbPx4/HFo9GBFhvkgOBkMjpI27QJ44Fv3A5KPe6FQe4AzR1HW8KJTfsdM2Dv9dE/4jU4GKa0F96FUtYCfJ4d5eezB4Mzfja7GR30mo@Zhe5f7jWO4IUb36Jth/8l03w@S15jHv7l9bRfmPV@0yaQHZIGF56S0M8xCfn88j/CISUpnN4Qb9z/xwJKYLesdjbRmb1dNNDDewEmG3BuoHbIbD97OpkcL43UU4/vf7nzd/b07g5snZyfjK4P0zt2eDQ@HP4zENeGOCiHoP@HQri7YIc3o8PF9uQERg5jDuMUxkMYZzDOYVzAuFyEhQZawOALB18Bo1psc5DMQTIHyRwkc5DMQTIHyRwk80sYVzAYDJDOOYwSBsjn1filycuvPHh1cTidvXb0@kk@P314dn5xefXojcdP3nzr7Xfefe/9Dz786ONPPv3s8y@@/Orrb7797vsffvzp519@vV4sbn67fcoKXoqqbuRypVpt7DPnQ1xvtt3z3//486/F9qI6/Bs)