# Don't get banned from stack exchange!

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, polyglot, answer-chaining

I'm sure this is going to spark some controversy, but let's do a practical demonstration.

The objective of this is simple, using the [new code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/367090) and no input, print out my pronouns ( "he/him", "he him" is also acceptable).

Here's the challenge. This is a classical polyglot contest!

This means that the first answer can be in any language, and the only requirement is that the user post their number (1), their language, and their code. The second user must then rework this code to satisfy the condition with the first answers language, and any other language that hasn't been used.  Adding code is the preferred method of polyglotting, but subtraction is ok too. This keeps going until we have a program which works simultaneously in many languages. No language should appear twice. Breaking the contest functionality in any previous language would make an answer invalid

An example:

First person to post code:
1. C++
[Code]

Second person to post code:
2. Python.
[Altered Code]

Third person to post code:
3. Java.
[Further altered code]

The winner will be the last answer that stands uncontested for 4 weeks.

This is a high steaks round, as the penalty for intentionally posting code which mis-genders me, could be a ban from the site itself (though I, unlike stack exchange, am able to overlook this)! Best of luck!

For Additional reference, he'res the clarification on chaining rules.

> ## Additional rules
>
> - Your program must run without erroring out or crashing. Warnings (and other stderr output) are acceptable, but the program must exit
>     normally (e.g. by running off the end of the program, or via a command
>     such as `exit` that performs normal program termination).
> - Each answer must be no more than 20% or 20 bytes (whichever is larger) longer than the previous answer. (This is to prevent the use
>     of languages like Lenguage spamming up the thread, and to encourage at
>     least a minor amount of golfing.)
> - Tricks like excessive comment abuse, despite being banned in some polyglot competitions, are just fine here.
> - You don't have to use the previous answers as a guide to writing your own (you can rewrite the whole program if you like, as long as it
>     complies with the spec); however, basing your answer mostly on a
>     previous answer is allowed and probably the easiest way to make a
>     solution.
> - You cannot submit two answers in a row. Let someone else post in between. This rule applies until victory condition is met.
> - As this challenge requires other competitors to post in the same languages you are, you can only use languages with a [free
>     implementation](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7822/62131)
>     (much as though this were a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) contest).
> - In the case where a language has more than one interpreter, you can pick any interpreter for any given language so long as all programs
>     which are meant to run successfully in that language do so in that
>     interpreter. (In other words, if a program works in more than one
>     interpreter, future posts can pick either of those interpreters,
>     rather than a post "locking in" a particular choice of interpreter for
>     a language.)
> - This challenge now uses the [new PPCG rules about language choice](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges?cb=1):
>     you can use a language, or a language interpreter, even if it's newer
>     than the question. However, you may not use a language/interpreter
>     that's newer than the question if a) the language was designed for the
>     purpose of polyglotting or b) the language was inspired by this
>     question. (So newly designed practical programming languages are
>     almost certainly going to be OK, as are unrelated esolangs, but things
>     like [A Pear Tree](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree), which was
>     inspired by this question, are banned.) Note that this doesn't change
>     the validity of languages designed for polyglotting that are older
>     than this question.
> - Note that the victory condition (see below) is designed so that breaking the chain (i.e. making it impossible for anyone else to
>     answer after you via the use of a language that is hard to polyglot
>     with further languages) will disqualify you from winning. The aim is
>     to keep going as long as we can, and if you want to win, you'll have
>     to respect that.

## For reference, this is the exact CoC I'm referring to, consolidated as per the request of many users for clairity:

> We expect [today’s changes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) to the [Code of
>   Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) to generate a lot of
>   questions. We’ve tried to anticipate some of the most common questions
>   people may have here, and we’ll be adding to this list as more
>   questions come up.
>
> **Q1: What are personal pronouns, and why are they relevant to the Code of Conduct?**
>
> Personal pronouns are a way to refer to a person without using their
>   name, when the subject is known. [From
>   mypronouns.org](https://www.mypronouns.org/sharing):
>
> > *The vast majority of people go by the pronouns sets “he/him” or “she/her.” A small but increasing number of people use “they/them”
> >     pronouns or another pronouns set -- sometimes simply because they
> >     don’t want to go by pronouns with a gender association (just as some
> >     folks go by “Ms.” whether or not they are married, because they don’t
> >     think their marital status should be a relevant issue), and sometimes
> >     people use pronouns that aren’t associated with one of those two most
> >     common (binary) genders because they are nonbinary (i.e. people who
> >     are neither exclusively a man nor exclusively a woman -- e.g.
> >     genderqueer, agender, bigender, fluid, third/additional gender in a
> >     cultural tradition, etc.).*
>
> The goal of our Code of Conduct is to help us “build a community that
>   is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.” Using
>   someone’s pronouns is a way of showing respect for them and refusing
>   to do so causes harm.
>
> **Q2: What does the Code of Conduct say about gender pronouns?**
>
> The Code of Conduct has two direct references to gender pronouns:
>
> 1. “Use stated pronouns (when known).”
> 2. “Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.”
>
> We’re asking everyone to do two things. First, if you do know
>   someone’s pronouns (e.g. because they told you), then use them as you
>   normally would use any pronoun. Second, if you don’t know someone’s
>   pronouns, use gender-neutral language rather than making an
>   assumption.
>
> **Q3: What should I do if I make a mistake and use the wrong pronouns?**
>
> If you make a mistake, apologize and correct your mistake if possible
>   (e.g. by editing your post). We recognize that this may be new to many
>   people, particularly members of our community who do not speak English
>   as a first language, and so mistakes will happen as we all learn
>   together.
>
> **Q4: What should I do if I see someone using the wrong pronouns?**
>
> If you notice someone who is using the wrong pronouns for someone else
>   who has stated them (e.g. in a comment or on their profiles), we
>   encourage you to gently correct them in a comment. Do not state
>   pronouns for third parties who have not done so in Stack Exchange (eg.
>   You know them in person). If the situation escalates, please flag what
>   you see. A moderator or community manager will look into it further.
>
> **Q5: How will this be moderated? Will we ban people based on one mistake?**
>
> We understand that miscommunication or mistakes may happen, so most
>   situations will just result in a gentle correction or warning. As with
>   any violation of the Code of Conduct, in cases of willful, repeated,
>   or abusive behavior, warnings may escalate to account suspensions
>   and/or expulsion.
>
> **Q6: What should I do if I don't know someone's pronouns?**
>
> When in doubt, use gender-neutral language or refer to the user by
>   name.
>
> **Q7: Are we going to force everyone to identify their pronouns?**
>
> No. Just as we do not force users to identify their real name, we will
>   never force users to identify their pronouns. This is a voluntary
>   decision by each user to share as much or as little as they are
>   comfortable.
>
> **Q8: How should I identify my pronouns if I choose to do so?**
>
> Whether and how you identify your pronouns is up to you. If you choose
>   to do so, add it to the “About Me” section of your user profile.
>
> **Q9: Do I have to use pronouns I’m unfamiliar or uncomfortable with (e.g., [neopronouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neopronoun) like
>   xe, zir, ne... )?**
>
> Yes, if those are stated by the individual.
>
> **Q10: What if I believe it is grammatically incorrect to use some pronouns (e.g. they/them to refer to a single person)?**
>
> If they are the pronouns stated by the individual, you must respect
>   that and use them. Grammar concerns do not override a person’s right
>   to self identify.
>
> **Q11: If I’m uncomfortable with a particular pronoun, can I just avoid using it?**
>
> We are asking everyone to use all stated pronouns as you would
>   naturally write. Explicitly avoiding using someone’s pronouns because
>   you are uncomfortable is a way of refusing to recognize their identity
>   and is a violation of the Code of Conduct.
>
> **Q12: Does this mean I’m required to use pronouns when I normally wouldn’t?**
>
> We are asking everyone to use all stated pronouns as you would
>   naturally write. You are not required to insert pronouns where you
>   otherwise would not.
>
> [From @CesarM (staff)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1#comment1101186_335191): You have to use their stated pronouns in
>   places where you'd include a pronoun. If you wouldn't include a
>   pronoun in the sentence, you don't have to go out of your way to find
>   a place to include one.
>
> **Q13: How does this apply to languages other than English?**
>
> For now, while the intent of being inclusive and respectful of all
>   gender identities applies to all our communities, the specific
>   requirements around pronoun usage apply only to English language
>   sites. As we determine best practices in other languages, we’ll work
>   with those communities and update guidance for those languages.
>
> **Q14: Should all posts be written using gender-inclusive language? Should we edit all old posts to be gender-inclusive?**
>
> The focus of this change is on using correct pronouns when addressing
>   other members of the community. However, writing posts in a
>   gender-inclusive way is encouraged and a great way to make the
>   community more accessible to more people. If you are writing or
>   editing a post and can make it gender-inclusive without changing the
>   meaning, you are encouraged to do so.
>
> **Q15: Is it expected that people go to "About me" to check whether someone has pronouns there when interacting in Q&A?**
>
> No.  That would be good practice, but it is not *required*.
>
> [From @jnat (staff)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes#comment1098285_334910): We ask that you use gender-neutral language
>   when uncertain, and use the stated pronouns once they're made known.
>   If you wanna "go the extra mile," looking at the user's "about me"
>   before interacting is certainly nice, but we're not requiring it.
>
> [From @CesarM (staff)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/334915#comment1098325_334915): *Made known* is when you become aware of
>   the fact. If it's in the comments, then, fine. Correct and move on.
>   There's no obligation to go out of your way to seek it out, but if
>   someone tells you directly, comply.
>
> **Q16: May I use *they/them* by default?**
>
> Yes, but be prepared to make adjustments if so requested.
>
> [From @Catija (staff)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/335477#comment1104046_335428) If you use *they/them* by default, that's
>   fine. If someone requests that you use other pronouns and you
>   immediately continue to use *they/them* for that person, we may point
>   it out to you. "Penalized" in most cases is generally going to be as
>   minor as a comment being removed or adjusted to meet the request of
>   the person being spoken about. Only in extreme cases of repeated
>   requests to change, will it lead to a mod message or suspension.
>
> **Q17: What should I do if I think someone requests me to use a certain pronoun in bad faith?** [From @Cesar M(Staff)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1#comment1098246_334908)
>
> > If people are requesting things in bad faith, you are welcome to escalate to mods and mods can contact us CMs when in doubt too.
>
> It is advised to use a custom (Something Else) flag for this. Please
>   explain, as detailed as possible, what the issue is.
>
> [Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: @JoKing there's a link there, it simply means that no part out your answer should violate the CoC.

Comment: Ah, I guess we're going to have to close it as unclear if that's the case

Comment: @JoKing you're the one whose being unclear, the new CoC is very comprehensive.

Comment: I can only assume you're being sarcastic to prove a point, since there's more than a hundred answers to the linked question, many of which are asking for clarifications with no response. On the other hand, this just seems to be just a [tag:answer-chaining] polyglot with basically no restrictions? By `adding code`/`subtracting code`, can we only do one at once? because both just means the new code can be whatever

Comment: @JoKing right, same rules as [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102370/60951) in the additional rules, except 2 and 4. Also the answer formatting does not apply,.

Comment: @JoKing right it's clear I must be verbosely specific. *ignore any questions on the CoC*. **CoC is law**.

Comment: Ideally, a challenge shouldn't need you to refer to *multiple* other resources to understand what the rules are, so long as the rules aren't too mathematically sophisticated.

Comment: @UnrelatedString should I copy them to this question?

Comment: [High steaks round?](https://i.imgur.com/h8Bh0xg.png)

Comment: @Night2 all answers

Comment: @JoKing I can only hope you're being intentionally thick, in the evident case that you aren't I've added the most verbosity that I possibly could think of, let me know if there's anything else is unclear and I'll point you to a relevant google query.

Comment: @Night2 I've fixed that.

Comment: Really, answers are meant to abide by the CoC anyway, so there's you don't need to explicitly list them out. This could just be a [tag:answer-chaining] [tag:polyglot] that outputs "he/him", except that that would probably be closed as a duplicate of something since it is too simple

Comment: While I think this challenge doesn't deserve closure as unclear, I think it is a duplicate of [Add a language to a polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102370/46076), so voting to leave closed.

Answer (score 5):

## 1. [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 6 bytes

```
he him
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/I1UhIzP3/38A)

Real easy one for Keg, just print the desired output.